# Fruit bagging factory

Tags: number, code-challenge, sequence, optimization, restricted-time

Your mission is to build an algorithm (program or function) that can optimize packing fruit from a conveyor belt into bags to be sent off to retailers, optimizing for a largest number of bags.

Each bag has to weight at least a certain amount, but any excess is lost profit since that weight could be used to fill another bag. Your bagging machine has always a lookahead of `n` fruits from the queue and may only choose to add any of these `n` fruits to the (single) bag that is being processed. It cannot look beyond the `n` first elements in the queue. The program always knows exactly how much weight there already is in the bag.

Another way to visualize this is having a conveyor belt with a loading area of size `n` at the end, from where a fruit has to be taken before a new fruit arrives. Any leftover fruit and a non-full bag at the end are discarded.

[image: Figure 1: Fruit bagging factory]

### Inputs

- List/array of weights of fruits in queue (positive integers)
- Minimum total weight for bags (positive integer)
- Lookahead `n` (positive integer)

### Output

Your algorithm should return for all bags the weights of the fruits in them, by whatever means is convenient for you and your language, be that stdin or a return value or something else. You should be able to run the program and calculate your score in one minute on your computer.

### Example

```
Total weight 1000, lookahead of 3 and fruit queue: 
[171,163,172,196,156,175,162,176,155,182,189,142,161,160,152,162,174,172,191,185]

One possible output (indented to show how the lookahead affects the bagging):
[171,163,172,    156,175,    176]
                        [162,    155,182,189,    161,160]
                                                        [152,162,174,172,191,185]
```

### Scoring

Your algorithm will be tested on six runs on a [batch of 10000 oranges](https://gist.github.com/angs/0a17ff0ef08136770c7e7cedeaf4a4d9) I have prepared for you, on lookaheads ranging from 2 to 7, inclusive on both ends. You shall pack them into bags weighing at least 1000 units. The oranges are normally distributed with a mean weight of 170 and a standard deviation of 13, if that is of any help.

Your score will be the sum of number of bags from the six runs. The highest score wins. Standard loopholes are disallowed.

[Simple example implementation and test suite boilerplate in Haskell](https://tio.run/##jX1rjx1HcuV3/oprYgyQXlGoyszIjBRWAowx1hAwCxm2F/tBEuyW1BQJUd3a7uZqxvB/H9@qihPnVM8MxgNoSN5H3ap8xOPEiZPvbh5/uv3w4Y/vf/7l/uHp8g83Tzef/u7949OLeOFfb3//9Ok/Pby/e3qLl/7lD49Ptz9/@uVXn/6fu8ebt7eXVx/3P//p9uHt/cPPX371@tkn//nm7of7ny@vHvY/t/dfPP3hl9vL/719/@O7p8vnly/vnl68@PH26avrJ368fby@8vPNL5eH25sfLp9efr1/@OHx8j9/88Xl@onf3t893d49PV4@@@zy5VeXr6/f/PZ6tdvHp8vbj3eX726evn93/frD7dPHh7vLq@0yrz7c3v349O56pe9ufvzx9mH/4K/HT@@ff315uD7A6xeXyxdffH75ZXvWf759/Pjh6fH60q/vbh9ur39e8JXPL@uyLPsr29euf3x@@bp8@un4drun44a2N/U6l99fP/TD/f769Z2PT//y9PC7u8vLN8//9zI@cr3v//1vl1ffvLr55LvXb77Yr/X28vJ39/c/3bzbhuVv1x8@u/xt@@Gbu5eXm8t3r1/9x/tfjvv5/ev//s/guv96/3Tz4bPjteOq23VfPX78@Xq5P8awXb9zfcBXMWlvvrjwb18ff/2Wr76@vHnz2/uH28u7248P1@X0/vvr1/mdv/6/N2/@8f7mQwz68d38lb/@3S@vy@7y/z7efrw9vnqdlct/639v3uQYx4/iV7/9q9/86uPTdcy3Vfb4Qpbaj9tz7Pdy@XC99t/v8/f59eXL19/mPWKZXV@9fjVfvlz@87LNwvbaF58fl@L/Pt9f/@zZpbbv3H38gN989r/rYv0WH7p/urz6/t394@3d5d9vP9z@/O/HV15fP3T78HD/cHn5vx4@vn/aP/j2/uPdDy/jm/dP19v99f3jn1z9eC5c9LPt/l5fXh038s03l6@PN749luj@zJf47Of7WL2Kh319POqrp5ufdNSO23vx4qYvtS2fXB6vdubD7SeX7x7uf7q9@@RyGJhYqbnUrivx48PD1Wrsw6UrSj7yl1fbdUlcF/Dl/u3l7TYaj5endzdPl@9vrtYGd/8nV/vt8VD7F67/f72nXx5u///7@4@Plw@bcT0eYL@f/UGvl3n//W749uf8zeXxaj6/uo7HN79uV7757vH62vbp/3G5vrB/5zW@9OIYhb94MXzsGKQ/97HdoMXY/Zm3P9w@XT5sE3R9jutGuv3xYZuasKrxsdeX93f4@9/8zau31zl7OAz@q9eXv7t8eP0ai3yfpMu/Xa/3zGtc4B62yfuH@4/ffbj9488377elIa5hM9Hf/LQNStrIu0/eXm0k7d3d9UOXwyVcftp@9@vLq5eHD3oZyzSXyvb2J9e3//7Drzd/eLy8ff/w@PTygpXFt@8ef71u533Wtrdj/l6/ePNme3t7af/st39c@3Ipy3JZrV//Wy9rb5fVtz/L8e9h139f3x/X//z62ri@3@f1v@vrfRzf2963ev339b95/c@v743re@P69@rH@309vjO268a/7fpercdnm8frcd3tc9t92PW36jjuZ2y/1Y7r79/f7mn7ftzvwGe2e75eb8zjTzyL2fH97fe2v2/PanFPI/6@fXa/zx73VI7f2MfA@fr2@7PwGtt9bs/f@jFW@2eX4zWPMdzHasR3WtzzPMYJ49zifrbf2J6rzRjzuN9ajvHZ7mm/13LMB@5x@9w2Txbjut9D/Lldu2/PNK5z3vn72/dnjIvHWG/jVGP89@9YjDXuP@avLcf723hgHD3@vt/LejzH9oytXH93mysZi@11wz3EPO7P58eYDKydJebRY7xGzEmLOcWf5ViD23/b5zzmfSwci9457vu9j@P3B/6Lz21zv83fPpb9eH6L@djG2Pvx@j4/si@mx14p8RzlWMPb57G2LX6nxv1sa6SVfW6O371eb26vjbj@cry3/b3FHE3Md/z@fu/9WHv7GK7He/uebHG/29qqx/v7tdcYD@wf7HXj@G7vb@Owz/GQMRiyBnHPI@bIYk3bsdY97mtbg9vzbet6e2/G6/s@XY73tvGb8dv7/Y3j9/d/d9lTFmM@j@/t9zXiuyX24Dx@Y/s9i/vfXrNYs9u9Wfw7bcLk5/bn8lhPFuthyv3VY93u6yHsh8mem879ut37/tke47HwvW0sW@c4WozHPvbL8dubvdm@Xy3srdjRba73dbGc7eOI/bnbCws775zv62vHnsRa99ibWMOx7vf3Om34bgdM9hL2LexmP8Zzn@/wEyO@v9tNrKUl1u5COzFjT9hhq9K/7J@J8d/mbcT@2O/Lufdm2F/Y2RG2ywvty3YNj727z1MNW7/Sjo5jjnf/6DHX@7qP9QFfse0nPPP2HYt1uX1uW3e7/dp84eTvd9iM8LEj5nsfox62q4oPg48ImznwPJ3X338//KzjmWO9TdjF@P1tjHZ/EzY11zz8aY1rh13pxjEdcV899tduvwftsC303z2e2WM8sMe2v3fs7yVs2ZR10jjv2/NP2H7n3pmHjSzLpI3c950d17VYR/tchB2BjYTNg23b7fSg/d99RtjNfY5aPC@uEzHLPk4zbKFzDffY0xZ72WMMLK6XtnMwLrGwKbsvdu4vi7EZxn2xPc@2T7bPGfwR7BB@H88Zc@iFcRh@I/0X/Mka4wN/VSQmbPQrPez2Pt@V6yvHIGzObsfCZ@/33sT39oiXsOfGMUYTeyx8xXYfNeK@EXvEEN9t8Ws8L9ZqFfvuPWwcYpeYuz228sMneNx3gy@JcZyVcc3@5xLjjtg47tvCHnrEjR0@K2zRHtes/Fx32iLHfg3f6KvYKthwxKNy37CFA7YGsUDMp1fGJB5@q4VPxvpBjDIRu076NEcc347xbGFP9nmPZ50xJrvfRvyHtdfoz0b4G/ih67Me84F7kbXa4rl67LcePmxM2jH4grRPPa41I5aC/RE/MCJG3r/rsobnYSemyZiG7xqdMVsPX7PPd4t4o9NOwn/NwhwHudKIvYR7SJu/0lfl@Mi@3z8H2zsOPzPCznvsoRY2BnNjiCMG4/L9Hpx2yrAuYjw99hnsy4i4f6y89v67I/Y61nf4EJ/0WT18vMVzDIkZe9jePSaKsUO8OWItIea3lbH/iNwkfUk5x2MTtjhsqk3JoUrMFXKRFr/rHK8ecfVAvLAe92jwFYglIlYxiZdb430MjHXlnxYxuMm@sdhX7vSVyGccY4B11MMG6rqCLVljDYbf7sb1MSSfc@RklffuMZ/ICdK3Io@KtYIc0prYz5Ux0D4X8TlvnG@sgQZ/HtfoYVt2W4ZxjPUNH5z2UfOuiGMR/49@ztUQa@w2OtY61m/GSMZca3bG/N4ZY@E3bDA28fAN1@@UBXEu7J8zZ3OJa2HfDTEdcv24H0PMZhKXxr7esYVVniv23fX9sq753GWF3Yi8EfEPYsVeuD@9cZx3@7HKPg18YWoePiUGWukT9jU2aR8Q82XMGD7XAkNohT4b47DHGoU2FXl2i5gPa7ZH7LDnwYix4t5nI@6DWMvjfkfE6zP2WMYLEQu2LvF2YXzlsf4NcXARm4Z9Er7aqvhDYy6JHAHxQXfBQo71tWMviJ8d6xOxKuJQjM2kj@yxB0fEboghLfaoD66xzAULY1JgJA67FXH7iOcxxNxiqzF/1jg@veV6PPKjWPcOn260xYg/vTEWHhEP7nG95PfAz9y5bxEbwL9v/7XALrzzuVr4TuBPFvakxX7F3G@2ChglsAP4PMRuGc8V@qSc6y44F3xE2NKM1xEP4LliLzbs5zUwGOQgMTZtMna22KvbPtliogbbNunD@iTWhxgh4xQXXM8FI4u12Ct9ncdv5n5e6ed6/B1zZvDpRnwScdi2/hDrpu0N@zqR24XP87Dn5sTaRsRhM/abN@KmJthLb1wrinshvh2Rdw/kvZKnYI9Z4FTYfxj3zNEnsUZfBTssxz32KjFe5@f3uNrEbiwyxiXiLyeGAVyhhq3zyFWQAyBmhJ8ErusRL1qlz92xk86YeZ9nk3y3ER/oYecSO4R/jjkw2evwrfDliL2B8TXnb2VsC@x7iXkSLC7zvcCwtzXaGn8T9mxGnhz7@cjzxrEfZvwOcDZgiHVy/SFO6Y3jlziGBc50xNdlRXwBzBW46hC8F/nSQjsDPHcfN@BZiIuNue/E@ovnga1BTgJsvRXim8iXLHyxIfa3@I1VcCjB97BvENP6kDoO4opyzIVHDWXWcx6JteIS22L8sK@xf82lRhRrAHlf2ibLPG6PYWbc45yCrSDPHJnbH@uoCBaKPDZs6Jhcc71LjWAIdrdKzBL@BLnMWJjfY93BxswqmFgj3jGA5QA/EJ8NvHibh2nEXhLnRFzqx5oH5jIbMQbk1KNIXhprZgomnXliI67XwxeNyP3KwjgAvskrc0LgiE189m57puD/YgNtZm62jy3yW2BohjUDfH4cn8PYNfjJyX2LuLUNYsnu9Enwpb4wl87alUvs44wNPTAtj/FBzQl4PdZ@5uTiYxCLYS9MGbPAGI5nb8RmLGydAc9HrNfO2Dhy8rayPoY8H3vVjHt5x7ICm@mF9hD7xadgHGE79@sbY/S@Sl4ZmJuFfy9Y17DPWD@w74HteZf8MuatIj5F3SrsCsa5mcSMRXDuHvhz5Ccz1vEMTNMK83yr9E/b71X49agfzkJczFapT3vYfsTmxr0/B58R2CxqgXt86awv5Vgs4j8K4y/Uf924luDbgN2j1meT@eGIWs4U3BlYhHeui/QRUTcxXHPQh1vE8/t4xJ5uU2I42HLUcWKP@pB8NWyqO/HQ9G1V9n7E5oY95YyX0nZNiUGAlxlzVMTOQ3Jbj/HAGkPNFzhe2sZGW2iwVx5@BL7PGWeMlTblVH8vzH93DFnqJqirIn5rLthC4VrOcXKORxf8tDfiUdYYd46F6wp8hlY57x7zZ845ye8Z4/MZ@3bfz1NwExMb0siRgD1Fna/1HOc9h8sYYUZOFzm54rFZTwJOq9hUY8zYjZyQtOON49Mn76NLrIG6DWrMwDp7kzxcfaqsDQNe5fRXLcZgoLaM/VKJT3o71zKwNxMrW6X2A2x4Mhdrk3kzuBqoPyAvA8@iYW0M5sCZg07G82qvxyI4n4kv8pirlT4mbNSRQ6yM/fdc0Bn7p3@LencvtPWIWbXWhth0WzOzskaEGGL02ENTcIzGOl5HPiw@d48hYIONddHZ6LtGXG@3y6hdAbsMH9kncbA2mcdUjG3stQbsAHV6we8n4jHhO@H3gUkBz0n7Doy10sbnXAeOkLXZwdpXC3uBnGU4a4HJ2YlcC3iHhd0GDwq2ODH7whpfxrpFsOE1ar2IkRv93nRi4@A8tEmMEPEBYpx97RThWFjGVXu8AywA2EbWGKVGg7UBXG5M4oxZE3TanD2OFN@OHC5jQtQs7LALM@wD4uvE@KvkZo1jn/mcMU415QoBKxSMY4ptgy/cY6jJGv0e10aMlHuxnPHHrPnWYz/4FD9ZuHeA36LGotw3Bw6Iem0lPj0iV0NdCOOaexP4btinxNkX5jTADYAJjX6uGbWVuHiu3fgM9i/WLvJD/Hs4beeYgl3L/Y/ww8CBh9SFYBMt1jL2dStnXs7UOpJwAxH3@ZR6aSN2PkbGt7tdRZ4wJEZA/DtMeEqyr5JjJvipRx6YY1RlzJFnOddsL6wXjIinso5ZZU828hHB5TM78u6i/jDudwJji7WBus9u61usZ@TyRexulxjapPbqXGew0xhH8CJdYkPgkQ6MfwqHTjg8cwheIjwA4CCIXfFe5lexDlrYjbmwTpqc0ZW4Eur@Xrjfkr8Bf97JzwH@iz2EWA3zMBfhXE3uJ9x7n4L9dnJgEkdz5rQtciCP@zSTPRp5mvIdR5GaJDijK3P6LnEnPmurYAYLY3Jgjn2QAzsEn@gLY2Ksob5yzjMfbdxDbbK@njyR8E9Za23PamVD8NGolbUqGH4lVwXrG/a/O@uHNiQvQbyDOsPgWBk4EsFjNKdN8yLPAO7bEM6d5NWJMU1y4IBNzVgPe17cGWfMQl8wjH5b68bhj8paJY7SuGiNvTuJnfgiuBViB6wl5TxVzg04x74wzmsRj2nts63EKhGnAotpTXyE5HgYT/D9Mv@SGNybYJMSZyQftUnuLHYJsXd31rVQVwAnKfH7IridzM2otPOnOrVwFna7ZczZXWL65K272O4p8ZDz87UKr3UKF25K3mP0YaivZj1lIVci4wWp04KXFTyhsk7meKgvas4w8PvOuk3GwqgXrORGZRzVxR4U2mlwwmAbgOlmDV/4zLDlwIFtkt@z26F2jBcwJ2C8sD3TWQsa4Bdpjh41hjpoE1x6HzRvMKm3gi/pq3CXh2DEyCWbcDsK7fTE2lpYA8O6RE3NjeMD7H4U/hb4UeC9I@b3Rp5lD14rsKoeNQof5Itap3@xiAGx53KeY@@jrtOmxIlSc0JcaMY1lHlp8Hrgz5OjVYSrtEgMVMkV72FjgKF11J2AERlr7ojXwW3R2Bg@3AbrHTXwc3Dr5kpsOPsPVuIRyP8z/53kK3j8rkf9yCvz0RH7IPgOGevvudOkn27iL01wjxk2aK4SX8JHdOmHcHJezHhPyCuBRWW9DjUtyeexxy18sUleW13y2UXWlnNcUDeeUrPd1lNF38ci@Sp8Wey5JryrMc@cJdTBYdsM@0l4UMjjsweic1yy3lQEH6zCcYoxn4X1TdQY3YjXImdALtalrgmuHcZO9zY4VH0h5xFxPfJpL@xFai44EHgPlVwlrG3EBQ1@JGKa4EiT2zDPfFatLdlC/n3m9qiHDOGmaH/OlBprXCtrsFOwpMKczYTvArs/g@uanGbhC@x7PTg1Lv0yyfsAf7TSH6O@Ac4u6vB7vNTOvQmwWcD9bSU/a5Rz/dxiDbnWPxufD7kmcKHWWTM88S@KvOesp6MOnD4w7PWMugVqi6gJJFdhIR8A/C4fzG1sJd/RpsT045yTZJ3cj7WG/bvXoLTmXsgTwn4fnX1Ryady4qtT@lGAiyhfFJxbcM/ANW7Oeh/qpG2Sc5C83pXcrLQZC58tcb1Kbs0Qfg78SF@JXwKTSv5sXAM4KPgj6WOQ1xfukeQSRvydvRYt4udOLm9y3ppwaJvwTIvg7xELIEdoTfyz1P1m1Idgc8CNQy7UJf5uwn0cqJM4a4zgqik31vycQ072eJbVWJvrJpxT4HNF6ouI3xfWddFviPwV6ydxVn/GAWjkK4CviB6LYcQJ91hE8sK2CscV@HqMI@Lu4eTswdb5cZ0dF5qdNcP0Sy18k/RaYH9ovyU4BhU@qkjsJPahL7IeMfeyvtGzhR6AzI0W9lAOyQ1G4Bytn3mGWpPIGn3s@eTeFOkL7fQZbZWa8sr8CbkJ8LC5MoZNvkhnXcyK1E0rOVW@4XAetZSoM03hXNfJPhjw@cGNQ4wxB@NIcBvbEN615Pi7HQyMcwhWlxwJI04J/4@aN/iiyQkr5CaD46y1Qvwbc@5S826Kp0TsAr5Q8l5X8gldxgd7E/E89l3unSZ5JPihK7F9jCFyDe@s5eRamkdvImyMNeHpT@6ZtHOTveeoA2MPI/fL3GNKT94k/wQ9puCVwOa79FWA0z6LYPpR880@xiFYIninwnNCfJ81zSa5XZd6GHgkfh4f3Hvk3kd9tdD2oEeiBbaK/AhrDbh4cl5XydfFt00jz74HdxQ8CuDGrj3nVXIq7T/sEqsO5gu5fqTfozj5EYi5gKOjBjBQ0/DkOuz5T/IfqnDZF8asiL9a5A7huzl3XfLUdq6DZh2tyfpq4u@6cPKK5Ggm9xM@24fkr@AZqlaC9JCDT@dHvf6orUc8t9fIivRwC/49sW6gMeDEXcDLxx7P/sbJ5wLfHjy5jBEq@bhN6lUDug3QfRD7nrzyVThjhfyf/Vphq8Df8UIOdnIBVvJMwacHXyv54YV7zYWb75Wx@hCec6ffTW5s8osW1jYQw2aM2bkGsybUhQ/bmFN6YQ/jUDxgJV7TIqYWe8Z6oHBv9fvgZ@29Q0X6i0x6UEw4kcHpyb4M4JBhU6fUtxI/X4Uj6MQws5b1jAegeQ4wrXjO3cYibgdGif5sxT2V34/@D@QePbgDybNz1krQn9bELiFvQc7WRVMDsWCT2L5Jfn/yY00w/yLrb5AnalIvwG9p72tyOuED67kmA7uDeDV56ujPiJizLsIFqLQpw1hHtkl9DHCoehNuprGfLeP85cw7MulNBw4OjMXIDzlqIv3MacDe1hg8uRYxhtMFBwzcFH4FNQzte4APtkXW78r@qRnPhJ5AC27kNPbII0c24B9T6sVV@l8Kc9EpuSTqGYmzF/kNE58fcWH26hXBERf27fjzmt9gLwV4vvAFcyG/IfOxlTVE5JguvfvoV8/aBTC9wT5xxBrZLxI4ePY8LMwpw78enFVoO0TNLG1ikTwh8ozMEeM3LXQDsP7GJI8OnHvEUagRJj9AeyQbe1wSP1jYw5/6K@DgT@q5JH/WpQcqeNFT@NJTOPXDWc9u4oOAg6AOj7iqRf5VhvQ7F@aWib8Nau9APwgxi/YC9We1374QxwH3IvFk8Xfd2BuH/qfUXykSl4reUPYuTuJddUr8WNjD18O3gA@CfKDZWZcIdSjV0mh@xkyyp180jBBPYA5H6P8g33Hpu2vChZhDtAyMexp8@8R1nGtqGnnDiBlUDwM87qzNdulLkLkEV9wn7dJYyOcDR84CG@uiS7LNdxX@bsYPU@qZqN2HNoz6t@TkTeYl4OZjPwf3pSyDthP1MXAntE9siEbUkPgMue1QbSoTu10FgzT2NGLdZx60nrVqUFfuUpv3qIWBe4dcVnMqcDngk1slNw65uAuuBS48fj/j4VX4JBGbQkMk66NYb9J7Ch0l9B85fK3gP/ALyW9bBKut557lIdjMHOTDJcYpuStyOMOaMNoCYPHJRS@shSAfSW2fhbyO7F2ZZ@4t5jlrZNJDOxSjMOLpyN8QqyRXpAjWPsmXscm6ZRebNIX/UIN/PlF7Fz2SDhz38NVlkR5pxVnBRWqDuDD6fRGjGDgZTl2D1E9bGHdnz3@VHnfln1diaODYZ50v1uJeO3SpnU/m1qmlVETjTvIu6H251NaBg2WNZpX4tZPDjFwbfc9emDMCB0hfw37TUqLe0qWnOHs6Jf5BfRcxStqiTj9sUc/s2ntv/Lc5tdCwVpPH/KynG2Pkoh/hkiuaM3fFfqnzvK5nOesjIe9FPSX7P8EBQW8N@lwbc8bUAxG7Aps4F9biWtjW2qiJgNxoSF@pT2ppNeHUt2e5BPRvgOegXpIYl9RrXPpTYTOHUxdD66kzsAGTGlH2by@ioVa5h8bCeDz1tapoGYptTe5blVgociPoIWQeZfTF0IoD3zJr@U6cJ@v8jXgaYvrkq0nfObi4HrGuanTZQjufmoLSl4H8G3FFk7owNM1cejwQ72JeTHRFfAoe06QPsfM5UcMy0VlshXxK9Fj0IlqJ0avRRAcI@E5/xgly4edbpeYW/DPsNjgvfvjiw/5Cv2xyTaAumNpwg/1ryQuxZ/UZp77E3tc@pLehc3xTZwJ540L8@VSbMOljLsH5H@TMZx9D5e/nWtGelnLWu0N/e/IJPX1b6sH1IfGa1DWBsUzpdYAGImq2yd9fiPmlHk2lfgbwpaE1jeCxTPAznNinC78qY4TC52zhW9DDh16ULtwdfHcO4futZ5uXemNDuGsufS39bPtH1Ce9iP9chF@j4zGl17exvpsatcb@4VP/f2CEyE9R1@qhmYh4GFy1k59XHFJ4suiz69G7nr3WopPRJcZPbnYXO4x9Ev2gU/t3hmhIufSbL9T4yby4c//A9mks4RIXQ78RewB8rwreaqzxVshfsJX9@qqvmjFSZx0DPe5d1vcQPT9gXehByH6gSh@Bfh9HL2nEIlN6qLNvt4t23zhrWADfQ1@fUTtmzzezL2yI3xqsw3bBecAhR/4IfLEL12Lv/23cq7qWRmUdqzRy@l30nFTTFLUGcBFhh9GHjZpkXagPlphcoQ8aMUfVhS@5kptpUgtwwb666Kg815bqkmuA15C9KYW6x9kfNGnXwOkY0h/apacmdY7CxsPPj@WMAaMHYAzq67QpfIEm3B7R6zn1HlXiusCswP1wqWWi7z10OLI2MKR@MrR3pZLXPQc1QdB7kjo9qsPazzXC7NFbyLPI/sCFfsqgcbRIDF64d6D90cDv6KLHcOCBO2bQta8eehHCn9Q6ILjFWTOBBsEgl6wLhzzxC@2b7GccF36qSb998oZW4iqo2TlwdqkbdPHRWW8w8bcLOR7AUk7XjHHzKVpw65nHD1@K@u/OAY79NgWbwd5B/ty69KyLPh1yT5OeoT1XGOSXqj5Fcn0rsajsD55nrhHqbFmzG2JbB/uaGnKa9WxLwbs30bVCP3Mz@Q5eG9TvArbawSHuUk8uwrF34lzJU@3nvLQN9pCZ9CAgzsuexELMSPtLgZGjfwU9XdA4GdqHN5/1whWJZRu5muDcoGcQNTqTumHqmVX6ExP7ljp@iGEW9ohBhy/7/UTPKjjZR538wN8OntF4ll@JzUXekX1lxhgYthg2NTUTpX@0isaPiRYqejfnKvzZSQ0G6BW49FhDewAczSF7MDmKndzY1J5cqd@P/TxFN3C7lzrEFpvUt9DrOoh5qq6h4jGw49DtgD4X@jthr116IIZokyFHGYKdQ2Mxa68mnNFFuGWCVyGezHqnE1ee0FCM/t@Ig/acDPhVFwy0OTnfTTVcDizgxLfJOlUntgneavYQiV6F8iSTc0TcsBTRWLDlmQ7tIvVg6Jk39psil@nlyGcNNr8JH3NSEwf8ivQPWvvH/FfRYw4toCE6WKhTpW50YT/Wvj8WcuLwu8kdnIxlkmMPH1ap1YU4rgcvejrXZ/Z6V8YY2QPd6E/gP1L/QnicsFOzMV6YTfogF8ZoyMvRK4M4C/lncjAK44zklSvXRnTgwDNJTffIe7uM8VzZa5i43rN8HNo1qlVl/Yy7ok/CpCcdsUlqPq20C010l6xJf1sVvRyX80xMeiMrOfLaS4c4vmuNyUTbU/okTz2og9934WKnDQwMR3uTcG977baS4wC8LPlmk9gXctTsS5KasSu/y6m3lrixC466nPVku/RUJe@3sp4MbUXkZWE7djtlC/tnURNKnK6Jpv0UzHZIfGDUh8v9tkpsrfpj4ZOAlRrsbyWG6qJpbuVZLraKvrRotoBrl7a5sb@xtTOu5QttkuKT2KPZD7AIp2ly/yuWiGtqj2/ilVP6dxfpky7U9kncXHvznXHb7II9T9G3EDs4C/WnMx426ZERHdTxjFeb2twLr6fnNeT@DwwfOpp7X5bY28z7KzWtgEUlRzx8/RSt0Bk149R5Dg1fm4zvgU80OY/CG7W29LwZfU5g8F7EvnTROIN@10pepmoBeHmm19kFVyqi/9ROfpbasVXqlOXck5f11FXqw3Y@l2UIJ7cXYkGak8F2QxcRnDzX/Hcm15FnKjTaptSvWEVbdwpnspIn3aVXBb4gtRcC6x6ikwWuBtZW8oMr@5wSuynSUya5i4mGgwevr6GPxITvvTIXmMuzczlEY75rPUF0fLvk3aprC9uKXLxJfQf5NdaeGbXM0N@WelxTehVMdD1F57yLZgvOneniM1OrTPJZN/YHpCaYE98FF7aJ3lxy6MHP6IyHZ/j6Sb7uwU2S8wWgqQwN99QVF51y2NImeQN82VAdM@M9x3UOHQ8nbjcDD9g0vtdy5gGBD437xljnWSBd@M1Sz5iihTQrOb@oN8J3JHbbBS9wyetd@nsH@fhzlRrHco6Zsh9R9@QUroloA@mZalrzTGzbiI8M4TKlXRE@QsYcUYsBVjdd9DdW6XcwqbU4MQz14VmbLMR@UEcB7pmc38o@/NTxqsSzuuhzKDdrNtZfd85BZd8Jco08AyH8ZmrPyJk@2vOefI/JeEU01zZ/enAKB@Pp9FOL8DBWxqW5vrrEG1XO2hJMYXQ5l0P6SLv04ZzO9lE/ZNKzs1I3z5vwDoWfkPlqE55eldqHUROyy3kbqWsJvZ3GeBp8ye48Rwtn7gD7wpktWZ9STlSTnpFV6poreY1d@kwSD5aemR6cXPR5dvFTLrpGmT8L/xi5Z57NMojxe6fdhR@pTl3Y3a7GfmgxdlV1UmJ/zMo@7BzrJnl26ASaYIIZAy7UXUeucdL10TMpVvY0u/T7TYm5pnDfE7t0qbEpL130lEaT88A6eZapz9eFs914zlyXOq05e8MTH5PeU9XpyrUyhDcjOKbmTFmPnYKrruzLMInRu2grp@YC9EQX8t9Te1p5jl1iIeU1j3MvTvJ/Jvd2KWdeLfrpZ@OZd3H9vW8OMcPp7Bo5m1NtCbjGyV9kj@WBpxTmTXkOpXDKqtQLoKs2xE@DLzWESw/8AGc3Jv90sOaLmk3roj8v2hqpD@DkNyDvS67tmhym7CUDVo1e2jxLYKV9AI@kQYN@EZ9SJRaYxEy64DPNaCdHxD7QHFNeLXQQgfMlLi2awcGXOXSGhQuRubKHvqfgRxmPRv9L1gtx3pYxB8wz@ErEaIN2/YSnN6ljSZ9lajiZ6N4N9jGjBpJnICnXErzCVTiFhfU7n@yzHYED4kwx4Ino1Vbd1Sm6uonriNaWyXmbyTty8vmRT1ThN@X@ijWbsaic2QW9LvTtgJea14@YCTEe1gI4UcDYp9SRWznjALPLOXPzzOVEPjQX2s3iwkHsopMCHkGhX1N@3pzsKc@@HGdMAU0oj5hnFvbrgtfRRdN0duFKFelz7tSznqv0Ji7SO1NYq@jgZXfWk/Z56TwjBJg3ajCoY7jUiqFLnZxIYNudOjOm539I3yr2aWtyHig4fM4zk@dy7udO/M15PmPq2Tdig@j5TT9h1EUy1RV3OdfBWDusQ/R6/ByHpObQpB9L3kyRM6WkvwH49ynfq@QGj3nmSpvwMIacT6RciowZRQcHeQOukXpy0Y@afGPhew/tv6hyvthCnM5EayO1xrpo9y5n3bk8i8apqwZNrvx86OF6OXOvYeOHnK@HfgAXbrXJ@Yc4qzT7kly4ZotoKTfRyquihb6SY4Xz5aD7gT1jjVpuqreVXI9Cba48BwnajisxwdTUFFzE17M20pD6G3AmE/vozrFKXd0m@co4a44kz3l5pvsGXoZot@t5hDiLN/USnXykKZiw@VmzGzYX57pN4bFtWP0KLZny7Cy7KvzbylwLPErYDNR/shbkPMsiz22S/t6cD9EObJUYO84tTN8LHmM993uBT589MCvPD0oMfJEzwZWvrOd8Sh@si@bJlL7P5KKCvy/85S6aVlprSPssvVSzyPl2kzm8ic4otCLBHU09msa6XVMbNni@SOKVi9gXxBGFsWoVjAbPh30Dbk2el9moKw8fBD4xcjCTesNoPKPR0FcnXAjkYclB0V4tk3ODtSe4CT8G9SbB7NAb14UnWgc5r4hBUxtgyP5bRfMrYszkfkt9p8tZT8D8cVZw8nhE@wC1mQYsaXDv4qzVLpxxlxoTdA@y16FTf8HQNwjfaqInuBKDQq7b7Mz5rZX7A3036OfP514kNhZ9pKHamYLrm@ik9ELOX/K3XDQRTfRO25nvgVoSauLJC1mFq76wzzSxxeWkNXLUTHCm42DPiSuvVvpN4Ie76LQ2qbsl5ofczDifee6t1IJyXFY5d0M5AkY/CayqK7dyUJPP1F4M1lqtiMYKdBNF91u1aRDzm5Gj6nIuAWpSee5Pkx5zk7PZauLOmXOkhrUJ120EB7Rzrpv0gWZtPXxExkaTvXcxLkdN1kRbaBEtaZd@6Zjj2llDa509zA7MX85B6M/iJtQ0gJU35ZuIxn/2zYq@I3qtsg/YyXNEfode3FHOXJguZ2hjbWuPb/KzjZxn49nnRx9@Fd0HOUcvcXjhNrr0fqQu//pMLwBnLYnODWK@asQVdp5XFw1T0Z8Db9GkBwI1jlaDLyZ4Afrk64F9Hrwhwb@sck/jujk30iuctd0p@aTLuYOD@zvtyXLmVGpvJmyJ@trEJlG/rnLeYRGtkpXjfeJATNYF5pSzDKec@@LUChxavxuMaU7nPwzRp2zMy4Bf93HiO1AD2s//3v2ExJLgIzXF7lfy/@bCMUpNQz3jUmocWS9znuMKTlvyuav4OdXt03uf57PHvJ9jk@TKQHda7EfqH2ls73IWXMSNs1B/NXvL9Fw@PQOtsd7SR3CYu8QoC/NFVy4a9EZcuG@L9NcsZyxpyHmBetYK1l@ee1@lbhx9qdDN1rN@DXoFi/QpyzkjWouF9n9XzaHY401ysNQaF@1gPbM4@UJVcG5nT772Stc4GwXrCOeymJ4FW6k3ZbJ2kvfe5QzMyv6RxBVwRp/JWQwrdZXTF7twUVfuS8RjqT9hwp9ehFNfBaePOasmvVxqB@UcYFN@5pQaRZP6hNS6PHRv0e@U/klqTk10TU3OpMv@RPRzoB455DzBImfnruwv68I5QS0SMQ90ILDmUSOBZkPX/tsusTu4dHImz1Teh2gIJ69ZMF7wjZKrKjXdMahJY3JG@BhyHluswdO9FvJFwQ/LmGvhPHXRJMizxwqfM3W3Kvsm8F23M78e9YS0CZXxefYHF/Yyo95jgdc0k3PvVznbtrOmBv8/pE8HtrYTI93jjSa4TpOY01XfvP@ZHnapw@d4rsyPT7pGRXgCkn8O2Q873ip5f@p0Y25jfZTBOmTq8EMXSDQ7Xc4zUVuY4xR1oxpacogZTuduSg4Nm1cX4hepRyqcqL6cNYHR2wrevKku53Od/MnzJkzPtw0uova3mZwtAE6WcsdyfS7U/0idrSkcD/QEN@okTeEuJL63SE4/hRO2St1zkX5cp79AP5c/x9eqnG1RiaFCRzfPHWvktZr0IQJry/OjVtHAWM59kqmDXRifJc9i5XwgThl27mkxOUsnc74i54tF/oh4EbxzcBWUK43aeWreTNH9NdHabcKVmTwTUM@wzjNQNO4z5hKjn3WFcb5Pl7oZ8mA92yR7s4toP1bp5xDe8DzGq6yN54XZwvwtz2OQfjtw9qcLLinn@Kmmfu6RImcT@DNtDtXJr9RoBi44u8Sr0DsszC/yrK2VvV8dZyXoGTOL1DnLs3h/@VPNAhNeJLjtOJ9nLuRPzsb146Il0oA3Cd7hoh@NnuommvmZT0iOitxiKkdjFX0g8Xup8dhY18q4ahHdfjkLuA1iqlZ5ZhXqutOpk5n9aOh9mVLT6cJnrdLfNOR81bBJTTSUEJdnj4TqqK6sGbjWKLWe0Ymru5zBPEUXN/EJOU8ozxZz0UqG9pOdOaeppyf2LHOPZ2cGm5zBnb5LtVM7fYueE5h1xim6ol36YkU3B72psEXZD9Sfnamp@90khlDO@kp@EviTXcdusv8uY5dJjmNqJUUOP8EpkvN7rbGOnHNZeBb8VF515/PAn7qeS2VyHo2fz1fJ86nnOU5G3RP6TujFzz64LrrEsoZOtrpLP7jqShVip6ldJj2xLpxM13O1hpyvvkrPofZbFvKztX85xyL2T1MMcyHfdK7EXV24WtkX0zlnwH6B0ZmRbzectd2u58c28tRSuzVyqDnPOeFo7BlXXEZ1J8E/aIV1nC0/a8B8tH92slYFnDc1kkRzBedpZkyJM0Mq66PgR0zpZUPdDP28OEs5db5d9NP1vC7wfXBORGf/QJ4nKfwP8CWVL9D7eX8m72xlPD40Nw3fYeWswTZcMLHDx@zn@rny5io1epKPJes44209a6mT46J6P9jfqVm4kLOMOSv1fGY1zlDr0guCM7tVO3Kuwp2b1FQz6cc3je0L63h6rq3Ws5DLwDbbkLMThF@IWG6GnanG@MLkLIxWpT6p/cty1jt6txBnIT8H5jgEY07@vNgQ8MaAsQ3h5tYm8ehCXhYwAeusGYNHaPOsCdulVw/3O57pAWGep/RJI49JPhJqesCm5n8B)

Comment: Come on people, I think there are still some low hanging fruit algorithms still waiting to be picked…

Comment: Can programs hardcode the mean weight / distribution? (assume that it works equally well on similar batches, of course hardcoding everything is invalid as it destroys the purpose of limited lookahead)

Comment: @user202729: Yes they can.

Comment: And hardcoding everything is a forbidden [standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2507/60340) anyway.

Comment: I can't see what lookhead is

Comment: Also, if no time limit, no length limit, and question is clear, everyone write brute-force for best solution

Comment: @l4m2 since optimizing for the given test case is forbidden, brute-forcing a best solution is impossible. Basically this means it should work as well / properly if the test set is shuffled. The algorithm can only act on the first `n` items in the queue.

Comment: @Angs Suggest a reasonable time requirement as it's not default

Comment: @l4m2 there are only 10000 test cases with always at most seven items to choose from - I can't imagine how it could take more than a few seconds but let's say a minute to be safe.

Comment: A bounty is maybe too soon?

Comment: Now I'm more confused. What exactly is limited to 256 bits? How exactly are we supposed to return if the return value doesn't fit in memory?

Comment: @user202729: You have a bag that weights `b`. You have to fill the bag up to `t`. You have `n` items with known weight and more coming. Which of the `n` items to choose next? That's the problem.

Comment: So the algorithm can only process one bag at a time?

Comment: @user202729 yes, I'll add that clarification

Comment: I think this problem would be more interesting with a lookahead of 10 or 20.

Comment: @qwr There are tradeoffs I suppose. My reasoning was that since a bag usually holds just six items, there are diminishing returns with larger lookaheads and being a model of a physical process, larger values require more space and are more error-prone. The smaller ones put on emphasis on how to guess what's coming, whereas larger lookaheads would probably favor brute-forcing all combinations (to a point of course, as it's exponential). At that point it becomes more about time constraints than the algorithm.

Comment: Or in other words: work smarter, not harder.

Comment: Anyway it is a fun problem and there's many interesting variations: 2 fruits with different distributions, k such fruits, ability to recycle some of wasted fruit into juice, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Python 3, <s>9964</s> 9981 bags

The idea of this solution is similar to those of Jonathan, JayCe and fortraan, but with a scoring function =)

This solution appends the best subsets of the lookahead area accoring to the `score`.

`score` provides an order over the subsets using the following scheme:

- A subset completing a bag is better than one that's not
- One subset completing a bag is better than another if it has less excess weight
- One subset not completing a bag is better than another if its mean is closer to what's expected to be in a bag

`expected_mean` tries to predict what the rest of the values should look like (assuming their choice is optimal).

**UPD**:

Here is another observation: you can place any oranges from the best subset into the bag without hurting the algorithm's performance. Moving any part of it still allows to move the rest afterwards, and the remainder should still be the best option (without new oranges) if the scoring is right. Moreover, this way there is a chance to dynamically improve the set of candidates to put into the bag by seeing more oranges before filling the bag. And you want to know as much information as possible, so there is no point in moving more than one orange to the bag at any given time.

```py
import itertools as it
import math
from functools import partial
from collections import Counter


mean, std = 170, 13


def powerset(list_, max_items):
    return it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(list_, r) for r in range(1, max_items + 1))


def expected_mean(w):
    spread = std * 1
    return max(mean - spread, min(mean + spread, w / max(1, round(w / mean))))


def score(weight_needed, candidate):
    c_sum = sum(candidate)
    c_mean = c_sum / len(candidate)
    if c_sum >= weight_needed:
        return int(-2e9) + c_sum - weight_needed
    return abs(expected_mean(weight_needed) - c_mean)


def f(oranges, min_bag_weight, lookahead):
    check = Counter(oranges)

    oranges = oranges.copy()
    result = []
    bag = []

    while oranges:
        weight_needed = min_bag_weight - sum(bag)

        lookahead_area = oranges[:lookahead]
        tail = oranges[lookahead:]

        to_add = min(powerset(lookahead_area, lookahead),
                     key=partial(score, weight_needed))
        to_add = min(powerset(to_add, 1),
                     key=partial(score, weight_needed))

        bag.extend(to_add)
        for x in to_add:
            lookahead_area.remove(x)
        oranges = lookahead_area + tail

        if sum(bag) >= min_bag_weight:
            result.append(bag)
            bag = []

    assert check == Counter(oranges) + Counter(bag) + sum(map(Counter, result), Counter())

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('oranges') as file:
        oranges = list(map(int, file))
    res = [f(oranges, 1000, l) for l in range(2, 7+1)]
    print(sum(map(len, res)))
```

[Try it!](https://tio.run/##pX3bjh3JkeQ7v6KAfRhy1erJjAiPcBegfdnPEASC6q5WE@INJHtb@nrtyUw3N8uaAfZhCRBk1blkZlz8Ym5u8eVf33/9/Kn/@9/vP375/PX70/vvz1@/f/784dvTu2@PH17lrz@@@/7rq1@@fv749Mtvn3663pAvfXn39fv7dx@uV3/6/OHD80/f33/@VK//78@/fXp86atXrz4@v/v0w9O37z8//flpX9sPT3t//Pbn51@evnz@/fnrt@fvrz@8//b97Q@Py/3z7eNOPn5786dXT48/X5@///b10@N@fvzp13fvP/14XOt4w9d3f/vw/Pr49eePf3v/6d15YXzJ1zdPv3z@@vT16f2np6/vPv39@fUu3/z0h6f9zZu8/vM/vzzu@vnnt8ctvv49r/rty9fnd8fNHrf8P592vZXH97w@3vz0x3zb46vff7p@9Yf61e9P/3m@83Hhr49h@Pn1@YvHe968qWt/@@nz1@fXvz@///uv399@en7@@fnxwZ/effr5/c/vvj/nrfz09ttvH487@e3ja76WL50X/XO@5z@fPjx/evme97/kq//rz0@3K13frkP86fvrP7bnePN4iusjf7x/Qgfh3d@@vX4xdPrWN4/PXneHZ/3l9edzJr6do/X2b@/@/vb6xA9PHz5//se7Xx@jhif@9fmnfzyeKpcPPvj4puPV/Onxev7vsQK@/Ov1m7y7b799@P547S9/PX9@XOb64fzp91/ff3jGx/j8tzt/vP1@f8c0P4b@8Yu8geNP3fLbd4/p5r385U/1yl/rzd/fvf8gb6l3/Omv/MLvn9@@@zkv/pp74nYZHakf6pO3P/94/tefc1e@PlfXD/ene/Pm/3HF67eP/fn/cYX64GPMfnz@5/fnx@q/vpdXP7bnP4/teb3wp9vF7o/949fnj5//z/Prf/LTXAMvJuIP52DzDh6rH5N3bID7zN4vei2dH999@XLc7znd@vJ9Jf2Ph4389jCXWKv/dbE@bgW/Oq/@h/NGPr778jp//UNe8c0P9UaMXe6x6/XH/nk8xdu3n959fH779rjUf7x9@/FhCt@@/Y8/vdgRfzn28PtPX377/viuc4zfigncHn/e/BX75Hi7bMrj1ccCuz71gZ9qPzytP@z5sS9fjwvgQR7W5nyIw6D9@9/73F61bXu123z83V/tc7za/fi3XT8ve/z8eH09/vrjd@vx@ozH38fv57o@d7xu/fHz4288/vrjtfV4bT3@3/16fe7XZ9bxvfmzPV7r/Xrv8Px9fu/xvuM@7HGtvq77Wce1xvX95@ePezo@n/e78J7jnh/ft@L6F89idn3@uN7x/@NZLe9p5f@P9573OfOe2nWNcwycvz@uH43fcdzn8fxjXmN1vne7fuc5hudYrfzMyHuOa5wwziPv57jG8Vwjcszzfnu7xue4p/Ne2zUfuMfjfcc8WY7reQ/57/Hd83im9Zjzyesfn48cF8@xPsap5/ifn7Eca9x/zt/YrteP8cA4ev7/vJf9eo7jGUd7XPeYKxmL4/eGe8h5PJ/PrzFZWDtbzqPneK2ck5Fzin/btQaPv8f7POd9bRyLOTnu572v6/oLf/N9x9wf83eO5bye33I@jjH2ef3@nB/ZF@G5V1o@R7vW8PF@rG3L6/S8n2ONjHbOzXXdx/fF8buV379drx3/HzlHgfnO65/3Pq@1d47hfr127smR93usrX69fn73nuOB/YO9bhzf4/VjHM45XjIGS9Yg7nnlHFmuabvWuud9HWvweL5jXR@vRf7@3Kfb9doxfpHXPu9vXdc/f56ypyzHPK7Pnfe18rMt92Bc1ziuZ3n/x@8s1@xxb5Y/l00Ivu98Ls/1ZLkeQu6vX@v2XA9pP0z2XDj363Hv53tnjsfG146xHJPjaDke59hv17UPe3N8vlvaW7Gjx1yf62K728eV@/O0F5Z23jnfj99dexJr3XNvYg3nuj9fm7Thpx0w2UvYt7Cb8xrPc77TT6z8/Gk3sZa2XLsb7UTknrDLVpV/Od@T43/M28r9cd6Xc@9F2l/Y2ZW2yxvty/Ednnv3nKeetn6nHV3XHJ/@0XOuz3Wf6wO@4thPeObjM5br8njfse5O@3X4wuD1J2xG@tiV832O0Uzb1cWHwUekzVx4nsnvP6@fftbxzLneAnYxr3@M0elv0qbWmoc/7fndaVemcUxX3tfM/XXa70U7bBv998xn9hwP7LHj/xP7e0tbFrJOBuf9eP6A7XfunbhsZNuCNvLcd3Z9r@U6Ouci7QhsJGwebNtppxft/@kz0m6eczTyefE9GbOc4xRpC51reOaettzLnmNg@X1lOxfjEkubcvpi5/6yHJtl3BfH8xz75HifwR/BDuH6eM6cQ2@Mw3CN8l/wJ3uOD/xVk5hw0K/MtNvnfHeurxqDtDmnHUuffd77EN87M17CnlvXGAX2WPqK4z56xn0r94ghvjvi13xerNUu9t1n2jjELjl3Z2zll0/wvO8BX5LjGJ1xzfnvluOO2Djv29IeesaNEz4rbdEZ1@x833TaIsd@Td/ou9gq2HDEo3LfsIULtgaxQM6nd8Yknn5rpE/G@kGMEohdgz7NEcePazxH2pNz3vNZI8fk9NuI/7D2Bv3ZSn8DP/R41ms@cC@yVkc@18z9NtOHraAdgy8o@zTzuyJjKdgf8QMrY@Tzsy5rOC47ESZjmr5rTcZsM33NOd8j441JOwn/FY05DnKllXsJ91A2f6evqvGRfX@@D7Z3XX5mpZ333EMjbQzmxhBHLMbl5z047ZRhXeR4eu4z2JeVcf/a@d3ndVfudazv9CEe9FkzfbzlcyyJGWfa3jMmyrFDvLlyLSHmt52x/8rcpHxJu8djAVucNtVCcqiWc4VcZOR1neM1M65eiBf26x4NvgKxRMYqJvHyGLyPhbHu/NcyBjfZN5b7yp2@EvmMYwywjmbaQF1XsCV7rsH029O4Ppbkc46crPPePecTOUH5VuRRuVaQQ9oQ@7kzBjrnIt/ng/ONNTDgz/M7ZtqW05ZhHHN9wweXfdS8K@NYxP9r3nM1xBqnjc61jvVbMZIx14rJmN8nYyxcwxZjE0/f8PhM2xDnwv45czaXuBb23RDTIdfP@zHEbCZxae7rE1vY5bly3z1eb/tez9122I3MGxH/IFacjfvTB8f5tB@77NPEF0Lz8JAYaKdPONdY0D4g5quYMX2uJYYwGn02xuGMNRptKvLskTEf1uzM2OHMgxFj5b3HIO6DWMvzflfG65F7rOKFjAXHlHi7Mb7yXP@GOLiJTcM@SV9tXfyhMZdEjoD4YLpgIdf6OrEXxM@O9YlYFXEoxiboI2fuwZWxG2JIyz3qi2uscsHGmBQYicNuZdy@8nkMMbfYasyfDY7PHLUer/wo173DpxttMeJPH4yFV8aDZ1wv@T3wM3fuW8QG8O/H35HYhU8@10jfCfzJ0p6M3K@Y@8NWAaMEdgCfh9it4rlGn1RzPQXngo9IW1rxOuIBPFfuxYH9vCcGgxwkx2YEY2fLvXrskyMmGrBtQR82g1gfYoSKU1xwPReMLNfi7PR1ntes/bzTz838P@bM4NON@CTisGP9IdYt25v2NZDbpc/ztOfmxNpWxmGR@80HcVMT7GUOrhXFvRDfrsy7F/JeyVOwxyxxKuw/jHvl6EGs0XfBDtt1j7NLjDf5/jOuNrEbm4xxy/jLiWEAV@hp6zxzFeQAiBnhJ4HresaL1ulzT@xkMmY@59kk3x3EB2baucIO4Z9zDkz2OnwrfDlib2B8w3mtim2BfW85T4LFVb6XGPaxRsfgNWHPIvPk3M9Xnreu/RB5HeBswBB7cP0hTpmD41c4hiXOdMXXbUd8AcwVuOoSvBf50kY7Azz3HDfgWYiLjblvYP3l88DWICcBtj4a8U3kS5a@2BD7W15jFxxK8D3sG8S0vqSOg7iiXXPhWUOJfs8jsVZcYluMH/Y19q@51IhyDSDvK9tklcedMUzkPUYItoI8c1Vuf62jJlgo8ti0oSu45uaUGsES7G6XmCX9CXKZtTG/x7qDjYkumNgg3rGA5QA/EJ8NvPiYhzBiL4VzIi71a80Dc4lBjAE59WqSl@aaCcGkK08cxPVm@qKVuV/bGAfAN3lnTggccYjPPm1PCP4vNtCicrNzbJHfAkMzrBng8@t6H8ZuwE8G9y3i1rGIJbvTJ8GX@sZcumpXLrGPMzb0xLQ8xwc1J@D1WPuVk4uPQSyGvRAyZokxXM8@iM1Y2joDno9Yb9yxceTkY2d9DHk@9qoZ9/KJZSU2MxvtIfaLh2AcaTvP7zfG6HOXvDIxN0v/3rCuYZ@xfmDfE9vzKfllzltHfIq6VdoVjPMwiRmb4Nwz8efMTyLXcSSmaY15vnX6p@N6HX4964fRiIvZLvVpT9uP2Ny492PxGYHNohZ4xpfO@lKNxSb@ozH@Qv3XjWsJvg3YPWp9FswPV9ZyQnBnYBE@uS7KR2TdxPCdiz7cMp4/xyP39AiJ4WDLUcfJPepL8tW0qe7EQ8u3ddn7GZsb9pQzXirbFRKDAC8z5qiInZfktp7jgTWGmi9wvLKNg7bQYK88/Qh8nzPOWDttyq3@3pj/nhiy1E1QV0X8Nlywhca1XOPkHI8p@OkcxKNsMO5cG9cV@Ayjc94958@cc1KfM8bnkfv23M8huImJDRnkSMCeos43Zo3zmcNVjBCZ02VOrnhs1ZOA0yo2NRgzTiMnpOz44PjM4H1MiTVQt0GNGVjnHJKHq0@VtWHAq5z@auQYLNSWsV868Ukf91oG9mZhZbvUfoANB3OxEcybwdVA/QF5GXgWA2tjMQeuHDQYz6u9XpvgfCa@yHOudvqYtFFXDrEz9j9zQWfsX/4t692z0dYjZtVaG2LTY81EZ40IMcSauYdCcIzBOt5EPiw@94whYIONddEY9F0rv@@0y6hdAbtMHzmDONgI5jEdY5t7bQA7QJ1e8PtAPCZ8J1wfmBTwnLLvwFg7bXzNdeIIVZtdrH2NtBfIWZazFlicncy1gHdY2m3woGCLC7NvrPFVrNsEG96z1osYedDvhRMbB@dhBDFCxAeIcc6104RjYRVXnfEOsABgG1VjlBoN1gZwuRXEGasm6LQ5Zxwpvh05XMWEqFnYZRci7QPi68L4u@Rmg2Nf@ZwxTjXlCgErFIwjxLbBF54xVLBGf8a1GSPVXmx3/LFqvv3aDx7iJxv3DvBb1FiU@@bAAVGv7cSnV@ZqqAthXGtvAt9N@1Q4@8acBrgBMKE17zWjsRMXr7Wb78H@xdpFfoifl9N2rhDsWu5/pR8GDrykLgSbaLmWsa9Hu/NyQutIwg1E3Och9dJB7Hytim9Pu4o8YUmMgPh3mfCUZF8Vx0zwU888sMaoy5gjz3Ku2dlYL1gZT1Uds8ueHOQjgstnduXdTf1h3m8AY8u1gbrPaetHrmfk8k3s7pQY2qT26lxnsNMYR/AiXWJD4JEOjD@EQyccnliClwgPADgIYle8VvlVroORdiM21kmLM7oTV0Ld3xv3W/E34M8n@TnAf7GHEKthHmITzlVwP@HeZwj2O8mBKRzNmdOOzIE879NM9mjmacp3XE1qkuCM7szpp8SdeK/tghlsjMmBOc5FDuwSfGJujImxhubOOa98dHAPjWB9vXgi6Z@q1jpe1MqW4KNZKxtdMPxOrgrWN@z/dNYPbUlegngHdYbFsTJwJJLHaE6b5k2eAdy3JZw7yasLYwpy4IBNRa6HMy@ejDOi0Rcso9/WunH6o7Z3iaM0Ltpz7waxE98Et0LsgLWknKfOuQHn2DfGeSPjMa19jp1YJeJUYDFjiI@QHA/jCb5f5V8Sg/sQbFLijOKjDsmdxS4h9p7OuhbqCuAkFX7fBLeTuVmddv5WpxbOwmm3jDm7S0xfvHUX2x0SDznf37vwWkO4cCF5j9GHob5a9ZSNXImKF6ROC15W8oTaHszxUF/UnGHh@s66TcXCqBfs5EZVHDXFHjTaaXDCYBuA6VYNX/jMsOXAgS3I7znt0LjGC5gTMF7YnnDWghb4RZqjZ42hL9oEl94HzRtM6q3gS/ou3OUlGDFyySHcjkY7HVhbG2tgWJeoqblxfIDdr8ZrgR8F3jtifh/kWc7ktQKrmlmj8EW@qE36F8sYEHuu5jn3Puo6IyROlJoT4kIzrqHKS5PXA39eHK0mXKVNYqBOrvhMGwMMbaLuBIzIWHNHvA5ui8bG8OG2WO/oiZ@DWxc7seHqP9iJRyD/r/w3yFfwvK5n/cg789GV@yD5DhXrn7lT0E8P8ZcmuEekDYpd4kv4iCn9EE7OixnvCXklsKiq16GmJfk89rilLzbJa7tLPrvJ2nKOC@rGITXbYz119H1skq/Cl@WeG8K7WnHnLKEODttm2E/Cg0IeXz0Qk@NS9aYm@GAXjlOOeTTWN1FjdCNei5wBudiUuia4dhg73dvgUM2NnEfE9cinvbEXabjgQOA9dHKVsLYRFwz4kYxpkiNNbkPc@axaW7KN/PvK7VEPWcJN0f6ckBprflfVYEOwpMaczYTvArsfyXUtTrPwBc69npwal36Z4n2AP9rpj1HfAGcXdfgzXhr33gTYLOD@tpOftdq9fm65hlzrn4PPh1wTuNCYrBne@BdNXnPW01EHLh@Y9jqyboHaImoCxVXYyAcAv8sXcxvbyXe0kJh@3XOSqpP7tdawf88alNbcG3lC2O9rsi@q@FROfDWkHwW4iPJFwbkF9wxc4@Gs96FOOoKcg@L17uRmlc3Y@GyF63Vya5bwc@BH5k78EphU8WfzO4CDgj9SPgZ5feMeKS5hxt/VazEyfp7k8hbnbQiHdgjPtAn@nrEAcoQxxD9L3S@yPgSbA24ccqEp8fcQ7uNCncRZYwRXTbmx5vccMtjj2XZjbW6acE6BzzWpLyJ@31jXRb8h8lesn8JZ/QUHYJCvAL4ieiyWESc8YxHJC8cuHFfg6zmOiLuXk7MHW@fX95y4UEzWDMsvjfRN0muB/aH9luAYdPioJrGT2Ie5yXrE3Mv6Rs8WegAqN9rYQ7kkN1iJc4x55xlqTaJq9Lnni3vTpC900meMXWrKO/Mn5CbAw2JnDFt8kcm6mDWpm3ZyqvzA4TxrKVlnCuFc92AfDPj84MYhxojFOBLcxrGEdy05/mkHE@NcgtUVR8KIU8L/o@YNvmhxwhq5yeA4a60QP2POXWreQ/GUjF3AFyre604@ocv4YG8inse@q70zJI8EP3Qnto8xRK7hk7WcWktx9SbCxtgQnn5wz5SdC/aeow6MPYzcr3KPkJ68IP8EPabglcDmu/RVgNMeTTD9rPlWH@MSLBG8U@E5Ib6vmuaQ3G5KPQw8Er@PD@49c@@rvtpoe9AjMRJbRX6EtQZcvDivu@Tr4tvCyLOfyR0FjwK4sWvPeZecSvsPp8Sqi/lCrR/p92hOfgRiLuDoqAEs1DS8uA5n/lP8hy5c9o0xK@KvkblD@m7O3ZQ8ddzroFVHG7K@hvi7KZy8Jjmayf2kz/Yl@St4hqqVID3k4NP5Va@/ausZz501siY93IJ/B9YNNAacuAt4@djj1d8YfC7w7cGTqxihk487pF61oNsA3Qex78Ur34Uz1sj/Ob8rbRX4O97IwS4uwE6eKfj04GsVP7xxr7lw870zVl/Cc570u8WNLX7RxtoGYtiKMSfXYNWEpvBhB3NKb@xhXIoH7MRrRsbUYs9YDxTurX4e/Kyzd6hJf5FJD4oJJzI5PdWXARwybWpIfavw8104gk4Ms2pZL3gAmucA08rnPG0s4nZglOjPVtxT@f3o/0DuMZM7UDw7Z60E/WlD7BLyFuRsUzQ1EAsOie2H5Pc3PzYE82@y/hZ5oib1AlxLe1@L0wkf2O81GdgdxKvFU0d/RsacfRMuQKdNWcY6sgX1McChmkO4mcZ@torztzvvyKQ3HTg4MBYjP@Sqicw7pwF7W2Pw4lrkGIYLDpi4KfwKahja9wAfbJus3539U5HPhJ5AS25kGHvkkSMb8I@QenGX/pfGXDQkl0Q9o3D2Jtcw8fkZF1avXhMccWPfjr@s@S32UoDnC18QG/kNlY/trCEix3Tp3Ue/etUugOkt9okj1qh@kcTBq@dhY06Z/vXirELbIWtmZROb5AmZZ1SOmNe01A3A@ltBHh0494ijUCMsfoD2SA72uBR@sLGHv/RXwMEP6rkUf9alByp50SF86RBO/XLWs4f4IOAgqMMjrhqZf7Ul/c6NuWXhb4vaO9APQsyivUDzRe13bsRxwL0oPFn83TT2xqH/qfRXmsSlojdUvYtBvKuHxI@NPXwzfQv4IMgHht11iVCHUi2N4XfMpHr6RcMI8QTmcKX@D/Idl767IVyIWKJlYNzT4NsXruNcU2HkDSNmUD0M8LirNjulL0HmElxxD9qltZHPB46cJTY2RZfkmO8u/N2KH0LqmajdpzaM@rfi5AXzEnDzsZ@T@9K2RduJ@hi4E9ontkQjakl8htx2qTaVid3ugkEaexqx7isP2u9aNagrT6nNe9bCwL1DLqs5Fbgc8MmjkxuHXNwF1wIXHteveHgXPknGptAQqfoo1pv0nkJHCf1HDl8r@A/8QvHbNsFq@71neQk2E4t8uMI4JXdFDmdYE0ZbACy@uOiNtRDkI6Xts5HXUb0rcefeYp6rRiY9tEsxCiOejvwNsUpxRZpg7UG@jAXrllNsUgj/oSf/PFB7Fz2SCRz38tVtkx5pxVnBRRqLuDD6fRGjGDgZTl2D0k/bGHdXz3@XHnfln3diaODYV50v1@JZO3SpnQdz69JSaqJxJ3kX9L5cauvAwapGs0v8OslhRq6NvmdvzBmBA5SvYb9pa1lvmdJTXD2dEv@gvosYpWzRpB@2rGdO7b03/mxOLTSs1eIxv@jpxhi56Ee45IrmzF2xX3rc13W0uz4S8l7UU6r/ExwQ9Nagz3UwZyw9ELErsImxsRY30rb2QU0E5EZL@ko9qKU1hFM/XuQS0L8BnoN6SWFcUq9x6U@FzVxOXQytp0ZiAyY1ourf3kRDrXMPrY3xeOlrddEyFNta3LcusVDmRtBDqDzK6IuhFQe@ZdXynThP1fkH8TTE9MVXk75zcHE9Y13V6LKNdr40BaUvA/k34oohdWFomrn0eCDexbyY6Ip4CB4zpA9x8jlRwzLRWRyNfEr0WMwmWonZqzFEBwj4znzBCXLh51un5hb8M@w2OC9@@eLL/kK/LLgmUBcsbbjF/rXihdiL@oxTX@Lsa1/S2zA5vqUzgbxxI/58q02Y9DG35Pwvcuarj6Hz@rVWtKel3fXu0N9efEIv31Z6cHNJvCZ1TWAsIb0O0EBEzbb4@xsxv9Kj6dTPAL60tKaRPJYAP8OJfbrwqypGaHzOkb4FPXzoRZnC3cFnYwnfb7/bvNIbW8Jdc@lrmXfbv7I@6U385yb8Gh2PkF7fwfpuadQa@4dv/f@JESI/RV1rpmYi4mFw1W5@XnFI4cmiz25m73r1WotOxpQYv7jZU@ww9kn2g4b27yzRkHLpN9@o8VN58eT@ge3TWMIlLoZ@I/YA@F4dvNVc46ORv2A7@/VVX7VipMk6Bnrcp6zvJXp@wLrQg1D9QJ0@Av0@jl7SjEVCeqirb3eKdt@6a1gA30Nfn1E75sw3qy9sid9arMNOwXnAIUf@CHxxCtfi7P8d3Ku6llZnHasNcvpd9JxU0xS1BnARYYfRh42aZN@oD1aYXKMPWjlH3YUvuZObaVILcMG@puiovNSWmpJrgNdQvSmNusfVHxS0a@B0LOkPndJTUzpHaePh59d2x4DRA7AW9XVGCF9gCLdH9HpuvUeduC4wK3A/XGqZ6HtPHY6qDSypnyztXenkdceiJgh6T0qnR3VY571GWD16G3kW1R@40U8ZNI42icEb9w60Pwb4HVP0GC488MQMpvbVQy9C@JNaBwS3uGom0CBY5JJN4ZAXfqF9k/OO48JPDem3L97QTlwFNTsHzi51gyk@uuoNJv52I8cDWMrtO3PcPEQLbr/z@OFLUf89OcC530KwGewd5M9jSs@66NMh9zTpGTpzhUV@qepTFNe3E4uq/uC4c41QZ6ua3RLbutjXNJDT7HdbCt69ia4V@pmHyWfwu0X9LmCrExziKfXkJhx7J85VPNV5z0vHYg@ZSQ8C4rzqSWzEjLS/FBg5@lfQ0wWNk6V9ePGiF65JLDvI1QTnBj2DqNGZ1A1Lz6zTn5jYt9LxQwyzsUcMOnzV7yd6VsnJvurkF/528YzWi/xKbC7yjuorM8bAsMWwqaWZKP2jXTR@TLRQ0bsZu/BngxoM0Ctw6bGG9gA4mkv2YHEUJ7mxpT25U78f@zlEN/C4l77EFpvUt9Druoh5qq6h4jGw49DtgD4X@jthr116IJZokyFHWYKdQ2Oxaq8mnNFNuGWCVyGerHqnE1cOaChm/2/GQWdOBvxqCgY6nJzvoRouFxZw49tUnWoS2wRvtXqIRK9CeZLFOSJu2JpoLNj2Qod2k3ow9MwH@02Ry8x25bMGmz@EjxnUxAG/ovyD1v4x/130mFMLaIkOFupUpRvd2I917o@NnDhct7iDwVimOPbwYZ1aXYjjZvKiw7k@q9e7M8aoHuhBfwL/UfoXwuOEnYrBeCGG9EFujNGQl6NXBnEW8s/iYDTGGcUrV66N6MCBZ1Ka7pn3Thnj2NlrWLjei3wc2jWqVWXzjruiT8KkJx2xSWk@7bQLQ3SXbEh/Wxe9HJfzTEx6Izs58tpLhzh@ao3JRNtT@iRvPaiLn3fhYpcNTAxHe5Nwb2fttpPjALys@GZB7As5avUlSc3Yld/l1Fsr3NgFR93uerJTeqqK99tZT4a2IvKytB2nnbKN/bOoCRVON0TTPgSzXRIfGPXhar/tElur/lj6JGClBvvbiaG6aJpbe5GL7aIvLZot4NqVbR7sbxzjjmv5Rpuk@CT2aPUDbMJpCu5/xRLxndrjW3hlSP/uJn3Sjdo@hZtrb74zbosp2HOIvoXYwWjUn6542KRHRnRQ1wtebWlzb/w@Pa@h9n9i@NDRPPuyxN5W3t@paQUsqjji6etDtEIja8al85wavhaM74FPDDmPwge1tvS8GX1OYPDexL5M0TiDftdOXqZqAXh7odc5BVdqov80bn6W2rFd6pTt3pNX9dRd6sN2P5dlCSd3NmJBmpPBdkMXEZw81/w3iuvIMxUGbVPpV@yirRvCmezkSU/pVYEvKO2FxLqX6GSBq4G1Vfzgzj6nwm6a9JRJ7mKi4eDJ6xvoIzHhe@/MBWJ7cS6HaMxPrSeIju@UvFt1bWFbkYsPqe8gv8baM6OWGfrbSo8rpFfBRNdTdM6naLbg3JkpPrO0yiSfdWN/QGmCOfFdcGGH6M0Vhx78jMl4ONLXB/m6FzdJzheApjI03EtXXHTKYUuH5A3wZUt1zIz3nN9z6Xg4cbtIPODQ@N7bnQcEPjTuG2NdZ4FM4TdLPSNECyk6Ob@oN8J3FHY7BS9wyetd@nsX@fixS41ju8dM1Y@oezKEayLaQHqmmtY8C9s24iNLuExlV4SPUDFH1mKA1YWL/sYu/Q4mtRYnhqE@vGqTjdgP6ijAPYvz29mHXzpenXjWFH0O5WbFYP315Bx09p0g16gzENJvlvaMnOmjPe/F9wjGK6K5dvjTi1O4GE@Xn9qEh7EzLq31NSXe6HLWlmAKa8q5HNJHOqUP53a2j/ohk56dnbp5PoR3KPyEyleH8PS61D6MmpBTztsoXUvo7QzG0@BLTuc5WjhzB9gXzmyp@pRyoob0jOxS19zJa5zSZ1J4sPTMzOTkos9zip9y0TWq/Fn4x8g962yWRYzfJ@0u/Eh36sKedjX3w8ix66qTkvsjOvuwa6yH5NmpE2iCCVYMuFF3HbnGTddHz6TY2dPs0u8XEnOFcN8Lu3SpsSkvXfSU1pDzwCZ5lqXPN4WzPXjO3JQ6rTl7wwsfk95T1emqtbKENyM4puZMVY8NwVV39mWYxOhTtJVLcwF6ohv576U9rTzHKbGQ8prXvRen@D/Bvd3anVeLfvoYPPMuv//sm0PMcDu7Rs7mVFsCrnHxF9ljeeEpjXlTnUMpnLIu9QLoqi3x0@BLLeHSAz/A2Y3FP12s@aJmM6boz4u2RukDOPkNyPuKa7sXh6l6yYBVo5e2zhLYaR/AIxnQoN/Ep3SJBYKYyRR8Zhjt5MrYB5pjyquFDiJwvsKlRTM4@TKXzrBwISpX9tT3FPyo4tHsf6l6Ic7bMuaAdQZfyxht0a7f8PQhdSzpsywNJxPdu8U@ZtRA6gwk5VqCV7gLp7CxfufBPtuVOCDOFAOeiF5t1V0N0dUtXEe0tkzO2yzekZPPj3yiC7@p9leu2YpF5cwu6HWhbwe81Pr@jJkQ42EtgBMFjD2kjjzaHQeIKefMxZ3LiXwoNtrN5sJBnKKTAh5Bo19Tfl4Ee8qrL8cZU0ATyjPmicZ@XfA6pmiaxhSuVJM@50k969ilN3GT3pnGWsUEL3uynnTOy@QZIcC8UYNBHcOlVgxd6uJEAtue1JkxPf9D@laxT8eQ80DB4XOemRzbvZ@78Dfn@YylZz@IDaLnt/yEURfJVFfc5VwHY@2wL9Hr8XscUppDQT9WvJkmZ0pJfwPw71u@18kNXnHnSpvwMJacT6RciooZRQcHeQO@o/Tksh@1@MbC917af9HlfLGNOJ2J1kZpjU3R7t3uunN1Fo1TVw2aXPX@1MP1dudew8YvOV8P/QAu3GqT8w9xVmn1JblwzTbRUh6ilddFC30nxwrny0H3A3vGBrXcVG@ruB6N2lx1DhK0HXdigqWpKbiI73dtpCX1N@BMJvbRnWNVurpD8pV11xwpnvP2QvcNvAzRbtfzCHEWb@klOvlIIZiw@V2zGzYX57qF8NgOrH6Hlkx7cZZdF/5tZ64FHiVsBuo/VQtynmVR5zZJf2/Nh2gHjk6MHecWlu8Fj7Hf@73Ap68emJ3nBxUGvsmZ4MpX1nM@pQ/WRfMkpO@zuKjg7wt/eYqmldYayj5LL1U0Od8umMOb6IxCKxLc0dKjGazbDbVhi@eLFF65iX1BHNEYq3bBaPB82Dfg1tR5mYO68vBB4BMjBzOpN6zBMxoNfXXChUAeVhwU7dUyOTdYe4KH8GNQbxLMDr1xU3iifZHzihi0tAGW7L9dNL8yxizut9R3ppz1BMwfZwUXj0e0D1CbGcCSFvcuzlqdwhl3qTFB96B6HSb1Fwx9g/CtJnqCOzEo5LrD7pzf3rk/0HeDfv567k1iY9FHWqqdKbi@iU7KbOT8FX/LRRPRRO903PkeqCWhJl68kF246hv7TAtb3G5aI1fNBGc6LvacuPJqpd8EfniKTuuQulthfsjNjPNZ595KLajGZZdzN5QjYPSTwKqmcisXNflM7cVirdWaaKxAN1F0v1WbBjG/GTmqLucSoCZV5/4M6TE3OZutF@5cOUdpWJtw3VZyQCfnekgfaNXW00dUbBTsvctxuWqyJtpCm2hJu/RL5xz3yRramOxhdmD@cg7CfBE3oaYBrHwo30Q0/qtvVvQd0WtVfcBOniPyO/Tirnbnwkw5QxtrW3t8i59t5Dwbzz6/@vC76D7IOXqFwwu30aX3o3T59xd6AThrSXRuEPN1I65w8rymaJiK/hx4iyY9EKhxjJ58McEL0CffL@zz4g0J/mWdexrfW3MjvcJV2w3JJ13OHVzc32VPtjunUnszYUvU1xY2ifp1l/MOm2iV7BzvGwciWBeIkLMMQ859cWoFLq3fLcY0t/MfluhTDuZlwK/nuvEdqAHt959PPyGxJPhIQ7H7nfy/2DhGpWmoZ1xKjaPqZc5zXMFpKz53Fz@nun1673E/e8znPTYprgx0p8V@lP6RxvYuZ8Fl3BiN@qvVW6bn8ukZaIP1lrmSwzwlRtmYL7py0aA34sJ926S/ZrtjSUvOC9SzVrD@6tz7LnXj7EuFbrae9WvQK9ikT1nOGdFaLLT/p2oO5R4fkoOV1rhoB@uZxcUX6oJzO3vytVe659koWEc4l8X0LNhOvSmTtVO89ylnYHb2jxSugDP6TM5i2KmrXL7YhYu6c18iHiv9CRP@9Cac@i44fc5ZN@nlUjso5wCb8jNDahRD6hNS6/LUvUW/U/knqTkN0TU1OZOu@hPRz4F65JLzBJucnbuzv2wK5wS1SMQ80IHAmkeNBJoNU/tvp8Tu4NLJmTyhvA/REC5es2C84BsVV1VqumtRk8bkjPC15Dy2XIO3e23ki4IfVjHXxnmaoklQZ481PmfpbnX2TeCzbnd@PeoJZRM64/PqD27sZUa9xxKvGSbn3u9ytu1kTQ3@f0mfDmztJEZ6xhtDcJ0hMaervvn8b3rYpQ5f47kzP77pGjXhCUj@uWQ/nHir5P2l0425zfXRFuuQpcMPXSDR7HQ5z0RtYY1T1o16askhZriduyk5NGxe34hflB6pcKLmdtcERm8rePOmupwvdfKD502Ynm@bXETtbzM5WwCcLOWO1frcqP9ROlshHA/0BA/qJIVwFwrf2ySnD@GE7VL33KQf1@kv0M/lL/G1LmdbdGKo0NGtc8cGea0mfYjA2ur8qF00MLZ7n2TpYDfGZ8Wz2DkfiFOW3XtaTM7SqZyvyflimT8iXgTvHFwF5Uqjdl6aNyG6vyZau0O4MsEzAfUM6zoDReM@Yy6x5l1XGOf7TKmbIQ/Ws02qN7uJ9mOXfg7hDcc1Xm0fPC/MNuZvdR6D9NuBsx8uuKSc46ea@rVHmpxN4C@0OVQnv1OjGbhgTIlXoXfYmF/UWVs7e78mzkrQM2Y2qXO2F/H@9l81C0x4keC243ye2MifjMH146IlMoA3Cd7hoh@NnuohmvmVT0iOitwilKOxiz6Q@L3SeBysa1VctYluv5wFPBYxVes8swp13XDqZFY/GnpfQmo6U/isXfqblpyvmjZpiIYS4vLqkVAd1Z01A9capdYzJnF1lzOYQ3RxC5@Q84TqbDEXrWRoP9mdc1p6emLPKvd4cWawyRnc5btUO3XSt@g5gVVnDNEVndIXK7o56E2FLap@oPniTE3d7yYxhHLWd/KTwJ@cOnbB/ruKXYIcx9JKyhw@wCmS83ttsI5cc9l4Fnwor3ryeeBPXc@lMjmPxu/nq9T51HGPk1H3hL4TevGrD26KLrGsoZutntIPrrpSjdhpaZdJT6wLJ9P1XK0l56vv0nOo/ZaN/GztX66xyP0zFMPcyDeNnbirC1er@mIm5wzYLzA6M/LtlrO2O/X82EGeWmm3Zg4Vcc8J12DPuOIyqjsJ/sForOMc@dkA5qP9s8FaFXDe0kgSzRWcp1kxJc4M6ayPgh8R0suGuhn6eXGWcul8u@in63ld4PvgnIjJ/oE6T1L4H@BLKl9gzvv@LN7Zznh8aW6avsPaXYNtuWBil485z/Vz5c11avQUH0vWccXbetbSJMdF9X6wv0uzcCNnGXPW@v3MapyhNqUXBGd2q3Zk7MKdC2qqmfTjm8b2jXU8PddW61nIZWCbbcnZCcIvRCwXaWe6Mb4wOQtjdKlPav@ynPWO3i3EWcjPgTkuwZiLPy82BLwxYGxLuLl9SDy6kZcFTMAma8bgEVrcNWGn9OrhftcLPSDMc0ifNPKY4iOhpgdsKl79Xw)

Comment: Very nice! It gets 1672 with a lookahead of 7, never seen one that high.

Comment: (it looks like that the second argument to your `powerset` function is redundant in this case because it's equal to `len(list_)` anyway?)

Comment: @user I experimented with this parameter in the previous version. Will probably remove it later

Comment: Congratulations on discovering the powerful combination of best single element out of the best subset and also having the best score! The bounty is yours.

Comment: A simpler `expected_mean(w)` that gives as good results: `return  (w+2) / max(1, round((w+2) / mean))`

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 9796 bags

Building on Jonathan's answer:

```python
import itertools as it

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def f(a,m,l):
 r=[];b=[]
 while a:
  c =  min(list(powerset(a[:l])),key=lambda w: abs(sum(b)+sum(w)-m))
  if sum(c)==0:
   c = a[:l]
  b+=[a.pop(a.index(min(c,key=lambda w: abs(sum(b)+w-m))))]
  if sum(b)>=m:r+=[b];b=[]
 return r
```

This relies on powerset from itertool's cookbook. First finds optimal subset of the buffer based on minimizing difference from target weight for all subsets, and then picks an element out of this subset based on same criterion. If no optimal subset selects from the whole buffer.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks Martin for the welcoming upvote :)

Comment: Ah yes I missed a trick there... I have no problem with this as another answer!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks Jonathan I've shortened my answer to credit you without all the apologies. This can be improved by using the fact that it's a normal(170,13) distribution - I'm sure the probability of getting a better fruit in the next run(s) can be used.

Comment: @JayCe sounds dangerously close to gambler's fallacy.

Comment: this new answer looks suspiciously like mine...

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/162852/4

Comment: @qwr You are correct! Scrolling down I realize this was your 9947 answer. I reverted it.

Comment: I don't mind if you build off my answer, just some attribution would be nice.

Answer (score 6):

## C++17, 9961.58 <sub>(average over some random seeds)</sub>

(scroll down for explanation if you don't know C++)

```cpp
#include<iostream>

#include<vector>
#include<random>

std::mt19937 engine(279); // random engine
// random distribution of the oranges
std::normal_distribution dist (170.,13.);

int constexpr N_NEW_ORANGES=7;

/** Input format: Current remaining weight of the bag (remain) and 
the weight of the oranges (weights)
Output: the index of the orange to be pick.
*/
struct pick_orange{
    std::vector<int>weights,sum_postfix;int remain;

    /// returns {min excess, mask}, (index) is the LSB
    std::pair<int,int> backtrack(int index, int remain) {
        if(sum_postfix[index]<remain)return {1e9,0};
        int min_excess=1e9, good_mask=0;
        for(int next=index;next<N_NEW_ORANGES;++next){
            if(weights[next]==remain){
                return {0, 1<<(next-index)};
            }else if(weights[next]>remain){
                if(weights[next]-remain<min_excess){
                    min_excess=weights[next]-remain;
                    good_mask=1<<(next-index);
                }
            }else{
                auto[excess,mask]=backtrack(next+1,remain-weights[next]);
                if(excess<min_excess){
                    min_excess=excess;
                    good_mask=(mask<<1|1)<<(next-index);
                }
            }
        }
        return {min_excess,good_mask};
    } 

    int ans;

    pick_orange(std::vector<int> weights_,int remain_)
        :weights(std::move(weights_)),remain(remain_){

        int old_size=weights.size();

        std::vector<int> count (N_NEW_ORANGES, 0);
        weights.resize(N_NEW_ORANGES, 0);

        sum_postfix.resize(N_NEW_ORANGES+1);
        sum_postfix.back()=0;

        for(int _=0; _<500; ++_){

            for(int i=old_size;i<N_NEW_ORANGES;++i)
                weights[i] = dist(engine);

            // prepare sum postfix
            for(int i=N_NEW_ORANGES;i-->0;)
                sum_postfix[i]=weights[i]+sum_postfix[i+1];

            // auto[excess,mask]=backtrack(0,remain);
            int mask = backtrack(0,remain).second;

            for(int i=0; 

                mask
                // i < N_NEW_ORANGES

                ; mask>>=1, ++i){

                // if(mask&1)std::cout<<'(';
                // std::cout<<weights[i];
                // if(mask&1)std::cout<<')';
                // std::cout<<' ';

                count[i]+=mask&1;
            }

            // std::cout<<"| "<<remain<<" | "<<excess<<'\n';

        }

        std::vector<double> count_balanced(old_size, -1);
        for(int i=0;i<old_size;++i){
            if(count_balanced[i]>-1)continue;
            int sum=0,amount=0;
            for(int j=i;j<old_size;++j)
                if(weights[j]==weights[i]){sum+=count[j];++amount;}

            double avg=sum;avg/=amount;
            for(int j=i;j<old_size;++j)
                if(weights[j]==weights[i])count_balanced[j]=avg;
        }

        ans=old_size-1;
        for(int i=ans;i-->0;)
            if(count_balanced[i]>count_balanced[ans])ans=i;
        // Fun fact: originally I wrote `<` for `>` here and wonder
        // why the number of bags is even less than that of the
        // randomized algorithm
    }

    operator int()const{return ans;}
};


#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>

int main(){
    // read input from the file "data"
    std::ifstream data ("data");
    std::vector<int> weights;
    int weight;while(data>>weight)weights.push_back(weight);

    int constexpr BAG_SIZE=1000;
    int total_n_bag=0;
    for(int lookahead=2;lookahead<=7;++lookahead){
        auto weights1=weights;
        std::reverse(weights1.begin(),weights1.end());

        int remain=BAG_SIZE,n_bag=0;
        std::vector<int> w;
        for(int _=lookahead;_--;){
            w.push_back(weights1.back());
            weights1.pop_back();
        }
        while(!weights1.empty()){
            int index=pick_orange(w,remain);

            remain-=w[index];
            if(remain<=0){
                ++n_bag;remain=BAG_SIZE;

                if(n_bag%100==0)
                    std::cout<<n_bag<<" bags so far..."<<std::endl;
            }
            w[index]=weights1.back();weights1.pop_back();
        }

        while(!w.empty()){
            int index=pick_orange(w,remain);
            remain-=w[index];
            if(remain<=0){++n_bag;remain=BAG_SIZE;}
            w.erase(w.begin()+index);
        }

        std::cout<<"lookahead = "<<lookahead<<", "
            "n_bag = "<<n_bag<<'\n';
        total_n_bag += n_bag;
    }

    std::cout<<"total_n_bag = "<<total_n_bag<<'\n';
}
```

> // Fun fact: originally I wrote `<` for `>` here and wonder
>   // why the number of bags is even less than that of the
>   // randomized algorithm

(if `<` is used basically the algorithm tries to *minimize* the number of bags)

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853848).

TIO link for 250 repetitions: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tX1rbx1Xlt13/oobB4nJ1sNV531MUcBM0Bk0EPQA6Q8B0jHUtETL7JZIgaRsdzz@6@lUndprr1WX9HRmgBiQJfLWrcepc/Zj7bXXefvp04v3b9/@7W//8frm7YfP765e/XD19uH27vWJ/@Lu8ubd7cfXJyf3D@@@/vrjw9x7rIerm/fXN1enofaz88NXXx22o@zXJ/zFu@v7h7vrbz8/XN/eHG6/Ozx8f3W4XT57f3W/nfDm9u7j5Yc3u@PWHw6nc51ePp/jy7Pzk5Prm4fD29ub@4ernz7dHX7/5ve//R9v/vm//8Pv/@m3f7ioy@df/eY3h9/dfPr8cPhuPd/D14f/8vnu7mr51t3Vx8vrm@ub94cfr67ff/@Am/j28v3hdPvw7LDc6@Fk/e3@GLvRw@n26/uzk3/@/LBc5Ovx6fXNu6uf9oceHm4P314dPl2//cvLk998tTzh3ee3D@PnN9sRP58clv/Gk28j/Wp5tNd2/uf3nz@@@XR7//Dd9U/n137zy/OtX/pqHdWrh893N/eHnz9e3xyufnp7dX///PDx8v4vvzw/nI4bOjtc3487@m9/@Ede69Pl9bjS8/Vqy7O//cvD3fK/0/Ui42vPD7ze2WG7y/W/6@9O5ab@OI795pUdt93N4ef5qj@ffjnnl5ZTLTf4ZrvBi/Xjw/vb23dv1ju9mHjg8rLGLdxc/fRwMc59vv7z1e4Fnz97tv7yjDdlN2aj9sf1028uLuym9oet/@E2p@eH@dWr0/XwF9tYyT2v//1y9eH@6tGZX//qiY@PfLEd@YrP/sSX1v9kcJ46wfmTX@IIHj3F48N/efxYj2/k8vPD7R9tDq2n/eaC82I9@7P5@XY7L3b3@MTllnHYzvNvevLtr7/3rKfr/1@9mv9lPvs3PvXJ439hJvAunvuVbC78cthW2zotL2/ube3JCj49XrxmNO7fPOcSenPm1/zaPt6@9/H2hytMmjdnZzbCp/jWzye7RXT74d2b@@v/fYVZ8nL94fTsnEc9upm3t5@XL57uVtDzwyTDhXPdXY2zPXEkz86l/@Thz2Y5rx68zqTTs3WpP1rrb5bfHt68Cnn569mz3SPrYdcXePjz60f24Prs0cvHHL3@5nAxHMjp5ov0cTYrevh0d/Xp8u5qveGD3fCv3ML@utcvXryezh9femcgv7ngnTzbffJs/ubxvfxri3Cy2XE01Yd1XQ5dnvOJY1/eXy2O8t35r43qMuonj55gPd2jXy53d314tXe2j796Pr78@vXF/PywvpifT5480XdjHf/n@WxM2GWSPrx69eXpl@dPHSyHcCzP/99Pe/Z3T/vl4cvzx/c5ls762i62kx45h0fvTk74xb8cvnhlbnH56TB@NJv46sv/daOX@@Xp1fvu9vO3H65sAb/59vLD5c3bq3enWAXPDy90sekLvX7lS2V7A0e2eX/G5QFfL6daJsnD9c3nq8dza5m0F9Pzy4/rt9RZ62X/fHF9/me97J/P/jXv@OfFPfNVnv28XOLZxTbcf/5m@fZ2sfOjId5G5HD5w/uL5Qvny99fXdiR/x9u6miUlk@XC54/9dYWt@DG6cX81DtZHcdT1uLJl3H0m@W735ytl7jmmZfJ9l8/3xy@u3y7xJ63d9eLYbv88OGvh98dfry7fbg6/OnVn9arH/70@k@H768W07YGtD8uZuDqTs/x4/d/HaHhzeeP317draHrEgXfrwHj1Q9XN4cPy2xdPr@8Wf@HIFi/v8X0y1O/O1x@eL/cx8P3H09kcG4/Xd1dLnN5nUanZyNe/9lc7joiv5wsPpaZxvViGO@uLj9KrvHdo9/4dV5vScDwljAyY/lc25cO7y4fLg@nX3z17uqHr5ZPrm@@sPXyaw773B399ovzH7@//nB1up7ntYXkZ3CWnz7ff/9meDX74JxhAhOTf/yHf3rzh9/9z99ezNM08fQPtw9LinOzfP89FhTmyofb279cfn91@e4inPu/Xy05zbNn/qOs6NVd4Pbni91z@JPeLS/z7t6jjPnlt1fv10F77r@4unl3eqaOkYHLBR7h@e52nx7G8yecu9/1@ZsXL86PjNGPj8Zxvb0RKxw5Of/00@2n7fiz8ycCuu2N/Qc@2cdPD39dTvbzI6s2gsYLjeN@pHs92acLI@i9@NGynfPjJWxm/mJ6IsZdcpV13M6PRvMJb7OcaBz6n5a5crGc68k4WFzMOHj1LWPN3t8u1uDu5cuXi58ZBy3v9MP5ya@Hw3iai6NxP/87I/1oqP@9Y/zvHeJfG9Gjx3u5mJ510mO2PzvOEo7drjlun69LOLWMJdfgqy@eH77YXeOLcSPbcfY2NteOA2SdH55dHLb7VgOpF9aDxynlFzjxL3@by3QSpulkzmX5M5/MJZ3Mbf07bD/XvPy8fF6XP235XV0@L335s/y@1O176@c5Lj8vf/rypy2f1eWzuvw7tu3zMm/fqet57ee8fBbjdmxq9ns773rceh95uVas2/3U9VppO//4/npP6/ftfiuOWe95OV/t2994lpy376/XW/@9Pmu2e6r27/XYcZ/F7ils1xhj0Pj79fo98Bzrfa7Pn8o2VuPYaftdszEcY1XtO8nuuW/jhHFOdj/rNdbnSt3G3O43hm181nsa9xq294F7XI9b31O2cR33YH@v5y7rM9XlnRdef/1@t3FpNtbrOEUb//GdbGON@7f3l6bt83U8MI7N/j3uZd6eY33GFJbrru9KxmL9fcY92Hscz9e2MamYO5O9x2bjVe2dJHun@Dtsc3D9sx7X7L3XiWNRCsd93Hvdrl/xx45b3/36/sZYlu35s72PdYxb2X4/3o@si95srQR7jrDN4fV4zO1s14l2P@scSWG8m@26y/n6@rtq55@2z9Z/J3tHHe/brj/uvWxzb4zhvH021mSy@13nVtw@H@eebTywfrDWM8d3/Xwdh/GOq4xBlTmIe672jrLN6bzN9Wb3tc7B9fnWeb1@1u33Y51O22fr@HW79ri/ul1//FxkTWUb8759b9xXte8GW4N9u8Z6vWz3v/4u25xd7y3bz24TOo8bz9VsPmWbD13uL27zdswHsx9Z1lxvXK/rvY9ji43HxM/WsUyF45htPMbYT9u1V3uzfj9ms7diR9d3PebFtLeP1dbnsBfZ7Hzj@15@t61JzPVmaxNz2Ob9@KzQhg87kGUtYd3CbpZtPMf7Nj9R7fvDbmIuTTZ3J9qJbmsib7bK/cs4xsZ/fW/V1se4r8a1183@ws5Ws10t0L6s52i2dsd7imbrZ9rRur3j4R@bvesx721@wFes6wnPvH4n27xcj1vn3bBfqy/svH6BzTAfW@19jzEqZrui@DD4CLOZFc9TeP5xffOzDc9s863DLtr11zEa/sZsqs95@NNo5za7UjLHtNp9FVtfw35X2uE80X8Xe@Zm44E1tv67YH1PZsu6zJPE974@f4ftb1w7fbORYeq0kWPd5e282ebReBdmR2AjYfNg24adrrT/w2eY3RzvKNnz4jwWs4xx6mYLG@dwsTWdbS03G4Ns53PbWRmXZLMpwxc3rq9sY1Mz18X6POs6WY/L8EewQ7g@ntPeYQuMw3AN91/wJ7OND/xVkJgw0a8Us9vjfUfOLx8DsznDjpnPHveexPcWi5ew5uo2Rh1rzHzFeh/R4r5qayQjvlvjV3tezNUo9r0Vs3GIXezdjdiqbT6h2X0n@BIbxx4Z14y/Jxt3xMZ239nsYbO4scBnmS0acc3M40qjLWpYr@Yb2yy2CjYc8ajcN2xhha1BLGDvs0XGJM38VjKfjPmDGKUjdu30aQ1xfNrGM5k9Ge/dnrXbmAy/jfgPcy/Rn1XzN/BDy7Nu7wP3InM12XMVW2/FfFjttGPwBW6fip2rWywF@yN@oFqMPL7bZA73zU70LGNqvqsWxmzFfM1438nijUI7Cf/VA3Mc5ErV1hLuwW3@TF/l4yPrfhwH21s3P1PNzjdbQ8lsDN5NRhxRGZePe2i0Uxnzwsaz2TqDfakW99eZ5x7XrbbWMb/Nh7ROn1XMx2d7jioxYzHbO2IiGzvEm9XmEmL@PDP2r5abuC8J@3iswxabTc1dcqhg7wq5SLLrNo5Xsbi6Il6Yt3vM8BWIJSxWyRIvp8T7qBjryL@zxeBZ1k22ddUafSXymYYxwDwqZgN1XsGWzDYHzW@XzPlRJZ9ryMki773Z@0RO4L4VeZTNFeSQOYn9nBkDjXdhx7XE9405kODP7RzFbMuwZRhHm9/wwW4fNe@yOBbxfy37XA2xxrDRNtcxfz1Gysy1emHM3wpjLFwjV8YmzXzD8p0wIc6F/WvM2ZrEtbDvGTEdcn27n4yYLUtcaut6YAuzPJetu@XzMM/@3GGG3bC8EfEPYsUSuD5b4jgP@zHLOjV8oWse3iUGmukTxhzrtA@I@TxmNJ@bDUNIgT4b4zBijUCbijw7WcyHOVssdhh5MGIsu/eeiPsg1mp2v9Xi9W5rzOMFiwVTkXg7ML5qNv8z4uAgNg3rxHx1juIPM3NJ5AiID0oTLGSbXwN7QfzcMD8RqyIOxdh0@shia7Ba7IYYMtsabZVzzHPBwJgUGEmD3bK4vdrzZMTcYqvx/nLi@JTk83HLj2zeN/j0TFuM@LMlxsLV4sER10t@D/ysNa5bxAbw7@ufZNhFK3yuZL4T@FM2e5JsveLdr7YKGCWwA/g8xG4ezwX6JH/XRXAu@AizpR6vIx7Ac9laTFjPs2EwyEFsbFJn7Jxtra7rZI2JEmxbpw8rnVgfYgSPU5rgek0wMpuLJdLXNbumr@eZfq7Yv/HOMnx6Jj6JOGydf4h13faafe3I7cznNbPnuRFrqxaHdVtvLRE3zYK9lMS5orgX4ttqeXdF3it5CtZYNpwK6w/j7jl6J9bYZsEOw3aPJUqMV3j8iKuz2I1JxjhY/NWIYQBXiGbrmuUqyAEQM8JPAtdtFi/mSJ87sJPCmHm85yz5biI@UMzOOXYI/2zvIMtah2@FL0fsDYwvNV7LY1tg35O9J8HiPN8zDHudoynxmrBn3fJkW89bnle39dDtOsDZgCHGzvmHOKUkjp/jGNlwpi2@DjPiC2CuwFWr4L3IlybaGeC5Y9yAZyEuzsx9O@afPQ9sDXISYOspEN9EvpTNF2fE/tmuMQsOJfge1g1i2laljoO4ImzvolkNpcd9Hom50iS2xfhhXWP95iY1IpsDyPvcNmXP40YM0@0eexdsBXlm9dx@m0dBsFDksWZDa@ecK0VqBFWwu1liFvMnyGXqxPwe8w42pkfBxBLxjgosB/iB@Gzgxet76JnYi@OciEvbNueBufREjAE5dQ2Sl9qc6YJJe56YiOsV80XVcr8wMQ6Ab2qROSFwxCQ@e9ieLvi/2MDcPTcbY4v8FhhaxpwBPl@34zB2CX6yc90ibk2VWHJr9EnwpW1iLu21qyaxT2Ns2AzTajY@qDkBr8fc95xcfAxiMayFLmNmGMP27InYTDZbl4HnI9ZLe2wcOXmaWR9Dno@1mjPX8sCyDJspgfYQ66V1wTjMdo7zZ8boZZa80jC3bP49YF7DPmP@wL4btteK5Jf23iLiU9StzK5gnFOWmDEIzl0Mf7b8pNs87oZp5sA8P0f6p/V6EX7d6oc9EBfLs9Snm9l@xOaZa79XPiOwWdQCR3zZWF/ysZjEfwTGX6j/tsy5BN8G7B61vtyZH1ar5XTBnYFFtMJ54T7C6iYZ56z04dni@TEetqZTlxgOthx1HFujrUq@aja1NeKh7tuirH2LzTPWVGO85LarSwwCvCwzR0XsXCW3bTYemGOo@QLHc9uYaAsz7FUzPwLf1xhn1Jk2ZVd/D8x/B4YsdRPUVRG/pSbYQuBc9nFqHI8i@GlJxKNyYtxZJ84r8BlS5Htv9v5y4zvx72XG593W7VjPXXCTLDYkkSMBe4o6Xyo@ziOH8xihW05nObnisV5PAk6r2FRizFgyOSFuxxPHp3TeR5FYA3Ub1JiBdZYkebj6VJkbGXhVo79KNgYVtWWsl0h8sqV9LQNr07GyWWo/wIY7c7HUmTeDq4H6A/Iy8CwS5kZlDuw5aGc8r/a6ToLzZfFFzd7VTB9jNmrLIWbG/iMXbIz93b9ZvbsE2nrErFprQ2y6zpkeWSNCDFGLraEuOEZiHa8gHxafO2II2ODMumhP9F3VzjfsMmpXwC7NR5ZOHCx15jERY2trLQE7QJ1e8PuOeEz4Trg@MCngOW7fgbFG2nh/14YjeG22svaVzF4gZ6mNtUDn7FiuBbwjm90GDwq22DH7wBqfx7pBsOHZar2IkRP9Xm/ExsF5SJ0YIeIDxDhj7gThWGSPq0a8AywA2IbXGKVGg7kBXK524oxeE2y0OSOOFN@OHM5jQtQs8mYXutkHxNeO8UfJzRLH3vO5zDg1K1cIWKFgHF1sG3zhiKE6a/QjrrUYyddi2OOPXvON23poXfxk4NoBfosai3LfGnBA1Gsj8elquRrqQhhXX5vAd80@Oc4@MacBbgBMqJZ9zSjNxMV97toxWL@Yu8gP8XNttJ21C3Yt91/NDwMHrlIXgk3MNpexrlPY83K61pGEG4i4r3WplyZi57V6fDvsKvKEKjEC4t@ahack68o5ZoKfNssDfYyijDnyrMY5WwLrBdXiKa9jRlmTiXxEcPly3vLuoP7Q7rcDY7O5gbrPsPXJ5jNy@SB2t0gMnaX22jjPYKcxjuBFNokNgUc2YPxdOHTC4elV8BLhAQAHQeyKzzy/snmQzG70iXVS54zOxJVQ92@B6835G/Dnhfwc4L9YQ4jV8B76JJyrzvWEey9dsN9CDozjaI05bbIcqNl95ixr1PI05TvWIDVJcEZn5vRF4k4cm2fBDCbG5MAcSyUHtgo@USbGxJhDZeY793w0cQ2lzvq680TMP3mtNR3Vyqrgo1YrS1Ew/EiuCuY37H9prB/mKnkJ4h3UGSrHKoMjYTzG3GjTWpBnAPetCudO8mrHmDo5cMCmus2HkRcXxhk90BfUTL@tdWPzR2GOEkdpXDTb2u3ETtokuBViB8wl5TxFvhtwjtvEOC9ZPKa1zzQTq0ScCiwmJfERkuNhPMH38/xLYvCWBJuUOMP5qElyZ7FLiL1LY10LdQVwkhy/D4LbybupkXZ@V6cWzsKwW5k5e5OY3nnrTWx3l3io8fgYhdfahQvXJe/J9GGor3o9ZSJXwuMFqdOCl2U8oTB35nioL2rOUHH9xrqNx8KoF8zkRnkcVcQeBNppcMJgG4Dpeg1f@Myw5cCBcye/Z9ihtI0XMCdgvLA9vbEWVMEv0hzdagyx0iY06X3QvCFLvRV8yTYLd7kKRoxcMgm3I9BOd8ytiTUwzEvU1Frm@AC7r4HXAj8KvHfE/C2RZ1mM1wqsqliNolXyRXOhf8kWA2LN@Xu2tY@6TuoSJ0rNCXFhzpxDnpcarwf@3DlaQbhKk8RAkVzxYjYGGFpB3QkYUWbNHfE6uC0aG8OH58p6RzT8HNy6PhMb9v6DmXgE8n/Pfzv5Cs2u26x@1CLz0WrrwPgOHuuP3KnTTyfxl1lwj242qM8SX8JHFOmHaOS85Mx7Ql4JLMrrdahpST6PNZ7NF2fJa2OTfHaSudU4Lqgbd6nZrvMpou9jknwVvszWXBLeVe17zhLq4LBtGetJeFDI470HonBcvN4UBB@MwnGyMe@B9U3UGFsmXoucAblYkbomuHYYO13b4FCViZxHxPXIp1tgL1JqggOB9xDJVcLcRlyQ4EcspjGONLkNfc9n1dpSnsi/99we9ZAq3BTtz@lSY7VzeQ22C5YUmLNl4bvA7nfjujqnWfgCY60bp6ZJv4zzPsAfjfTHqG@As4s6/IiX0r43ATYLuH@eyc@qYV8/zzaHmtY/E58PuSZwoVRYM9zxL4J81lhPRx3YfaDZ6251C9QWURNwrsJEPgD4Xa0yt8kz@Y65S0xf9zmJ18nbNtewfkcNSmvugTwhrPda2BflfKpGfLVLPwpwEeWLgnML7hm4xqmx3oc6aerkHDivdyY3y23GxGdzXC@SW1OFnwM/Umbil8CknD9r5wAOCv6I@xjk9YFrxLmEFn97r0Wy@LmQy@uctyQc2iQ80yD4u8UCyBFSEv8sdb9u9SHYHHDjkAsVib@TcB8r6iSNNUZw1ZQbm9s@h@zs8QxzZm2uZOGcAp8LUl9E/D6xrot@Q@SvmD@Os7YjDkAiXwF8RfRY1EyccMQikhemWTiuwNdtHBF310bOHmxd284zcKFeWDN0v5TMN0mvBdaH9luCYxDho4LETmIfyiTzEe9e5jd6ttAD4LnRxB7KKrlBNZwjlT3PUGsSXqO3Ne/cmyB9oYU@I81SU56ZPyE3AR7WZ8awzhcprIvlIHXTSE5VW3G4ZrUUqzN14VzHzj4Y8PnBjUOM0SvjSHAbUxXeteT4ww4axlkFq3OORCZOCf@Pmjf4os4JC@Qmg@OstUL8jHfepOadFE@x2AV8Iee9zuQTNhkfrE3E81h3vnaS5JHgh87E9jGGyDVaYS3H51LfehNhY3ISnn7nmnE719l7jjow1jByP889uvTkdfJP0GMKXglsfpO@CnDaexBM32q@3sdYBUsE71R4TojvvaaZJLcrUg8Dj6Ttxwf3brn3Vl8NtD3okUiGrSI/wlwDLu6c11nydfFtPZNnX4w7Ch4FcOOmPedRcirtPywSq1bmCz5/pN8jNPIjEHMBR0cNoKKm0ZzrMPIf5z9E4bJPjFkRfyXLHcx3890VyVPTvg7qdbQk8yuJvyvCyQuSo2W5H/PZrUr@Cp6haiVIDzn4dG2r12@1dYvnRo0sSA@34N8d8wYaA424C3j5WOPe39j5XODbgyfnMUIkHzdJvapCtwG6D2LfnVc@C2cskP8zzmW2CvydFsjBdi7ATJ4p@PTgazk/PHCtNeHmt8hYvQrPudDvOjfW@UUTaxuIYT3GLJyDXhMqwodNzClbYA9jVTxgJl6TLKYWe8Z6oHBv9fvgZ43eoSD9RVl6ULJwIo3T430ZwCHNpnapbzl@PgtHsBHD9FrWEQ9A8xxgWvacw8YibgdGif5sxT2V34/@D@QexbgDzrNrrJWgPy2JXULegpytiKYGYsEksX2S/H7nx5Jg/kHmXyVPNEu9ANfS3lfndMIHxn1NBnYH8arz1NGfYTFnnIQLEGlTamYdOXfqY4BDVZJwMzP72TzOn/a8oyy96cDBgbFk8kO2mkjZcxqwtjUGd66FjWFvggMabgq/ghqG9j3AB@dJ5u/M/qluz4SewGzcyJ7ZI48cOQP/6FIvjtL/EpiLdsklUc9wnD3INbL4fIsLvVcvCI44sW@nHdf8KnspwPOFL@gT@Q2ej82sISLHbNK7j351r10A06vsE0es4f0ihoN7z8PEnNL868ZZhbaD1czcJgbJEyzP8BzRrplNNwDzr3by6MC5RxyFGqHzA7RHMrHHxfGDiT38rr8CDn6nnovzZ5v0QBkvugtfugunvjbWs5P4IOAgqMMjrkqWf4Uq/c6BuaXjb5XaO9APQsyivUDlqPZbJuI44F44niz@rmT2xqH/yfVXgsSlojfkvYudeFfsEj8G9vAV8y3ggyAfSHmvS4Q6lGpppLbHTLynXzSMEE/gHVbT/0G@06TvLgkXolfRMshc0@DbO67TOKd6Jm8YMYPqYYDH7bXZIn0J8i7BFW@ddqlO5POBI5cNGyuiS7K@7yj8XY8futQzUbs3bRj1b87J68xLwM3HejbuS5gqbSfqY@BOaJ9YFY2oKvEZctuq2lRZ7HYUDDKzpxHz3vOgea9Vg7pykdp8s1oYuHfIZTWnApcDPjlFcuOQizfBtcCFx/U9Hp6FT2KxKTREvD6K@Sa9p9BRQv9Rg68V/Ad@wfltk2C1cd@zXAWb6ZV8OMc4JXdFDpcxJzJtAbB456IH1kKQj7i2z0Reh/eu9D33Fu/Za2TSQ1sVo8jE05G/IVZxrkgQrL2TL5M765ZFbFIX/kM0/nlH7V30SApw3M1Xh0l6pBVnBRcpVeLC6PdFjJLByWjUNXD9tIlxt/f8R@lxV/55JIYGjr3X@Wwujtphk9p5Z27tWkpBNO4k74LeV5PaOnAwr9HMEr8WcpiRa6PvuQXmjMAB3New3zQEq7cU6Sn2nk6Jf1DfRYzitqjQD2erZxbtvc/8OTdqoWGuOo/5qKcbY9REP6JJrpgbc1esl9j387qHvT4S8l7UU7z/ExwQ9NagzzUxZ3Q9ELErsIl9Yi0umW2NiZoIyI2q9JW2Ti2tJJz6dJRLQP8GeA7qJY5xSb2mSX8qbGZt1MXQemo3bCBLjcj7tyfRUItcQ3ViPO76WlG0DMW2OvctSixkuRH0EDyPyvTF0IoD39Jr@Y04j9f5E/E0xPTOV5O@c3Bxm8W6qtGVJ9p51xSUvgzk34grktSFoWnWpMcD8S7eSxZdkdYFj0nSh1j4nKhhZdFZTIF8SvRYlCBaidarkUQHCPhOOeIENeHn50jNLfhn2G1wXtrmizf7C/2yzjmBuqBrw1X2rzkvJB/VZxr1JUZfe5XehsLxdZ0J5I0T8eddbSJLH3Mwzn8lZ977GCKv73NFe1rCXu8O/e3OJ2zu21wPrlSJ16SuCYylS68DNBBRs3X@/kTMz/VoIvUzgC9VrWkYj6WDn9GIfTbhV3mMEPicyXwLevjQi1KEu4Pv9ip8v3lv81xvrAp3rUlfS9nb/mr1yRbEf07Cr9Hx6NLrm1jfdY3azP7hXf@/YYTIT1HXKqaZiHgYXLWdn1ccUniy6LMr1rvuvdaik1EkxndudhE7jHVi/aBd@3eqaEg16TefqPHjeXHh@oHt01iiSVwM/UasAfC9InirNsdTIH8hz@zXV31Vj5EK6xjocS8yv6vo@QHrQg@C9wNF@gj0@zT0klos0qWH2vt2i2j31b2GBfA99PVlaseMfNP7wqr4rco6bBGcBxxy5I/AF4twLUb/b@Ja1blUI@tYIZHT30TPSTVNUWsAFxF2GH3YqEnGifpgjskF@qBq7yg24UvO5GZmqQU0wb6K6Kgca0sVyTXAa/DelEDdY@8P6rRr4HRU6Q8t0lPjOkdm4@Hn67THgNEDUCv1dVIXvkASbo/o9ex6jyJxXWBW4H40qWWi7910OLw2UKV@UrV3JZLX3Ss1QdB74jo9qsNa9jVC79GbyLPw/sCJfipD42iSGDxw7UD7I4HfUUSPYcMDB2ZQtK8eehHCn9Q6ILjFXjOBBkEll6wIh9zxC@2bLHscF34qSb@984Zm4iqo2TXg7FI3KOKjvd6Qxd9O5HgAS9md08atddGCm/c8fvhS1H8HB9jWWxdsBmsH@XMq0rMu@nTIPbP0DI1coZJfqvoUzvWNxKK8P7jvuUaos3nNroptrexrSshp5r0tBe8@i64V@plTlu/gd5X6XcBWCzjERerJQTj2jTiX81TLPi9NlT1kWXoQEOd5T2IgZqT9pcDI0b@Cni5onFTtw@tHvXBBYtlEriY4N@gZRI0uS93Q9cwi/UkW@@Y6fohhJvaIQYfP@/1Ez8o42VudfMPfNp5RPcqvxOYi7/C@sswYGLYYNtU1E6V/NIrGTxYtVPRu9ln4s50aDNAraNJjDe0BcDSrrEHnKBZyY117cqZ@P9ZzF93A9V5iFVucpb6FXtdKzFN1DRWPgR2Hbgf0udDfCXvdpAeiijYZcpQq2Dk0Fr32moUzOgm3TPAqxJNe72zElTs0FK3/1@KgkZMBvyqCgaZGzndSDZcNC9jxbbxOVYhtgrfqPUSiV6E8SeccETcMQTQW8nSkQztJPRh65on9pshlStjy2Qybn4SP2amJA36F@wet/eP9R9FjNi2gKjpYqFO5bnRgP9ZYHxM5cbiucwc7Yxnn2MOHRWp1IY4rxovujfPTe70jYwzvgU70J/Afrn8hPE7YqZ4YL/QkfZATYzTk5eiVQZyF/NM5GIFxhvPKlWsjOnDgmbimu@W9Rca4z@w1dFzvKB@Hdo1qVeWyx13RJ5GlJx2xiWs@zbQLSXSXcpL@tih6OU32M8nSGxnJkddeOsTxRWtMWbQ9pU9y14Na@f0mXGy3gYbhaG8S7m3UbiM5DsDLnG/WiX0hR/W@JKkZN@V3NeqtOW7cBEed9nqyRXqqnPcbWU@GtiLyMrMdw07lif2zqAk5TpdE074LZlslPsjUh/P1Nktsrfpj5pOAlWbY30gMtYmmeQ5Hudgs@tKi2QKundvmxP7GlPa4VptokxSfxBr1foBJOE2d61@xRJxTe3wdr@zSvztJn3Sgto/j5tqb3xi39SLYcxd9C7GDPVB/2uPhLD0yooNaj3i1rs098Xy6X4Ovf8PwoaM5@rLE3nreH6lpBSzKOeLm67tohXarGbvOs2n45s74HvhEkv0oWqLWlu43o88JDL4FsS9FNM6g3zWTl6laAC0c6XUWwZWC6D@lnZ@ldmyUOmXY9@R5PXWW@nDe78tShZNbArEgzclgu6GLCE5e0/y3O9eReyok2ibXr5hFW7cLZzKSJ12kVwW@wLUXDOuuopMFrgbmlvODI/ucHLsJ0lMmuUsWDYdmvL6EPpIsfO@ZuUCfjvblEI35ovUE0fEtknerri1sK3LxJPUd5NeYezlTywz9ba7H1aVXIYuup@icF9Fswb4zRXyma5VJPtsy@wNcE6wR3wUXNonenHPowc8ojIe7@fpOvu7GTZL9BaCpDA131xUXnXLY0iR5A3xZVR2zzHu282w6Ho24XTc8YNX4nsOeBwQ@NO4bY@17gRThN0s9o4sWUo/k/KLeCN/h2G0RvKBJXt@kv7eSj99nqXFM@5jJ@xF1TXbhmog2kO6ppjVPx7Yz8ZEqXCa3K8JH8JjDajHA6noT/Y1Z@h2y1FoaMQz14V6bDMR@UEcB7umc38g@fNfxisSziuhzKDerJ9ZfB@cgsu8EuYbvgWB@07VnZE8f7Xl3vkdnvCKaa6s/3TiFlfG0@6lJeBgz41KfX0XijSh7bQmmUIvsyyF9pEX6cHZ7@6gfytKzM1M3ryXhHQo/wfPVJDy9KLWPTE3IIvttuK4l9HYS42nwJUvjPlrYcwfYF/Zs8fqUcqKS9IzMUtecyWss0mfieLD0zBTj5KLPs4ifaqJr5Pmz8I@Re/reLJUYfyu0u/AjsVEXdthVWw/Jxi6qToqtjx7Zh@1jnSTPNp3ALJigx4ATddeRa@x0fXRPipk9zU36/brEXF24745dNqmxKS9d9JRqkv3ACnmWrs9XhLOduM9ckTptbuwNd3xMek9Vp8vnShXejOCYmjN5PbYLrjqzLyNLjF5EW9k1F6AnOpH/7trTynMsEgspr7nue3Gc/9O5tkPY82rRT98T97yz84@@OcQMu71rZG9OtSXgGjt/kT2WG54SmDf5PpTCKYtSL4CuWhU/Db5UFS498APs3ej808qaL2o2qYj@vGhruD5AI78BeZ9zbWfnMHkvGbBq9NL6XgIz7QN4JAka9JP4lCixQCdmUgSfSZl2slrsA80x5dVCBxE4n@PSohlsfJlNZ1i4EJ4rN9P3FPzI41Hrf/F6IfbbyswBfQ@@YDFapV3f4elJ6ljSZ@kaTll07yr7mFED8T2QlGsJXuEsnMLA@l3r7LOthgNiTzHgiejVVt3VLrq6juuI1laW/Tadd9TI50c@EYXf5OvL5qzHorJnF/S60LcDXqqf32ImxHiYC@BEAWPvUkdOYY8D9CL7zPU9lxP5UJ9oN0MTDmIRnRTwCAL9mvLzemdPufflNMYU0IRqFvP0wH5d8DqKaJr2IlypIH3OhXrWfZbexEl6ZwJrFQW87MJ60ngvhXuEAPNGDQZ1jCa1YuhSOycS2HahzkzW/T@kbxXrNCXZDxQcvsY9k/u07@d2/K1xf0bXs0/EBtHz634iUxcpq654k30dMmuHsYpeT9vHIa451OnHnDcTZE8p6W8A/r3L9yK5wbXvudJZeBhV9idSLoXHjKKDg7wB53A9OetHdb6x8L2r9l9E2V9sIk6XRWvDtcaKaPdOe90534umUVcNmlx@vOnhtrDnXsPGV9lfD/0ATbjVWfY/xF6l3pfUhGs2iZZyEq28KFroMzlW2F8Ouh9YMzlRy031tpzrEajN5fsgQdtxJibompqCi7R5r41Upf4GnCmLfWyNY@W6uknylbrXHHGe83Sk@wZehmi3636E2IvX9RIb@UhdMOHc9prdsLnY160Lj23F6mdoyYSjveyi8G8jcy3wKGEzUP/xWlDjXha@b5P09/r7EO3AFImxY99C973gMcZ9vxf49N4DM3P/IMfAJ9kTXPnKus@n9ME20Tzp0vfpXFTw94W/XETTSmsNbp@ll6oH2d@uM4fPojMKrUhwR12PJrFul9SGVe4v4njlJPYFcURgrBoFo8HzYd2AW@P7ZSbqysMHgU@MHCxLvaEm7tGY0VcnXAjkYc5B0V6tLPsGa09wEn4M6k2C2aE3rghPNFZyXhGDujZAlfU3i@aXxZjO/Zb6TpG9noD5Y69g5/GI9gFqMwlYUuXaxV6rRTjjTWpM0D3wXodC/YWMvkH41ix6gjMxKOS6Ke85vzFyfaDvBv38/tyTxMaij1RVO1Nw/Sw6KSWQ8@f8rSaaiFn0TtOe74FaEmrizguZhas@sc/UscVppzWy1Uywp2Nlz0lTXq30m8APF9FpTVJ3c8wPuVnm@/R9b6UW5OMyy74byhHI9JPAqopyKys1@bLai8paaw6isQLdRNH9Vm0axPw5k6PaZF8C1KR8358kPeZZ9maLjjt7zuEa1lm4btU4oIXvOkkfqNfWzUd4bNTZe2fjstVks2gLTaIl3aRf2t5xLKyhpcIe5gbMX/ZBKEdxE2oawMqT8k1E49/7ZkXfEb1W3gfcyHNEfode3Br2XJgie2hjbmuPr/OzMznPmXufb334UXQfZB89x@GF29ik98N1@ecjvQDstSQ6N4j5YiauMHheRTRMRX8OvMUsPRCocaRofDHBC9AnHzfsc@MNCf6VI9c0zuvvRnqFvbbbJZ9ssu9g5fp2ezLtOZXamwlbor7WsUnUr6PsdxhEq2TmeO84EJ11gd5lL8Mu@740agVWrd9VxjS7/R@q6FMm5mXAr0vd8R2oAd32Pw8/IbEk@EhJsfuZ/L8@cYxc01D3uJQah9fLGvdxBafN@dxR/Jzq9um99/3eY63sYxPnykB3WuyH6x9pbN9kLziLG3ug/qr3lum@fLoHWmK9pVTjMBeJUSbmi025aNAbacJ9m6S/ZtpjSVX2C9S9VjD/fN/7KHVj60uFbrbu9ZuhVzBJn7LsM6K1WGj/F9UcsjWeJAdzrXHRDtY9i50vFAXnbuzJ117paHujYB5hX5ase8FG6k1lmTvOey@yB2Zk/4jjCtijL8teDDN1ld0XN@GizlyXiMdcfyILf3oSTn0UnN7eWczSy6V2UPYBzsrP7FKjSFKfkFpXM91b9Du5f5KaUxJd0yx70nl/Ivo5UI@ssp9gkL1zZ/aXFeGcoBaJmAc6EJjzqJFAs6Fo/22R2B1cOtmTpyvvQzSEndcsGC/4Rs5VlZpurdSkybJHeK2yH5vNwd29BvJFwQ/zmGvieyqiSeB7jwU@p@tuRfZN4Lst7/n1qCe4TYiMz70/OLCXGfWebHhNyrLv/Sx72xbW1OD/q/TpwNYWYqQj3kiC6ySJOZvqm5cnetilDu/jOTM/3ukaBeEJSP5ZZT0MvFXyftfpxru1@REq65Cuww9dINHsbLKfidpCHyerG0XTkkPMsNt3U3Jo2Lw4Eb9wPVLhRJVprwmM3lbw5rPqch7r5HfuN5F1f1vjImp/W5a9BcDJUu6Yz8@J@h@us9WF44Ge4ESdpC7cBcf3Jsnpu3DCZql7TtKP2@gv0M/VjvG1KHtbRGKo0NH1fccSea1Z@hCBtfn@UbNoYEz7PknXwQ6Mz5xnMfN9IE6ped/TkmUvHc/5guwvZvkj4kXwzsFVUK40aueuedNF9zeL1m4SrkznnoC6h7XvgaJxX2YuUcteVxj7@xSpmyEP1r1NvDc7iPZjlH4O4Q33bbzCnLhfWJ6Yv/l@DNJvB85@b4JLyj5@qqnvayTI3gTtSJtDdfIjNZqBC/Yi8Sr0DgPzC99ra2bvV8FeCbrHzCR1znAU70@PNQuy8CLBbcf@PH0if7Inzp8mWiIJeJPgHU30o9FTnUQz3/MJyVGRW3TlaMyiDyR@zzUeE@taHldNotsvewGnSkw1R@5Zhbpub9TJ9H409L50qekU4bNG6W@qsr@q2aQkGkqIy71HQnVUZ9YMmtYotZ5RiKs32YO5iy6u4xOyn5DvLdZEKxnaT3nPOXU9PbFnnnsc7RmcZQ9u912qnVroW3SfQK8zdtEVLdIXK7o56E2FLfJ@oHK0p6au9ywxhHLWZ/KTwJ8sOnad/Xceu3RyHF0ryXL4Dk6R7N@bE@vI/i4D94LvyqsufB7406b7UmXZj6bt91fx/an7Pk5G3RP6TujF9z64IrrEMod2trpIP7jqSgVip65dJj2xTTiZTffVqrK/@iw9h9pvGcjP1v5lHwtbP0kxzIl80z4Td23C1fK@mMJ3BuwXGF3O5NvVxtpu0f1jE3lqrt1qOVTv@5ywJvaMKy6jupPgH6TAOs6anyVgPto/21mrAs7rGkmiuYL9ND2mxJ4hkfVR8CO69LKhboZ@Xuyl7DrfTfTTdb8u8H2wT0Rh/4DvJyn8D/AllS9Qyn59Ou9sZjxeNTc135HDXoOtNsHENh8z9vVrypuL1OhxPpbMY4@3da@lQo6L6v1gfbtm4UTOMt5ZiPs9q7GHWpFeEOzZrdqRfRbuXKemWpZ@/KyxfWAdT/e11XoWchnY5lxl7wThFyKW62ZnYmZ8kWUvjBSlPqn9y7LXO3q3EGchPwfmWAVjdv682BDwxoCxVeHmxiTx6EReFjCBXFgzBo8w970mbJFePdxvPdIDwnvu0ieNPMb5SKjpAZvqJ//n7XcfLt/f/@3F/cO7i7fPns31/wI)

---

Defines a function (actually it just looks like a function, it's a struct) `pick_orange` that, given a `vector<int> weights` the weight of the oranges and `int remain` the remaining weight of the bag, returns the index of the orange that should be picked.

Algorithm:

repeat `500` times `{`
generates *random* (fake) oranges (normal distribution with mean 170 and stddev 13) until there are `N_NEW_ORANGES=7` oranges
pick any subset whose sum is smallest and not smaller than `remain` (the function `backtrack` does that)
mark all oranges in that subset as *good*
`}`

average out the number of times an oranges being marked as *good* of the (real) oranges with equal weight
return the best orange

---

There are 3 hardcoded constants in the program that cannot be inferred from the problem:

- The random seed (this is not important)
- `N_NEW_ORANGES` (the prediction length). Increasing this makes the program runs exponentially longer (because backtrack)
- number of repetitions. Increasing this makes the program runs linearly longer.

Comment: Ok. Changing the seed to the one that gives the best answer seems like optimizing for the test case though, so you should take the average of a few, say 10, different seeds as your score. Could you post a TIO link to a version that does less repetitions to get the runtime down?

Comment: Finally got it to compile after getting a newer gcc. On 50 runs with random seeds it got an average of 9961.58. Very impressive still. Made me wonder though - your algorithm basically trains itself again on every bag, is there fixed set of best values that could be memorized?

Comment: @Angs I don't think there is a way that can use memorization to help in this case. Any idea?

Comment: My OS comes with gcc 5.4.0, it had some problems with `invalid use of template-name ‘std::normal_distribution’`. No problems with gcc 7.1.0.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 9756 bags

Let's get the orange rolling...

```python
def f(a,m,l):
 r=[];b=[]
 while a:
  b+=[a.pop(a.index(min(a[:l],key=lambda w:abs(sum(b)+w-m))))]
  if sum(b)>=m:r+=[b];b=[]
 return r
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bV3Lsh3HcVybX3F3AEMwY6a7q7uKDnrhtSP8AbQWl0GQQgivACDL@nr6zExlZc6VFQERuPc8Znq665GVlfX5H9/@8ulj@@PTl@ePv7/9@vTT04fnz6/fffz25unVq1f73L5r2/bdbvPxZ/9un@O73Y//tuvfyx7/fvx@Pf7442fr8fsZjz@Pn891ve/4vfXHvx9/4vHHH79bj9@tx9@7X7@f@/WedXxu/tsev@v9eu3w/Hl@7vG64zrs8V19Xdezju8a1@ef7z@u6Xh/Xu/Ca45rfnzeiuu/uBez6/3H9x1/P@7V8ppW/v147XmdM6@pXd9xroHz58f3R@NnHNd53P@Y11qdr92un3mu4blWK98z8prjWies88jrOb7juK8RueZ5vb1d63Nc03mt7XoeuMbjdcdzslzX8xryv8dnz@Oe1uOZT37/8f7IdfFc62Odeq7/@R7Ltcb15/Mb2/X7Yz2wjp5/P69lv@7juMfRHt97PCtZi@PnhmvI53jen19rsrB3tnyOnuu18pmMfKb4b7v24PHneJ3nc18b12JOrvt57ev6/oU/@brj2R/P71zLed2/5fM41tjn9fPz@ci5CM@z0vI@2rWHj9djb1t@T8/rOfbIaOezub738Xlx/Gzl52/X746/j3xGgeed339e@7z23rmG@/W780yOvN5jb/Xr9@dn77keOD8468b1PX5/rMP5jJeswZI9iGte@Yws97Rde93zuo49eNzfsa@P30X@/Dyn2/W7Y/0iv/u8vnV9//nvKWfKcs3jet95XSvf2/IMxvUdx/dZXv/xM8s9e1yb5b/LJgRfd96X536y3A8h19evfXvuh7QfJmcunOf1uPbztTPXY@PvjrUck@touR7n2m/Xdx/25nh/t7S3YkePZ33ui@1uH1eez9NeWNp55/N@/Ow6k9jrnmcTezj3/fm7SRt@2gGTs4RzC7s5r/U8n3f6iZXvP@0m9tKWe3ejnYg8E3bZqvIv52ty/Y/ntvJ8nNflPHuR9hd2dqXt8kb7cnyG59k9n1NPW7/Tjq7rGZ/@0fNZn/s@9wd8xXGecM/Heyz35fG6Y9@d9uvwhcHvn7AZ6WNXPu9zjWbari4@DD4ibebC/Ux@/vn96Wcd95z7LWAX8/uPNTr9TdrU2vPwpz0/O@3KNK7pyuuaeb5O@71oh22j/555z57rgTN2/H3ifG9py0L2yeBzP@4/YPudZycuG9m2oI08z51dn2u5j85nkXYENhI2D7bttNOL9v/0GWk3z2c08n7xORmznOsUaQude3jmmbY8y55rYPl5ZTsX4xJLm3L6Yuf5slybZTwXx/0c5@R4ncEfwQ7h@3Gf@Qy9MQ7Dd5T/gj/Zc33gr5rEhIN@ZabdPp935/6qNUibc9qx9NnntQ/xvTPjJZy5da1R4Iylrziuo2fct/KMGOK7I37N@8Ve7WLffaaNQ@ySz@6MrfzyCZ7XPeBLch2jM645/7vluiM2zuu2tIeeceOEz0pbdMY1O183nbbIcV7TN/outgo2HPGoXDds4YKtQSyQz9M7YxJPvzXSJ2P/IEYJxK5Bn@aI48e1niPtyfnc814j1@T024j/sPcG/dlKfwM/9LjX63ngWmSvjryvmedtpg9bQTsGX1D2aeZnRcZSsD/iB1bGyOd7XfZwXHYiTNY0fdeajNlm@przeY@MNybtJPxXNOY4yJVWniVcQ9n8nb6q1kfO/fk62N51@ZmVdt7zDI20MXg2hjhiMS4/r8Fppwz7ItfT85zBvqyM@9fOzz6/d@VZx/5OH@JBnzXTx1vex5KYcabtPWOiXDvEmyv3EmJ@2xn7r8xNype0ezwWsMVpUy0kh2r5rJCLjPxe53rNjKsX4oX9ukaDr0AskbGKSbw8Bq9jYa07/2sZg5ucG8tz5U5fiXzGsQbYRzNtoO4r2JI992D67WncH0vyOUdO1nntns8TOUH5VuRRuVeQQ9oQ@7kzBjqfRb7OB5839sCAP8/PmGlbTluGdcz9DR9c9lHzroxjEf@vec/VEGucNjr3OvZvxUjGXCsmY36fjLHwHbYYm3j6hsd72oY4F/bPmbO5xLWw74aYDrl@Xo8hZjOJS/Ncn9jCLveV5@7x@7bvdd9th93IvBHxD2LF2Xg@fXCdT/uxyzlNfCE0Dw@JgXb6hHOPBe0DYr6KGdPnWmIIo9FnYx3OWKPRpiLPHhnzYc/OjB3OPBgxVl57DOI@iLU8r3dlvB55xipeyFhwTIm3G@Mrz/1viIOb2DSck/TV1sUfGnNJ5AiID6YLFnLtrxN7Qfzs2J@IVRGHYm2CPnLmGVwZuyGGtDyjvrjHKhdsjEmBkTjsVsbtK@/HEHOLrcbzs8H1maP245Uf5b53@HSjLUb86YOx8Mp48IzrJb8HfubOc4vYAP79@DMSu/DJ@xrpO4E/WdqTkecVz/6wVcAogR3A5yF2q3iu0SfVs56Cc8FHpC2teB3xAO4rz@LAed4Tg0EOkmszgrGz5Vk9zskREw3YtqAPm0GsDzFCxSkuuJ4LRpZ7cXb6Os/vrPO808/N/DuemcGnG/FJxGHH/kOsW7Y37Wsgt0uf52nPzYm1rYzDIs@bD@KmJtjLHNwrinshvl2Zdy/kvZKn4IxZ4lQ4f1j3ytGDWKPvgh226xpnlxhv8vVnXG1iNzZZ45bxlxPDAK7Q09Z55irIARAzwk8C1/WMF63T557YyWTMfD5nk3x3EB@YaecKO4R/zmdgctbhW@HLEXsD4xvO76rYFtj3ls9JsLjK9xLDPvboGPxO2LPIPDnP85Xnres8RH4PcDZgiD24/xCnzMH1KxzDEme64uu2I74A5gpcdQnei3xpo50BnnuuG/AsxMXG3Dew//J@YGuQkwBbH434JvIlS19siP0tv2MXHErwPZwbxLS@pI6DuKJdz8KzhhL9nkdir7jEtlg/nGucX3OpEeUeQN5XtskqjztjmMhrjBBsBXnmqtz@2kdNsFDksWlDV3DPzSk1giXY3S4xS/oT5DJrY36PfQcbE10wsUG8YwHLAX4gPht48fEcwoi9FM6JuNSvPQ/MJQYxBuTUq0lemnsmBJOuPHEQ15vpi1bmfm1jHADf5J05IXDEIT77tD0h@L/YQIvKzc61RX4LDM2wZ4DPr@t1WLsBPxk8t4hbxyKW7E6fBF/qG3Ppql25xD7O2NAT0/JcH9ScgNdj71dOLj4GsRjOQsiaJcZw3fsgNmNp6wx4PmK9ccfGkZOPnfUx5Pk4q2Y8yyeWldjMbLSHOC8egnGk7Tw/3xijz13yysTcLP17w76Gfcb@gX1PbM@n5Jf53DriU9St0q5gnYdJzNgE556JP2d@ErmPIzFNa8zzrdM/Hd/X4dezfhiNuJjtUp/2tP2IzY1nPxbvEdgsaoFnfOmsL9VabOI/GuMv1H/duJfg24Ddo9ZnwfxwZS0nBHcGFuGT@6J8RNZNDJ@56MMt4/lzPfJMj5AYDrYcdZw8o74kX02b6k48tHxbl7OfsbnhTDnjpbJdITEI8DJjjorYeUlu67ke2GOo@QLHK9s4aAsN9srTj8D3OeOMtdOm3OrvjfnviSFL3QR1VcRvwwVbaNzLtU7O9ZiCn85BPMoG4861cV@BzzA6n7vn8zPnM6n3GePzyHN7nucQ3MTEhgxyJGBPUecbs9b5zOEqRojM6TInVzy26knAaRWbGowZp5ETUnZ8cH1m8DqmxBqo26DGDKxzDsnD1afK3jDgVU5/NXINFmrLOC@d@KSPey0DZ7Owsl1qP8CGg7nYCObN4Gqg/oC8DDyLgb2xmANXDhqM59Ver01wPhNf5PmsdvqYtFFXDrEz9j9zQWfsX/4t692z0dYjZtVaG2LTY89EZ40IMcSaeYZCcIzBOt5EPiw@94whYIONddEY9F0rP@@0y6hdAbtMHzmDONgI5jEda5tnbQA7QJ1e8PtAPCZ8J3w/MCngOWXfgbF22vh61okjVG12sfY10l4gZ1nOWmBxdjLXAt5habfBg4ItLsy@scZXsW4TbHjPWi9i5EG/F05sHJyHEcQIER8gxjn3ThOOhVVcdcY7wAKAbVSNUWo02BvA5VYQZ6yaoNPmnHGk@HbkcBUTomZhl12ItA@Irwvj75KbDa595XPGONWUKwSsUDCOENsGX3jGUMEa/RnXZoxUZ7Hd8ceq@fbrPHiIn2w8O8BvUWNR7psDB0S9thOfXpmroS6Eda2zCXw37VPh7BtzGuAGwITWvNeMxk5cvPZuvgbnF3sX@SH@vZy2c4Vg13L9K/0wcOAldSHYRMu9jHM92p2XE1pHEm4g4j4PqZcOYudrVXx72lXkCUtiBMS/y4SnJOeqOGaCn3rmgbVGXdYceZZzz87GesHKeKrqmF3O5CAfEVw@syvvbuoP83oDGFvuDdR9Tls/cj8jl29id6fE0Ca1V@c@g53GOoIX6RIbAo90YPwhHDrh8MQSvER4AMBBELvid5Vf5T4YaTdiY520OKM7cSXU/b3xvBV/A/58kp8D/BdnCLEankNswrkKnidc@wzBfic5MIWjOXPakTmQ53WayRnNPE35jqtJTRKc0Z05/ZS4E6@1XTCDjTE5MMe5yIFdgk/MjTEx9tDc@cwrHx08QyNYXy@eSPqnqrWOF7WyJfho1spGFwy/k6uC/Q37P531Q1uSlyDeQZ1hca0MHInkMZrTpnmTewD3bQnnTvLqwpiCHDhgU5H74cyLJ@OMaPQFy@i3tW6c/qjtXeIojYv2PLtB7MQ3wa0QO2AvKeep89mAc@wb47yR8ZjWPsdOrBJxKrCYMcRHSI6H9QTfr/IvicF9CDYpcUbxUYfkzmKXEHtPZ10LdQVwkgq/b4LbybNZnXb@VqcWzsJpt4w5u0tMX7x1F9sdEg85X9@78FpDuHAheY/Rh6G@WvWUjVyJihekTgteVvKE2h7M8VBf1Jxh4fuddZuKhVEv2MmNqjhqij1otNPghME2ANOtGr7wmWHLgQNbkN9z2qFxrRcwJ2C8sD3hrAUt8Is0R88aQ1@0CS69D5o3mNRbwZf0XbjLSzBi5JJDuB2NdjqwtzbWwLAvUVNz4/oAu1@N3wV@FHjviPl9kGc5k9cKrGpmjcIX@aI26V8sY0CcuXrOefZR1xkhcaLUnBAXmnEPVV6avB748@JoNeEqbRIDdXLFZ9oYYGgTdSdgRMaaO@J1cFs0NoYPt8V6R0/8HNy62IkNV//BTjwC@X/lv0G@guf3etaPvDMfXXkOku9Qsf6ZOwX99BB/aYJ7RNqg2CW@hI@Y0g/h5LyY8ZqQVwKLqnodalqSz@OMW/pik7y2u@Szm@wt57qgbhxSsz32U0ffxyb5KnxZnrkhvKsVd84S6uCwbYbzJDwo5PHVAzG5LlVvaoIPduE45ZpHY30TNUY34rXIGZCLTalrgmuHtdOzDQ7V3Mh5RFyPfNobe5GGCw4E3kMnVwl7G3HBgB/JmCY50uQ2xJ3PqrUl28i/r9we9ZAl3BTtzwmpseZnVQ02BEtqzNlM@C6w@5Fc1@I0C1/gPOvJqXHplyneB/ijnf4Y9Q1wdlGHP@Olce9NgM0C7m87@Vmr3evnlnvItf45eH/INYELjcma4Y1/0eR3zno66sDlA9NeR9YtUFtETaC4Chv5AOB3@WJuYzv5jhYS0697TlJ1cr/2Gs7vWYPSmnsjTwjnfU32RRWfyomvhvSjABdRvig4t@CegWs8nPU@1ElHkHNQvN6d3KyyGRvvrXC9Tm7NEn4O/MjciV8Ckyr@bH4GcFDwR8rHIK9vPCPFJcz4u3otRsbPk1ze4rwN4dAO4Zk2wd8zFkCOMIb4Z6n7RdaHYHPAjUMuNCX@HsJ9XKiTOGuM4KopN9b8nkMGezzbbqzNTRPOKfC5JvVFxO8b67roN0T@iv1TOKu/4AAM8hXAV0SPxTLihGcsInnh2IXjCnw91xFx93Jy9mDr/PqcExeKyZph@aWRvkl6LXA@tN8SHIMOH9UkdhL7MDfZj3j2sr/Rs4UegMqNNvZQLskNVuIcY955hlqTqBp9nvni3jTpC530GWOXmvLO/Am5CfCw2BnDFl9ksi5mTeqmnZwqP3A4z1pK1plCONc92AcDPj@4cYgxYjGOBLdxLOFdS45/2sHEOJdgdcWRMOKU8P@oeYMvWpywRm4yOM5aK8S/8cxdat5D8ZSMXcAXKt7rTj6hy/rgbCKex7mrszMkjwQ/dCe2jzVEruGTtZzaS3H1JsLG2BCefvDMlJ0L9p6jDowzjNyvco@Qnrwg/wQ9puCVwOa79FWA0x5NMP2s@VYf4xIsEbxT4Tkhvq@a5pDcbko9DDwSv68Prj1z76u@2mh70CMxEltFfoS9Bly8OK@75Ovi28LIs5/JHQWPArixa895l5xK@w@nxKqL@ULtH@n3aE5@BGIu4OioASzUNLy4Dmf@U/yHLlz2jTEr4q@RuUP6bj67KXnquNdBq442ZH8N8XdTOHlNcjST60mf7UvyV/AMVStBesjBp/OrXn/V1jOeO2tkTXq4Bf8O7BtoDDhxF/DyccarvzF4X@DbgydXMUInH3dIvWpBtwG6D2Lfi1e@C2eskf9zflbaKvB3vJGDXVyAnTxT8OnB1yp@eONZc@Hme2esvoTnPOl3ixtb/KKNtQ3EsBVjTu7BqglN4cMO5pTe2MO4FA/YideMjKnFnrEeKNxbfT/4WWfvUJP@IpMeFBNOZHJ6qi8DOGTa1JD6VuHnu3AEnRhm1bJe8AA0zwGmlfd52ljE7cAo0Z@tuKfy@9H/gdxjJnegeHbOWgn604bYJeQtyNmmaGogFhwS2w/J729@bAjm32T/LfJETeoF@C7tfS1OJ3xgv9dkYHcQrxZPHf0ZGXP2TbgAnTZlGevIFtTHAIdqDuFmGvvZKs7f7rwjk9504ODAWIz8kKsmMu@cBpxtjcGLa5FrGC44YOKm8CuoYWjfA3ywbbJ/d/ZPRd4TegItuZFh7JFHjmzAP0LqxV36Xxpz0ZBcEvWMwtmbfIeJz8@4sHr1muCIG/t2/GXNb7GXAjxf@ILYyG@ofGxnDRE5pkvvPvrVq3YBTG@xTxyxRvWLJA5ePQ8bc8r0rxdnFdoOWTMrm9gkT8g8o3LE/E5L3QDsvxXk0YFzjzgKNcLiB2iP5GCPS@EHG3v4S38FHPygnkvxZ116oJIXHcKXDuHUL2c9e4gPAg6COjziqpH5V1vS79yYWxb@tqi9A/0gxCzaCzRf1H7nRhwH3IvCk8XfTWNvHPqfSn@lSVwqekPVuxjEu3pI/NjYwzfTt4APgnxg2F2XCHUo1dIYfsdMqqdfNIwQT@AZrtT/Qb7j0nc3hAsRS7QMjGcafPvCdZx7Koy8YcQMqocBHnfVZqf0JcizBFfcg3ZpbeTzgSNniY1N0SU5nncX/m7FDyH1TNTuUxtG/Vtx8oJ5Cbj5OM/JfWnbou1EfQzcCe0TW6IRtSQ@Q267VJvKxG53wSCNPY3Y95UH7XetGtSVp9TmPWth4N4hl9WcClwO@OTRyY1DLu6Ca4ELj@@veHgXPknGptAQqfoo9pv0nkJHCf1HDl8r@A/8QvHbNsFq@71neQk2E4t8uMI4JXdFDmfYE0ZbACy@uOiNtRDkI6Xts5HXUb0rcefe4jlXjUx6aJdiFEY8HfkbYpXiijTB2oN8GQvWLafYpBD@Q0/@eaD2LnokEzju5avbJj3SirOCizQWcWH0@yJGMXAynLoGpZ@2Me6unv8uPe7KP@/E0MCxrzpf7sWzduhSOw/m1qWl1ETjTvIu6H251NaBg1WNZpf4dZLDjFwbfc/emDMCByhfw37T1rLeMqWnuHo6Jf5BfRcxStmiST9sWc@c2ntv/Lc5tdCwV4vH/KKnG2vkoh/hkiuaM3fFeelx39fR7vpIyHtRT6n@T3BA0FuDPtfBnLH0QMSuwCbGxlrcSNvaBzURkBst6Sv1oJbWEE79eJFLQP8GeA7qJYVxSb3GpT8VNnM5dTG0nhqJDZjUiKp/exMNtc4ztDbG46Wv1UXLUGxrcd@6xEKZG0EPofIooy@GVhz4llXLd@I8VecfxNMQ0xdfTfrOwcX1jHVVo8s22vnSFJS@DOTfiCuG1IWhaebS44F4F8/FRFfEQ/CYIX2Ik/eJGpaJzuJo5FOix2I20UrMXo0hOkDAd@YLTpALP986Nbfgn2G3wXnxyxdf9hf6ZcE9gbpgacMt9q8VL8Re1Gec@hJnX/uS3obJ9S2dCeSNG/HnW23CpI@5Jed/kTNffQyd3197RXta2l3vDv3txSf08m2lBzeXxGtS1wTGEtLrAA1E1GyLv78R8ys9mk79DOBLS2sayWMJ8DOc2KcLv6pihMb7HOlb0MOHXpQp3B28N5bw/fa7zSu9sSXcNZe@lnm3/Svrk97Ef27Cr9H1COn1HazvlkatsX/41v@fGCHyU9S1ZmomIh4GV@3m5xWHFJ4s@uxm9q5Xr7XoZEyJ8YubPcUO45xkP2ho/84SDSmXfvONGj@VF0@eH9g@jSVc4mLoN@IMgO/VwVvNPT4a@Qu2s19f9VUrRpqsY6DHfcr@XqLnB6wLPQjVD9TpI9Dv4@glzVgkpIe6@nanaPetu4YF8D309Rm1Y858s/rClvitxTrsFJwHHHLkj8AXp3Atzv7fwbOqe2l11rHaIKffRc9JNU1RawAXEXYYfdioSfaN@mCFyTX6oJXPqLvwJXdyM01qAS7Y1xQdlZfaUlNyDfAaqjelUfe4@oOCdg2cjiX9oVN6akrnKG08/Pza7hgwegDWor7OCOELDOH2iF7PrfeoE9cFZgXuh0stE33vqcNRtYEl9ZOlvSudvO5Y1ARB70np9KgO67zXCKtHbyPPovoDN/opg8bRJjF449mB9scAv2OKHsOFB56YwdS@euhFCH9S64DgFlfNBBoEi1yyKRzywi@0b3LecVz4qSH99sUb2omroGbnwNmlbjDFR1e9wcTfbuR4AEu5fWaum4dowe13Hj98Keq/Jwc4z1sINoOzg/x5TOlZF3065J4mPUNnrrDIL1V9iuL6dmJR1R8cd64R6mxVs1tiWxf7mgZymv1uS8G7N9G1Qj/zMHkPfrao3wVsdYJDPKWe3IRj78S5iqc673npWOwhM@lBQJxXPYmNmJH2lwIjR/8KerqgcbK0Dy9e9MI1iWUHuZrg3KBnEDU6k7ph6Zl1@hMT@1Y6fohhNvaIQYev@v1Ezyo52Ved/MLfLp7RepFfic1F3lF9ZcYYGLYYNrU0E6V/tIvGj4kWKno3Yxf@bFCDAXoFLj3W0B4AR3PJGSyO4iQ3trQnd@r34zyH6AYe19KX2GKT@hZ6XRcxT9U1VDwGdhy6HdDnQn8n7LVLD8QSbTLkKEuwc2gsVu3VhDO6CbdM8CrEk1XvdOLKAQ3F7P/NOOjMyYBfTcFAh5PzPVTD5cICbnybqlNNYpvgrVYPkehVKE@yOEfEDVsTjQXbXujQblIPhp75YL8pcpnZrnzWYPOH8DGDmjjgV5R/0No/nn8XPebUAlqig4U6VelGN/ZjnedjIycO31vcwWAsUxx7@LBOrS7EcTN50eHcn9Xr3RljVA/0oD@B/yj9C@Fxwk7FYLwQQ/ogN8ZoyMvRK4M4C/lncTAa44zilSvXRnTgwDMpTffMe6escezsNSxc70U@Du0a1aqyecdd0Sdh0pOO2KQ0n3bahSG6Szakv62LXo7LPBOT3shOjrz20iGOn1pjMtH2lD7JWw/q4vtduNhlAxPD0d4kXNtZu@3kOAAvK75ZEPtCjlp9SVIzduV3OfXWCjd2wVG3u57slJ6q4v121pOhrYi8LG3HaadsY/8sakKF0w3RtA/BbJfEB0Z9uDpvu8TWqj@WPglYqcH@dmKoLprm1l7kYrvoS4tmC7h2ZZsH@xvHuONavtEmKT6JM1r9AJtwmoLnX7FEfKb2@BZeGdK/u0mfdKO2T@Hm2pvvjNtiCvYcom8hdjAa9acrHjbpkREd1PWCV1va3Bs/T@c11PlPDB86mmdfltjbyvs7Na2ARRVHPH19iFZoZM24dJ5Tw9eC8T3wiSHzKHxQa0vnzeh9AoP3JvZlisYZ9Lt28jJVC8DbC73OKbhSE/2ncfOz1I7tUqds9568qqfuUh@2@1yWJZzc2YgFaU4G2w1dRHDyXPPfKK4jZyoM2qbSr9hFWzeEM9nJk57SqwJfUNoLiXUv0ckCVwN7q/jBnX1Ohd006SmT3MVEw8GT1zfQR2LC996ZC8T2Yi6HaMxPrSeIju@UvFt1bWFbkYsPqe8gv8beM6OWGfrbSo8rpFfBRNdTdM6naLZg7swUn1laZZLPurE/oDTBnPguuLBD9OaKQw9@xmQ8HOnrg3zdi5sk8wWgqQwN99IVF51y2NIheQN82VIdM@M15@dcOh5O3C4SDzg0vvd25wGBD43rxlrXLJAp/GapZ4RoIUUn5xf1RviOwm6n4AUueb1Lf@8iHz92qXFs95ip@hH1TIZwTUQbSGeqac2zsG0jPrKEy1R2RfgIFXNkLQZYXbjob@zS72BSa3FiGOrDqzbZiP2gjgLcszi/nX34pePViWdN0edQblYM1l9PzkFn3wlyjZqBkH6ztGdkpo/2vBffIxiviOba4U8vTuFiPF1@ahMexs64tPbXlHijy6wtwRTWlLkc0kc6pQ/nNttH/ZBJz85O3TwfwjsUfkLlq0N4el1qH0ZNyCnzNkrXEno7g/E0@JLTOUcLM3eAfWFmS9WnlBM1pGdkl7rmTl7jlD6TwoOlZ2YmJxd9nlP8lIuuUeXPwj9G7lmzWRYxfp@0u/Aj3akLe9rVPA8j166rTkqej@jsw661HpJnp06gCSZYMeBG3XXkGjddH51JsbOn2aXfLyTmCuG@F3bpUmNTXrroKa0h88AmeZalzzeFsz04Z25KndacveGFj0nvqep01V5ZwpsRHFNzpqrHhuCqO/syTGL0KdrKpbkAPdGN/PfSnlae45RYSHnN696LU/yf4Nlu7c6rRT99DM68y88/@@YQM9xm18hsTrUl4BoXf5E9lhee0pg31RxK4ZR1qRdAV22JnwZfagmXHvgBZjcW/3Sx5ouazZiiPy/aGqUP4OQ3IO8rru1eHKbqJQNWjV7amiWw0z6ARzKgQb@JT@kSCwQxkyn4zDDayZWxDzTHlFcLHUTgfIVLi2Zw8mUunWHhQlSu7KnvKfhRxaPZ/1L1QszbMuaANYOvZYy2aNdvePqQOpb0WZaGk4nu3WIfM2ogNQNJuZbgFe7CKWys33mwz3YlDoiZYsAT0autuqshurqF64jWlsm8zeIdOfn8yCe68JvqfOWerVhUZnZBrwt9O@Cl1udnzIQYD3sBnChg7CF15NHuOEBMmTMXdy4n8qHYaDebCwdxik4KeASNfk35eRHsKa@@HGdMAU0oz5gnGvt1weuYomkaU7hSTfqcJ/WsY5fexE16ZxprFRO87Ml60vlcJmeEAPNGDQZ1DJdaMXSpixMJbHtSZ8Z0/of0reKcjiHzQMHhc85Mju3ez134m3M@Y@nZD2KD6PktP2HURTLVFXeZ62CsHfYlej1@j0NKcyjox4o302SmlPQ3AP@@5Xud3OAVd660CQ9jyXwi5VJUzCg6OMgb8BmlJ5f9qMU3Fr730v6LLvPFNuJ0JlobpTU2Rbt3u@vO1Swap64aNLnq9amH6@3OvYaNXzJfD/0ALtxqk/mHmFVafUkuXLNNtJSHaOV10ULfybHCfDnofuDM2KCWm@ptFdejUZur5iBB23EnJliamoKL@H7XRlpSfwPOZGIf3blWpas7JF9Zd82R4jlvL3TfwMsQ7XadR4hZvKWX6OQjhWDC5nfNbthczHUL4bEdWP0OLZn2YpZdF/5tZ64FHiVsBuo/VQtyzrKouU3S31vPQ7QDRyfGjrmF5XvBY@z3fi/w6asHZuf8oMLAN5kJrnxlnfMpfbAumichfZ/FRQV/X/jLUzSttNZQ9ll6qaLJfLtgDm@iMwqtSHBHS49msG431IYtzhcpvHIT@4I4ojFW7YLR4P5wbsCtqXmZg7ry8EHgEyMHM6k3rMEZjYa@OuFCIA8rDor2apnMDdae4CH8GNSbBLNDb9wUnmhf5LwiBi1tgCXnbxfNr4wxi/st9Z0ps56A@WNWcPF4RPsAtZkBLGnx7GLW6hTOuEuNCboH1eswqb9g6BuEbzXRE9yJQSHXHXbn/PbO84G@G/Tz131vEhuLPtJS7UzB9U10UmYj56/4Wy6aiCZ6p@PO90AtCTXx4oXswlXf2Gda2OJ20xq5aiaY6bjYc@LKq5V@E/jhKTqtQ@puhfkhNzM@z5p7K7WgWpdd5m4oR8DoJ4FVTeVWLmrymdqLxVqrNdFYgW6i6H6rNg1ifjNyVF3mEqAmVXN/hvSYm8xm64U7V85RGtYmXLeVHNDJZz2kD7Rq6@kjKjYK9t7lulw1WRNtoU20pF36pfMZ98ka2pjsYXZg/jIHYb6Im1DTAFY@lG8iGv/VNyv6jui1qj5gJ88R@R16cVe7c2GmzNDG3tYe3@JnGznPxtnnVx9@F90HmaNXOLxwG116P0qXf3@hF4BZS6Jzg5ivG3GFk@c1RcNU9OfAWzTpgUCNY/TkiwlegD75fmGfF29I8C/rPNP43Ho20itctd2QfNJl7uDi@S57st05ldqbCVuivrawSdSvu8w7bKJVsnO9bxyIYF0gQmYZhsx9cWoFLq3fLcY0t/kPS/QpB/My4Ndz3fgO1ID2@79PPyGxJPhIQ7H7nfy/2LhGpWmoMy6lxlH1MuccV3Dais/dxc@pbp9ee9xnj/m8xybFlYHutNiP0j/S2N5lFlzGjdGov1q9ZTqXT2egDdZb5koO85QYZWO@6MpFg96IC/dtk/6a7Y4lLZkXqLNWsP9q7n2XunH2pUI3W2f9GvQKNulTljkjWouF9v9UzaE840NysNIaF@1gnVlcfKEuOLezJ197pXvORsE@wlwW01mwnXpTJnuneO9TZmB29o8UroAZfSazGHbqKpcvduGi7jyXiMdKf8KEP70Jp74LTp/PrJv0cqkdlDnApvzMkBrFkPqE1Lo8dW/R71T@SWpOQ3RNTWbSVX8i@jlQj1wyT7DJ7Nyd/WVTOCeoRSLmgQ4E9jxqJNBsmNp/OyV2B5dOZvKE8j5EQ7h4zYLxgm9UXFWp6a5FTRqTGeFryTy23IO3a23ki4IfVjHXxuc0RZOgZo813mfpbnX2TeC9bnd@PeoJZRM64/PqD27sZUa9xxKvGSZz73eZbTtZU4P/X9KnA1s7iZGe8cYQXGdIzOmqbz7/nx52qcPXeu7Mj2@6Rk14ApJ/LjkPJ94qeX/pdOPZ5v5oi3XI0uGHLpBodrrMM1FbWOuUdaOeWnKIGW5zNyWHhs3rG/GL0iMVTtTc7prA6G0Fb95Ul/OlTn5w3oTpfNvkImp/m8lsAXCylDtW@3Oj/kfpbIVwPNATPKiTFMJdKHxvk5w@hBO2S91zk35cp79AP5e/xNe6zLboxFCho1tzxwZ5rSZ9iMDaan7ULhoY271PsnSwG@Oz4lnsfB6IU5bde1pMZulUztdkvljmj4gXwTsHV0G50qidl@ZNiO6vidbuEK5McCagzrCuGSga9xlziTXvusKY7zOlboY8WGebVG92E@3HLv0cwhuOa73aPjgvzDbmbzWPQfrtwNkPF1xS5vippn6dkSazCfyFNofq5HdqNAMXjCnxKvQOG/OLmrW1s/drYlaCzpjZpM7ZXsT72z9rFpjwIsFtx3ye2MifjMH946IlMoA3Cd7hoh@NnuohmvmVT0iOitwilKOxiz6Q@L3SeBysa1VctYluv8wCHouYqnXOrEJdN5w6mdWPht6XkJrOFD5rl/6mJfNV0yYN0VBCXF49EqqjurNm4Fqj1HrGJK7uMoM5RBe38AmZJ1SzxVy0kqH9ZHfOaenpiT2r3OPFzGCTGdzlu1Q7ddK36JzAqjOG6IpO6YsV3Rz0psIWVT/QfDFTU8@7SQyhnPWd/CTwJ6euXbD/rmKXIMextJIyhw9wimR@rw3WketZNs6CD@VVT94P/KnrXCqTeTR@n69S86njHiej7gl9J/TiVx/cFF1i2UM3Wz2lH1x1pRqx09Iuk55YF06m61ytJfPVd@k51H7LRn629i/XWuT5GYphbuSbxk7c1YWrVX0xk88M2C8wOjPy7Zaztjt1fuwgT620WzOHirjnhGuwZ1xxGdWdBP9gNNZxjvxsAPPR/tlgrQo4b2kkieYK5mlWTImZIZ31UfAjQnrZUDdDPy9mKZfOt4t@us7rAt8HcyIm@wdqnqTwP8CXVL7AnPfzWbyznfH40tw0fYe1uwbbcsHELh9zzvVz5c11avQUH0v2ccXbOmtpkuOiej8436VZuJGzjGfW@n1mNWaoTekFwcxu1Y6MXbhzQU01k35809i@sY6nc221noVcBrbZlsxOEH4hYrlIO9ON8YXJLIzRpT6p/csy6x29W4izkJ8Dc1yCMRd/XmwIeGPA2JZwc/uQeHQjLwuYgE3WjMEjtLhrwk7p1cP1rhd6QHjOIX3SyGOKj4SaHrCpePXq1Q9fP79/9@31q//@@Or77//49e1vT7@9fn7z4c3773/87unLTz//@d9@efzfd09//8u792@fnh8/fPrlTz/9/PzD50@fXz//8O7jr2//9/WHdx9fP//84/s/v/nr23/89P75wy@/Pj/9/cfnX76@/vq3D69/@f5Pf//XD98//vf4oKd3vz1dP/z3nz78@OXxWb/gO768/fa3Lx@fvvzxy/Pv//nu67evTz89PX7@26cvT@8/ffrr81/ePv/69O7j0@v2pr8Zb@zNfLMel/kvePkPz58/v/346@vfXn/68vzx97dff/7xz2@e9m3b3vADvv/@u2@fvj2//4/n37/@1/@8/XL8@vE9xyV9eP78@v3bj2@e8IGP137@8u7jt6dXj598/fHp1Zun1//05u//@D8)**

Always picks the fruit from the buffer which minimises the absolute difference of the new weight and the target weight.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 9806 bags

Building on Jonathan and JayCe's answers:

```python
import itertools as it

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def f(a,m,l):
 r=[];b=[]
 while a:
  c =  min(list(powerset(list(reversed(sorted(a[:l]))))),key=lambda w: abs((sum(b)+sum(w))-m))
  if sum(c)==0:
   c = a[:l]
  b+=[a.pop(a.index(min(c,key=lambda w: abs((sum(b)+w)-m))))]
  if sum(b)>=m:r+=[b];b=[]
 return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fX3bjh1Jktyz@ivqrYsYqpEZER7h3kLvg54F6ANGA6E4zZ4hljeQ3B3t149OZrq5WdYKaoBNVp1LZsbFL@bmFl//48ffv3zu//zy7eXz395/f/rt6eOH7z@eP718ff7w@cfbp59//nmf209t237abT7@7D/tc/y0@/F3u35e9vj58fp6/PHH79bj9RmPP4/fz3V97njd@uPnx594/PHHa@vx2nr8u/v1@tyvz6zje/Nne7zW@/Xe4fn7/N7jfcd92ONafV33s45rjev7z88f93R8Pu934T3HPT@@b8X1N57F7Pr8cb3j38ezWt7Tyn8f7z3vc@Y9tesa5xg4f39cPxq/47jP4/nHvMbqfO92/c5zDM@xWvmZkfcc1zhhnEfez3GN47lG5Jjn/fZ2jc9xT@e9tms@cI/H@455shzX8x7y7@O75/FM6zHnk9c/Ph85Lp5jfYxTz/E/P2M51rj/nL@xXa8f44Fx9Pz3eS/79RzHM472uO4xVzIWx@8N95DzeD6fX2OysHa2nEfP8Vo5JyPnFH@3aw0ef473ec772jgWc3Lcz3tf1/UX/uT7jrk/5u8cy3k9v@V8HGPs8/r9OT@yL8Jzr7R8jnat4eP9WNuW1@l5P8caGe2cm@u6j@@L43crv3@7Xjv@PXKOAvOd1z/vfV5r7xzD/Xrt3JMj7/dYW/16/fzuPccD@wd73Ti@x@vHOJxzvGQMlqxB3PPKObJc03atdc/7Otbg8XzHuj5ei/z9uU@367Vj/CKvfd7fuq5//jxlT1mOeVyfO@9r5Wdb7sG4rnFcz/L@j99Zrtnj3ix/LpsQfN/5XJ7ryXI9hNxfv9btuR7SfpjsuXDu1@Pez/fOHI@Nrx1jOSbH0XI8zrHfrmsf9ub4fLe0t2JHj7k@18V2t48r9@dpLyztvHO@H7@79iTWuufexBrOdX@@NmnDTztgspewb2E35zWe53ynn1j5@dNuYi1tuXY32onIPWGXrSr/cr4nx/@Yt5X747wv596LtL@wsyttlzfal@M7PPfuOU89bf1OO7quOT79o@dcn@s@1wd8xbGf8MzHZyzX5fG@Y92d9uvwhcHrT9iM9LEr5/sco5m2q4sPg49Im7nwPJPff14//azjmXO9BexiXv8Yo9PfpE2tNQ9/2vO7065M45iuvK@Z@@u034t22Db675nP7Dke2GPHvyf295a2LGSdDM778fwB2@/cO3HZyLYFbeS57@z6Xst1dM5F2hHYSNg82LbTTi/a/9NnpN0852jk8@J7MmY5xynSFjrX8Mw9bbmXPcfA8vvKdi7GJZY25fTFzv1lOTbLuC@O5zn2yfE@gz@CHcL18Zw5h94Yh@Ea5b/gT/YcH/irJjHhoF@ZabfP@e5cXzUGaXNOO5Y@@7z3Ib53ZryEPbeuMQrssfQVx330jPtW7hFDfHfEr/m8WKtd7LvPtHGIXXLuztjKL5/ged8DviTHMTrjmvPvLccdsXHet6U99IwbJ3xW2qIzrtn5vum0RY79mr7Rd7FVsOGIR@W@YQsXbA1igZxP74xJPP3WSJ@M9YMYJRC7Bn2aI44f13iOtCfnvOezRo7J6bcR/2HtDfqzlf4GfujxrNd84F5krY58rpn7baYPW0E7Bl9Q9mnmd0XGUrA/4gdWxsjnZ13WcFx2IkzGNH3XmozZZvqac75HxhuTdhL@KxpzHORKK/cS7qFs/k5fVeMj@/58H2zvuvzMSjvvuYdG2hjMjSGOWIzLz3tw2inDusjx9NxnsC8r4/6187vP667c61jf6UM86LNm@njL51gSM860vWdMlGOHeHPlWkLMbztj/5W5SfmSdo/HArY4baqF5FAt5wq5yMjrOsdrZly9EC/s1z0afAViiYxVTOLlMXgfC2Pd@bdlDG6ybyz3lTt9JfIZxxhgHc20gbquYEv2XIPpt6dxfSzJ5xw5Wee9e84ncoLyrcijcq0gh7Qh9nNnDHTORb7PB@cba2DAn@d3zLQtpy3DOOb6hg8u@6h5V8axiP/XvOdqiDVOG51rHeu3YiRjrhWTMb9Pxli4hi3GJp6@4fGZtiHOhf1z5mwucS3suyGmQ66f92OI2Uzi0tzXJ7awy3Plvnu83va9nrvtsBuZNyL@Qaw4G/enD47zaT922aeJL4Tm4SEx0E6fcK6xoH1AzFcxY/pcSwxhNPpsjMMZazTaVOTZI2M@rNmZscOZByPGynuPQdwHsZbn/a6M1yP3WMULGQuOKfF2Y3zluf4NcXATm4Z9kr7auvhDYy6JHAHxwXTBQq71dWIviJ8d6xOxKuJQjE3QR87cgytjN8SQlnvUF9dY5YKNMSkwEofdyrh95fMYYm6x1Zg/GxyfOWo9XvlRrnuHTzfaYsSfPhgLr4wHz7he8nvgZ@7ct4gN4N@PPyOxC598rpG@E/iTpT0ZuV8x94etAkYJ7AA@D7FbxXONPqnmegrOBR@RtrTidcQDeK7ciwP7eU8MBjlIjs0Ixs6We/XYJ0dMNGDbgj5sBrE@xAgVp7jgei4YWa7F2enrPK9Z@3mnn5v5b8yZwacb8UnEYcf6Q6xbtjftayC3S5/nac/NibWtjMMi95sP4qYm2MscXCuKeyG@XZl3L@S9kqdgj1niVNh/GPfK0YNYo@@CHbbrHmeXGG/y/WdcbWI3NhnjlvGXE8MArtDT1nnmKsgBEDPCTwLX9YwXrdPnntjJZMx8zrNJvjuID8y0c4Udwj/nHJjsdfhW@HLE3sD4hvNaFdsC@95yngSLq3wvMexjjY7Ba8KeRebJuZ@vPG9d@yHyOsDZgCH24PpDnDIHx69wDEuc6Yqv2474ApgrcNUleC/ypY12BnjuOW7AsxAXG3PfwPrL54GtQU4CbH004pvIlyx9sSH2t7zGLjiU4HvYN4hpfUkdB3FFu@bCs4YS/Z5HYq24xLYYP@xr7F9zqRHlGkDeV7bJKo87Y5jIe4wQbAV55qrc/lpHTbBQ5LFpQ1dwzc0pNYIl2N0uMUv6E@Qya2N@j3UHGxNdMLFBvGMBywF@ID4bePExD2HEXgrnRFzq15oH5hKDGANy6tUkL801E4JJV544iOvN9EUrc7@2MQ6Ab/LOnBA44hCffdqeEPxfbKBF5Wbn2CK/BYZmWDPA59f1PozdgJ8M7lvErWMRS3anT4Iv9Y25dNWuXGIfZ2zoiWl5jg9qTsDrsfYrJxcfg1gMeyFkzBJjuJ59EJuxtHUGPB@x3rhj48jJx876GPJ87FUz7uUTy0psZjbaQ@wXD8E40nae32@M0ecueWVibpb@vWFdwz5j/cC@J7bnU/LLnLeO@BR1q7QrGOdhEjM2wbln4s@Zn0Su40hM0xrzfOv0T8f1Ovx61g@jERezXerTnrYfsblx78fiMwKbRS3wjC@d9aUai038R2P8hfqvG9cSfBuwe9T6LJgfrqzlhODOwCJ8cl2Uj8i6ieE7F324ZTx/jkfu6RESw8GWo46Te9SX5KtpU92Jh5Zv67L3MzY37ClnvFS2KyQGAV5mzFEROy/JbT3HA2sMNV/geGUbB22hwV55@hH4PmecsXbalFv9vTH/PTFkqZugror4bbhgC41rucbJOR5T8NM5iEfZYNy5Nq4r8BlG57x7zp8556Q@Z4zPI/ftuZ9DcBMTGzLIkYA9RZ1vzBrnM4erGCEyp8ucXPHYqicBp1VsajBmnEZOSNnxwfGZwfuYEmugboMaM7DOOSQPV58qa8OAVzn91cgxWKgtY7904pM@7rUM7M3Cynap/QAbDuZiI5g3g6uB@gPyMvAsBtbGYg5cOWgwnld7vTbB@Ux8kedc7fQxaaOuHGJn7H/mgs7Yv/xb1rtno61HzKq1NsSmx5qJzhoRYog1cw@F4BiDdbyJfFh87hlDwAYb66Ix6LtWft9pl1G7AnaZPnIGcbARzGM6xjb32gB2gDq94PeBeEz4Trg@MCngOWXfgbF22via68QRqja7WPsaaS@QsyxnLbA4O5lrAe@wtNvgQcEWF2bfWOOrWLcJNrxnrRcx8qDfCyc2Ds7DCGKEiA8Q45xrpwnHwiquOuMdYAHANqrGKDUarA3gciuIM1ZN0GlzzjhSfDtyuIoJUbOwyy5E2gfE14Xxd8nNBse@8jljnGrKFQJWKBhHiG2DLzxjqGCN/oxrM0aqvdju@GPVfPu1HzzETzbuHeC3qLEo982BA6Je24lPr8zVUBfCuNbeBL6b9qlw9o05DXADYEJr3mtGYycuXms334P9i7WL/BA/L6ftXCHYtdz/Sj8MHHhJXQg20XItY1@PduflhNaRhBuIuM9D6qWD2PlaFd@edhV5wpIYAfHvMuEpyb4qjpngp555YI1RlzFHnuVcs7OxXrAynqo6Zpc9OchHBJfP7Mq7m/rDvN8AxpZrA3Wf09aPXM/I5ZvY3SkxtEnt1bnOYKcxjuBFusSGwCMdGH8Ih044PLEELxEeAHAQxK54rfKrXAcj7UZsrJMWZ3QnroS6vzfut@JvwJ9P8nOA/2IPIVbDPMQmnKvgfsK9zxDsd5IDUziaM6cdmQN53qeZ7NHM05TvuJrUJMEZ3ZnTT4k78V7bBTPYGJMDc5yLHNgl@MTcGBNjDc2dc1756OAeGsH6evFE0j9VrXW8qpUtwUezVja6YPidXBWsb9j/6awf2pK8BPEO6gyLY2XgSCSP0Zw2zZs8A7hvSzh3klcXxhTkwAGbilwPZ148GWdEoy9YRr@tdeP0R23vEkdpXLTn3g1iJ74JboXYAWtJOU@dcwPOsW@M80bGY1r7HDuxSsSpwGLGEB8hOR7GE3y/yr8kBvch2KTEGcVHHZI7i11C7D2ddS3UFcBJKvy@CW4nc7M67fytTi2chdNuGXN2l5i@eOsutjskHnK@v3fhtYZw4ULyHqMPQ3216ikbuRIVL0idFrys5Am1PZjjob6oOcPC9Z11m4qFUS/YyY2qOGqKPWi00@CEwTYA060avvCZYcuBA1uQ33PaoXGNFzAnYLywPeGsBS3wizRHzxpDX7QJLr0PmjeY1FvBl/RduMtLMGLkkkO4HY12OrC2NtbAsC5RU3Pj@AC7X43XAj8KvHfE/D7Is5zJawVWNbNG4Yt8UZv0L5YxIPZczXPufdR1RkicKDUnxIVmXEOVlyavB/68OFpNuEqbxECdXPGZNgYY2kTdCRiRseaOeB3cFo2N4cNtsd7REz8Hty52YsPVf7ATj0D@X/lvkK/geV3P@pF35qMr90HyHSrWP3OnoJ8e4i9NcI9IGxS7xJfwEVP6IZycFzPeE/JKYFFVr0NNS/J57HFLX2yS13aXfHaTteUcF9SNQ2q2x3rq6PvYJF@FL8s9N4R3teLOWUIdHLbNsJ@EB4U8vnogJsel6k1N8MEuHKcc82isb6LG6Ea8FjkDcrEpdU1w7TB2urfBoZobOY@I65FPe2Mv0nDBgcB76OQqYW0jLhjwIxnTJEea3Ia481m1tmQb@feV26MesoSbov05ITXW/K6qwYZgSY05mwnfBXY/kutanGbhC5x7PTk1Lv0yxfsAf7TTH6O@Ac4u6vBnvDTuvQmwWcD9bSc/a7V7/dxyDbnWPwefD7kmcKExWTO88S@avOasp6MOXD4w7XVk3QK1RdQEiquwkQ8Afpcv5ja2k@9oITH9uuckVSf3a61h/541KK25N/KEsN/XZF9U8amc@GpIPwpwEeWLgnML7hm4xsNZ70OddAQ5B8Xr3cnNKpux8dkK1@vk1izh58CPzJ34JTCp4s/mdwAHBX@kfAzy@sY9UlzCjL@r12Jk/DzJ5S3O2xAO7RCeaRP8PWMB5AhjiH@Wul9kfQg2B9w45EJT4u8h3MeFOomzxgiumnJjze85ZLDHs@3G2tw04ZwCn2tSX0T8vrGui35D5K9YP4Wz@isOwCBfAXxF9FgsI054xiKSF45dOK7A13McEXcvJ2cPts6v7zlxoZisGZZfGumbpNcC@0P7LcEx6PBRTWInsQ9zk/WIuZf1jZ4t9ABUbrSxh3JJbrAS5xjzzjPUmkTV6HPPF/emSV/opM8Yu9SUd@ZPyE2Ah8XOGLb4IpN1MWtSN@3kVPmBw3nWUrLOFMK57sE@GPD5wY1DjBGLcSS4jWMJ71py/NMOJsa5BKsrjoQRp4T/R80bfNHihDVyk8Fx1lohfsacu9S8h@IpGbuAL1S81518Qpfxwd5EPI99V3tnSB4JfuhObB9jiFzDJ2s5tZbi6k2EjbEhPP3gnik7F@w9Rx0Yexi5X@UeIT15Qf4JekzBK4HNd@mrAKc9mmD6WfOtPsYlWCJ4p8JzQnxfNc0hud2Uehh4JH4fH9x75t5XfbXR9qBHYiS2ivwIaw24eHFed8nXxbeFkWc/kzsKHgVwY9ee8y45lfYfTolVF/OFWj/S79Gc/AjEXMDRUQNYqGl4cR3O/Kf4D1247BtjVsRfI3OH9N2cuyl56rjXQauONmR9DfF3Uzh5TXI0k/tJn@1L8lfwDFUrQXrIwafzq15/1dYznjtrZE16uAX/DqwbaAw4cRfw8rHHq78x@Fzg24MnVzFCJx93SL1qQbcBug9i34tXvgtnrJH/c35X2irwd7yRg11cgJ08U/DpwdcqfnjjXnPh5ntnrL6E5zzpd4sbW/yijbUNxLAVY06uwaoJTeHDDuaU3tjDuBQP2InXjIypxZ6xHijcW/08@Fln71CT/iKTHhQTTmRyeqovAzhk2tSQ@lbh57twBJ0YZtWyXvEANM8BppXPedpYxO3AKNGfrbin8vvR/4HcYyZ3oHh2zloJ@tOG2CXkLcjZpmhqIBYcEtsPye9vfmwI5t9k/S3yRE3qBbiW9r4WpxM@sN9rMrA7iFeLp47@jIw5@yZcgE6bsox1ZAvqY4BDNYdwM439bBXnb3fekUlvOnBwYCxGfshVE5l3TgP2tsbgxbXIMQwXHDBxU/gV1DC07wE@2DZZvzv7pyKfCT2BltzIMPbII0c24B8h9eIu/S@NuWhILol6RuHsTa5h4vMzLqxevSY44sa@HX9d81vspQDPF74gNvIbKh/bWUNEjunSu49@9apdANNb7BNHrFH9IomDV8/Dxpwy/evFWYW2Q9bMyiY2yRMyz6gcMa9pqRuA9beCPDpw7hFHoUZY/ADtkRzscSn8YGMPf@mvgIMf1HMp/qxLD1TyokP40iGc@uWsZw/xQcBBUIdHXDUy/2pL@p0bc8vC3xa1d6AfhJhFe4Hmq9rv3IjjgHtReLL4u2nsjUP/U@mvNIlLRW@oeheDeFcPiR8be/hm@hbwQZAPDLvrEqEOpVoaw@@YSfX0i4YR4gnM4Ur9H@Q7Ln13Q7gQsUTLwLinwbcvXMe5psLIG0bMoHoY4HFXbXZKX4LMJbjiHrRLayOfDxw5S2xsii7JMd9d@LsVP4TUM1G7T20Y9W/FyQvmJeDmYz8n96Vti7YT9TFwJ7RPbIlG1JL4DLntUm0qE7vdBYM09jRi3VcetN@1alBXnlKb96yFgXuHXFZzKnA54JNHJzcOubgLrgUuPK5f8fAufJKMTaEhUvVRrDfpPYWOEvqPHL5W8B/4heK3bYLV9nvP8hJsJhb5cIVxSu6KHM6wJoy2AFh8cdEbayHIR0rbZyOvo3pX4s69xTxXjUx6aJdiFEY8HfkbYpXiijTB2oN8GQvWLafYpBD@Q0/@eaD2LnokEzju5avbJj3SirOCizQWcWH0@yJGMXAynLoGpZ@2Me6unv8uPe7KP@/E0MCxrzpfrsWzduhSOw/m1qWl1ETjTvIu6H251NaBg1WNZpf4dZLDjFwbfc/emDMCByhfw37T1rLeMqWnuHo6Jf5BfRcxStmiST9sWc@c2ntv/NmcWmhYq8VjftXTjTFy0Y9wyRXNmbtiv/S4r@tod30k5L2op1T/Jzgg6K1Bn@tgzlh6IGJXYBNjYy1upG3tg5oIyI2W9JV6UEtrCKd@vMoloH8DPAf1ksK4pF7j0p8Km7mcuhhaT43EBkxqRNW/vYmGWuceWhvj8dLX6qJlKLa1uG9dYqHMjaCHUHmU0RdDKw58y6rlO3GeqvMP4mmI6YuvJn3n4OJ6xrqq0WUb7XxpCkpfBvJvxBVD6sLQNHPp8UC8i3kx0RXxEDxmSB/i5HOihmWiszga@ZTosZhNtBKzV2OIDhDwnfmKE@TCz7dOzS34Z9htcF788sWX/YV@WXBNoC5Y2nCL/WvFC7FX9RmnvsTZ176kt2FyfEtnAnnjRvz5Vpsw6WNuyflf5MxXH0Pn9WutaE9Lu@vdob@9@IRevq304OaSeE3qmsBYQnodoIGImm3x9zdifqVH06mfAXxpaU0jeSwBfoYT@3ThV1WM0PicI30LevjQizKFu4PPxhK@3363eaU3toS75tLXMu@2f2V90pv4z034NToeIb2@g/Xd0qg19g/f@v8TI0R@irrWTM1ExMPgqt38vOKQwpNFn93M3vXqtRadjCkxfnGzp9hh7JPsBw3t31miIeXSb75R46fy4sn9A9unsYRLXAz9RuwB8L06eKu5xkcjf8F29uurvmrFSJN1DPS4T1nfS/T8gHWhB6H6gTp9BPp9HL2kGYuE9FBX3@4U7b5117AAvoe@PqN2zJlvVl/YEr@1WIedgvOAQ478EfjiFK7F2f87uFd1La3OOlYb5PS76DmppilqDeAiwg6jDxs1yb5RH6wwuUYftHKOugtfcic306QW4IJ9TdFRea0tNSXXAK@helMadY@rPyho18DpWNIfOqWnpnSO0sbDz6/tjgGjB2At6uuMEL7AEG6P6PXceo86cV1gVuB@uNQy0feeOhxVG1hSP1nau9LJ645FTRD0npROj@qwznuNsHr0NvIsqj9wo58yaBxtEoM37h1ofwzwO6boMVx44IkZTO2rh16E8Ce1DghucdVMoEGwyCWbwiEv/EL7Jucdx4WfGtJvX7yhnbgKanYOnF3qBlN8dNUbTPztRo4HsJTbd@a4eYgW3H7n8cOXov57coBzv4VgM9g7yJ/HlJ510adD7mnSM3TmCov8UtWnKK5vJxZV/cFx5xqhzlY1uyW2dbGvaSCn2e@2FLx7E10r9DMPk8/gd4v6XcBWJzjEU@rJTTj2TpyreKrznpeOxR4ykx4ExHnVk9iIGWl/KTBy9K@gpwsaJ0v78OJVL1yTWHaQqwnODXoGUaMzqRuWnlmnPzGxb6XjhxhmY48YdPiq30/0rJKTfdXJL/zt4hmtV/mV2FzkHdVXZoyBYYthU0szUfpHu2j8mGihonczduHPBjUYoFfg0mMN7QFwNJfsweIoTnJjS3typ34/9nOIbuBxL32JLTapb6HXdRHzVF1DxWNgx6HbAX0u9HfCXrv0QCzRJkOOsgQ7h8Zi1V5NOKObcMsEr0I8WfVOJ64c0FDM/t@Mg86cDPjVFAx0ODnfQzVcLizgxrepOtUktgneavUQiV6F8iSLc0TcsDXRWLDtlQ7tJvVg6JkP9psil5ntymcNNn8IHzOoiQN@RfkHrf1j/rvoMacW0BIdLNSpSje6sR/r3B8bOXG4bnEHg7FMcezhwzq1uhDHzeRFh3N9Vq93Z4xRPdCD/gT@o/QvhMcJOxWD8UIM6YPcGKMhL0evDOIs5J/FwWiMM4pXrlwb0YEDz6Q03TPvnTLGsbPXsHC9V/k4tGtUq8rmHXdFn4RJTzpik9J82mkXhugu2ZD@ti56OS7nmZj0RnZy5LWXDnH81BqTiban9EneelAXP@/CxS4bmBiO9ibh3s7abSfHAXhZ8c2C2Bdy1OpLkpqxK7/LqbdWuLELjrrd9WSn9FQV77ezngxtReRlaTtOO2Ub@2dREyqcboimfQhmuyQ@MOrD1X7bJbZW/bH0ScBKDfa3E0N10TS39ioX20VfWjRbwLUr2zzY3zjGHdfyjTZJ8Uns0eoH2ITTFNz/iiXiO7XHt/DKkP7dTfqkG7V9CjfX3nxn3BZTsOcQfQuxg9GoP13xsEmPjOigrle82tLm3vh9el5D7f/E8KGjefZlib2tvL9T0wpYVHHE09eHaIVG1oxL5zk1fC0Y3wOfGHIehQ9qbel5M/qcwOC9iX2ZonEG/a6dvEzVAvD2Sq9zCq7URP9p3PwstWO71CnbvSev6qm71Iftfi7LEk7ubMSCNCeD7YYuIjh5rvlvFNeRZyoM2qbSr9hFWzeEM9nJk57SqwJfUNoLiXUv0ckCVwNrq/jBnX1Ohd006SmT3MVEw8GT1zfQR2LC996ZC8T26lwO0ZifWk8QHd8pebfq2sK2IhcfUt9Bfo21Z0YtM/S3lR5XSK@Cia6n6JxP0WzBuTNTfGZplUk@68b@gNIEc@K74MIO0ZsrDj34GZPxcKSvD/J1L26SnC8ATWVouJeuuOiUw5YOyRvgy5bqmBnvOb/n0vFw4naReMCh8b23Ow8IfGjcN8a6zgKZwm@WekaIFlJ0cn5Rb4TvKOx2Cl7gkte79Pcu8vFjlxrHdo@Zqh9R92QI10S0gfRMNa15FrZtxEeWcJnKrggfoWKOrMUAqwsX/Y1d@h1Mai1ODEN9eNUmG7Ef1FGAexbnt7MPv3S8OvGsKfocys2KwfrryTno7DtBrlFnIKTfLO0ZOdNHe96L7xGMV0Rz7fCnF6dwMZ4uP7UJD2NnXFrra0q80eWsLcEU1pRzOaSPdEofzu1sH/VDJj07O3XzfAjvUPgJla8O4el1qX0YNSGnnLdRupbQ2xmMp8GXnM5ztHDmDrAvnNlS9SnlRA3pGdmlrrmT1zilz6TwYOmZmcnJRZ/nFD/lomtU@bPwj5F71tksixi/T9pd@JHu1IU97Wruh5Fj11UnJfdHdPZh11gPybNTJ9AEE6wYcKPuOnKNm66Pnkmxs6fZpd8vJOYK4b4XdulSY1NeuugprSHngU3yLEufbwpne/CcuSl1WnP2hhc@Jr2nqtNVa2UJb0ZwTM2Zqh4bgqvu7MswidGnaCuX5gL0RDfy30t7WnmOU2Ih5TWvey9O8X@Ce7u1O68W/fQxeOZdfv/ZN4eY4XZ2jZzNqbYEXOPiL7LH8sJTGvOmOodSOGVd6gXQVVvip8GXWsKlB36AsxuLf7pY80XNZkzRnxdtjdIHcPIbkPcV13YvDlP1kgGrRi9tnSWw0z6ARzKgQb@JT@kSCwQxkyn4zDDayZWxDzTHlFcLHUTgfIVLi2Zw8mUunWHhQlSu7KnvKfhRxaPZ/1L1Qpy3ZcwB6wy@ljHaol2/4elD6ljSZ1kaTia6d4t9zKiB1BlIyrUEr3AXTmFj/c6DfbYrcUCcKQY8Eb3aqrsaoqtbuI5obZmct1m8IyefH/lEF35T7a9csxWLypld0OtC3w54qfX9GTMhxsNaACcKGHtIHXm0Ow4QU86ZizuXE/lQbLSbzYWDOEUnBTyCRr@m/LwI9pRXX44zpoAmlGfME439uuB1TNE0jSlcqSZ9zpN61rFLb@ImvTONtYoJXvZkPemcl8kzQoB5owaDOoZLrRi61MWJBLY9qTNjev6H9K1in44h54GCw@c8Mzm2ez934W/O8xlLz34QG0TPb/kJoy6Sqa64y7kOxtphX6LX4/c4pDSHgn6seDNNzpSS/gbg37d8r5MbvOLOlTbhYSw5n0i5FBUzig4O8gZ8R@nJZT9q8Y2F7720/6LL@WIbcToTrY3SGpui3bvddefqLBqnrho0uer9qYfr7c69ho1fcr4e@gFcuNUm5x/irNLqS3Lhmm2ipTxEK6@LFvpOjhXOl4PuB/aMDWq5qd5WcT0atbnqHCRoO@7EBEtTU3AR3@/aSEvqb8CZTOyjO8eqdHWH5CvrrjlSPOftle4beBmi3a7nEeIs3tJLdPKRQjBh87tmN2wuznUL4bEdWP0OLZn26iy7LvzbzlwLPErYDNR/qhbkPMuizm2S/t6aD9EOHJ0YO84tLN8LHmO/93uBT189MDvPDyoMfJMzwZWvrOd8Sh@si@ZJSN9ncVHB3xf@8hRNK601lH2WXqpocr5dMIc30RmFViS4o6VHM1i3G2rDFs8XKbxyE/uCOKIxVu2C0eD5sG/AranzMgd15eGDwCdGDmZSb1iDZzQa@uqEC4E8rDgo2qtlcm6w9gQP4ceg3iSYHXrjpvBE@yLnFTFoaQMs2X@7aH5ljFncb6nvTDnrCZg/zgouHo9oH6A2M4AlLe5dnLU6hTPuUmOC7kH1OkzqLxj6BuFbTfQEd2JQyHWH3Tm/vXN/oO8G/fz13JvExqKPtFQ7U3B9E52U2cj5K/6Wiyaiid7puPM9UEtCTbx4Ibtw1Tf2mRa2uN20Rq6aCc50XOw5ceXVSr8J/PAUndYhdbfC/JCbGeezzr2VWlCNyy7nbihHwOgngVVN5VYuavKZ2ovFWqs10ViBbqLofqs2DWJ@M3JUXc4lQE2qzv0Z0mNucjZbL9y5co7SsDbhuq3kgE7O9ZA@0Kqtp4@o2CjYe5fjctVkTbSFNtGSdumXzjnukzW0MdnD7MD85RyE@SpuQk0DWPlQvolo/FffrOg7oteq@oCdPEfkd@jFXe3OhZlyhjbWtvb4Fj/byHk2nn1@9eF30X2Qc/QKhxduo0vvR@ny76/0AnDWkujcIObrRlzh5HlN0TAV/TnwFk16IFDjGD35YoIXoE@@X9jnxRsS/Ms69zS@t@ZGeoWrthuST7qcO7i4v8uebHdOpfZmwpaory1sEvXrLucdNtEq2TneNw5EsC4QIWcZhpz74tQKXFq/W4xpbuc/LNGnHMzLgF/PdeM7UAPa7z@ffkJiSfCRhmL3O/l/sXGMStNQz7iUGkfVy5znuILTVnzuLn5Odfv03uN@9pjPe2xSXBnoTov9KP0jje1dzoLLuDEa9Vert0zP5dMz0AbrLXMlh3lKjLIxX3TlokFvxIX7tkl/zXbHkpacF6hnrWD91bn3XerG2ZcK3Ww969egV7BJn7KcM6K1WGj/T9Ucyj0@JAcrrXHRDtYzi4sv1AXndvbka690z7NRsI5wLovpWbCdelMma6d471POwOzsHylcAWf0mZzFsFNXuXyxCxd1575EPFb6Eyb86U049V1w@pyzbtLLpXZQzgE25WeG1CiG1Cek1uWpe4t@p/JPUnMaomtqciZd9SeinwP1yCXnCTY5O3dnf9kUzglqkYh5oAOBNY8aCTQbpvbfTondwaWTM3lCeR@iIVy8ZsF4wTcqrqrUdNeiJo3JGeFryXlsuQZv99rIFwU/rGKujfM0RZOgzh5rfM7S3ersm8Bn3e78etQTyiZ0xufVH9zYy4x6jyVeM0zOvd/lbNvJmhr8/5I@HdjaSYz0jDeG4DpDYk5XffP5/@hhlzp8jefO/Pima9SEJyD555L9cOKtkveXTjfmNtdHW6xDlg4/dIFEs9PlPBO1hTVOWTfqqSWHmOF27qbk0LB5fSN@UXqkwoma210TGL2t4M2b6nK@1skPnjdher5tchG1v83kbAFwspQ7Vutzo/5H6WyFcDzQEzyokxTCXSh8b5OcPoQTtkvdc5N@XKe/QD@Xv8bXupxt0YmhQke3zh0b5LWa9CECa6vzo3bRwNjufZKlg90YnxXPYud8IE5Zdu9pMTlLp3K@JueLZf6IeBG8c3AVlCuN2nlp3oTo/ppo7Q7hygTPBNQzrOsMFI37jLnEmnddYZzvM6VuhjxYzzap3uwm2o9d@jmENxzXeLV98Lww25i/1XkM0m8Hzn644JJyjp9q6tceaXI2gb/S5lCd/E6NZuCCMSVehd5hY35RZ23t7P2aOCtBz5jZpM7ZXsX723/WLDDhRYLbjvN5YiN/MgbXj4uWyADeJHiHi340eqqHaOZXPiE5KnKLUI7GLvpA4vdK43GwrlVx1Sa6/XIW8FjEVK3zzCrUdcOpk1n9aOh9CanpTOGzdulvWnK@atqkIRpKiMurR0J1VHfWDFxrlFrPmMTVXc5gDtHFLXxCzhOqs8VctJKh/WR3zmnp6Yk9q9zj1ZnBJmdwl@9S7dRJ36LnBFadMURXdEpfrOjmoDcVtqj6gearMzV1v5vEEMpZ38lPAn9y6tgF@@8qdglyHEsrKXP4AKdIzu@1wTpyzWXjWfChvOrJ54E/dT2XyuQ8Gr@fr1LnU8c9TkbdE/pO6MWvPrgpusSyhm62eko/uOpKNWKnpV0mPbEunEzXc7WWnK@@S8@h9ls28rO1f7nGIvfPUAxzI980duKuLlyt6ouZnDNgv8DozMi3W87a7tTzYwd5aqXdmjlUxD0nXIM944rLqO4k@AejsY5z5GcDmI/2zwZrVcB5SyNJNFdwnmbFlDgzpLM@Cn5ESC8b6mbo58VZyqXz7aKfrud1ge@DcyIm@wfqPEnhf4AvqXyBOe/7s3hnO@Pxpblp@g5rdw225YKJXT7mPNfPlTfXqdFTfCxZxxVv61lLkxwX1fvB/i7Nwo2cZcxZ6/czq3GG2pReEJzZrdqRsQt3LqipZtKPbxrbN9bx9FxbrWchl4FttiVnJwi/ELFcpJ3pxvjC5CyM0aU@qf3LctY7ercQZyE/B@a4BGMu/rzYEPDGgLEt4eb2IfHoRl4WMAGbrBmDR2hx14Sd0quH@12v9IAwzyF90shjio@Emh6wqfj5559/@f7144cfzz//r88/v3nz5p8fPn398u3H04cf77/9@PLl4/enl@@PH3766ff3fzx9/fKP99@@v//xfLz68u7j@ze//vT0@O/7029PHz98l9@fv/72/se/ffv8@PQvf/37y4fPv/zx7cun/423PB@//vLp3YfPLz8@fPn8/fn726dvb57@@PLt6dvTh89P314@/@3988f3n5@/v/nT/ubNdQd/PL@8/fT243Hdb7/9@S//7d3jfz89/ePvHz6@f3o5buavj1t5@vTh8/N5P3XD50/f3v/78dPvz98fT/j46@XPv378y5vjv7f/@v4/fvv48und7y9P//j16eXd9@fn7//26fndmz8df/3jzZv/@unN8VAf/ng6fvHXN7/9tp3Pflzv/J7HD@/@9NufX375@uXr88svHz7//v7/PB838tf/z5f/4/zeN2/@wq9@9@Zffvv067fHV73D4@U4fvvnu5e//Y/HgxzD/fj9MVQfv3z515e/v3/5/Riy5/a2vx1v7e18ux4j9F/w9l9evn59//n35z@ev5yj@v3Pv/7l7dO@bdtbfsHj8X58@fHy8b@//O37/3yM0/Hy4zrHLX16@XpMxNsnfOHjvV@/ffj8WDSP33z/9ennpz89ff/x7fk/fcFjPf1f)

#### How it works

Say that the bag has 900 units in it, and there are 2 fruit available: a 99 unit fruit and a 101 unit fruit. If the 99 unit fruit is closer to the beginning of the lookahead list, then `min` will select it instead of 101. If this happens, we would now need another fruit to fulfill the remaining 1 unit needed. I changed the program to favor the higher-valued fruit in these cases.

It does this by sorting and then reversing the lookahead list before powersetting.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 9975 bags

- If possible go for 5 oranges
- When starting bag pick extreme value, balance later
- If possible fill bag immediately
- Try to keep bag weight close to estimated curve (n*200 for 5bag, n*167 for 6bag, etc)

longest out of all submissions but should be readable

```php
class Belt
{
    private $file;
    private $windowSize;
    private $buffer = [];

    public function __construct($filename, $windowSize) {
        $this->file = new \SplFileObject($filename);
        $this->windowSize = $windowSize;
        $this->loadBuffer();
    }

    public function reset($windowSize) {
        $this->file->seek(0);
        $this->windowSize = $windowSize;
        $this->buffer = [];
        $this->loadBuffer();
    }

    public function peekBuffer() {
        return $this->buffer;
    }

    public function pick($index) {
        if (!array_key_exists($index, $this->buffer)) {
            return null;
        }
        $value = $this->buffer[$index];
        unset($this->buffer[$index]);
        $this->buffer = \array_values($this->buffer);
        $this->loadBuffer();
        return $value;
    }

    private function loadBuffer() {
        for ($c = count($this->buffer); $c < $this->windowSize; $c++) {
            if ($this->file->eof()) {
                return;
            }
            $line = $this->file->fgets();
            if (false !== $line && "" !== $line) {
                $this->buffer[] = trim($line);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Packer
{

    const BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT = 1000;
    const MEAN_WEIGHT = 170;
    const MEAN_COUNT = 6; //ceil(self::BAG_WEIGHT/self::MEAN_WEIGHT);
    const MEAN_TARGET_WEIGHT = 167; //ceil(self::BAG_WEIGHT/self::MEAN_COUNT);

    public static function pack(Belt $belt, Picker $picker) {
        $bag = ["oranges" => [], "buffers" => []];
        $bags = [];
        while ($oranges = $belt->peekBuffer()) {

            $index = $picker->pick($oranges, \array_sum($bag["oranges"]));
            $orange = $belt->pick($index);
            $bag["oranges"][] = $orange;
            $bag["buffers"][] = $oranges;

            if (\array_sum($bag["oranges"]) >= self::BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT) {
                $bags[] = $bag;
                $bag = ["oranges" => [], "buffers" => []];
            }
        }
        return $bags;
    }
}

class Base
{
    public static function bestPermutation($elements, $weight = 0) {
        if (\array_sum($elements) < Packer::BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT - $weight) {
            return null;
        }
        $permute = function ($weight, $elements) use (&$permute) {
            if ($weight >= Packer::BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT) {
                return [];
            }
            $best = \PHP_INT_MAX;
            $bestElements = [];
            foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
                $sum = $weight + $value;
                $els = [$value];
                if ($sum < Packer::BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT) {
                    $subSet = $elements;
                    unset($subSet[$key]);
                    $els = $permute($weight + $value, $subSet);
                    $els[] = $value;
                    $sum = $weight + \array_sum($els);
                }
                if ($sum >= Packer::BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT && $sum < $best) {
                    $best = $sum;
                    $bestElements = $els;
                }
            }
            return $bestElements;
        };
        $best = $permute($weight, $elements);

        return $best;
    }

    public function pickLightestOutOfHeavierThan($buffer, $targetWeight) {
        $b = -1;
        $bW = PHP_INT_MAX;
        foreach ($buffer as $key => $value) {
            if ($targetWeight <= $value && $value < $bW) {
                $b = $key;
                $bW = $value;
            }
        }
        return $b;
    }

    public function pickClosestTo($buffer, $targetWeight) {
        $b = -1;
        $bW = PHP_INT_MAX;
        foreach ($buffer as $key => $value) {
            $diff = \abs($targetWeight - $value);
            if ($diff < $bW) {
                $b = $key;
                $bW = $diff;
            }
        }
        return $b;
    }

    public function pickFurthestFrom($buffer, $targetWeight) {
        $b = -1;
        $bW = \PHP_INT_MIN;
        foreach ($buffer as $key => $value) {
            $diff = \abs($targetWeight - $value);
            if ($diff > $bW) {
                $b = $key;
                $bW = $diff;
            }
        }
        return $b;
    }

    public function findMax($buffer) {
        $i = -1;
        $m = 0;
        foreach ($buffer as $k => $v) {
            if ($v > $m) {
                $m = $v;
                $i = $k;
            }
        }
        return $i;
    }

    public function findMin($buffer) {
        $i = -1;
        $m = \PHP_INT_MAX;
        foreach ($buffer as $k => $v) {
            if ($v < $m) {
                $m = $v;
                $i = $k;
            }
        }
        return $i;
    }

    public function minimalOrangeCount($buffer, $weight) {
        $elementsToAdd = ceil((Packer::BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT - $weight) / Packer::MEAN_WEIGHT);
        $buffer = \array_merge($buffer,
            \array_fill(0, \floor($elementsToAdd / 2), Packer::MEAN_WEIGHT - 7),
            \array_fill(0, \floor($elementsToAdd / 2), Packer::MEAN_WEIGHT + 7),
            \array_fill(0, $elementsToAdd - \floor($elementsToAdd / 2) * 2, Packer::MEAN_WEIGHT)
        );
        \rsort($buffer);
        $orangeCount = 0;
        foreach ($buffer as $w) {
            $weight += $w;
            $orangeCount++;
            if ($weight >= Packer::BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT) {
                return $orangeCount;
            }
        }
        return $orangeCount + (Packer::BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT - $weight) / Packer::MEAN_WEIGHT;
    }
}


class Picker extends Base
{
    public function pick($buffer, $weight) {
        $weightNeeded = Packer::BAG_TARGET_WEIGHT - $weight;

        $minimalOrangeCount = $this->minimalOrangeCount($buffer, $weight);
        $orangeTargetWeight = ceil($weightNeeded / $minimalOrangeCount);

        if (0 === $weight) {
            $mean = \array_sum($buffer) / count($buffer);
            if ($mean > $orangeTargetWeight) {
                return $this->findMin($buffer);
            } elseif ($mean < $orangeTargetWeight) {
                return $this->findMax($buffer);
            }
            return $this->pickFurthestFrom($buffer, $orangeTargetWeight);
        }

        $i = $this->pickLightestOutOfHeavierThan($buffer, $weightNeeded);
        if (-1 !== $i) {
            return $i;
        }
        $i = $this->pickClosestTo($buffer, $orangeTargetWeight);
        return -1 !== $i ? $i : 0;
    }
}

$bagCount = 0;
$belt = new Belt(__DIR__ . "/oranges.txt", 0);
for ($l = 2; $l <= 7; $l++) {
    $belt->reset($l);
    $bags = Packer::pack($belt, new Picker());
    $bagCount += count($bags);
    printf("%d -> %d\n", $l, count($bags));
}
echo "Total: $bagCount\n";
```

> 2 -> 1645 
>   3 -> 1657 
>   4 -> 1663 
>   5 -> 1667
>   6 -> 1671
>   7 -> 1672
>   Total: 9975

[Try It](https://tio.run/##zX39jx3VteXv/iv6Ib@oPYCoOp/7YOCJRPmSJoAmjBgpINSY67gn7bblbkPejPjbM7eq9tpr1XXbOC@RMkjG7r51q06dc/bX2mvv8/zJ87/97aP/eP7k@b17j64ubm7Ofnm4ur33f@@dHf97/uLyh4vbw9n9x5dXh4f7X/14ef39sx//ePl/Tj/47uXjx4cXZx@f/embh/e2j15@d3X56Ozxy@tHt5fPrs@@/fbRs@ub2xcvH92er7e@vnh6eE9v@eBsG8Dy3/3bJ5c373@yXHe86fXhx7Ov//j86jfHHz//7n8f9BYPHp5@iXc8fvWVIcuFV88uvv/lOvBzv8tPd4/9xeHmcHzkzw71/U9uDoe/nE//wJh2E/lfHe/z4yhwoYz0xeH25Yvr/ZPefJ/LR385v38c7OGvep/Lx2fn/3bx4sXFf377l8N/fnv46@XN7Y1f997@9g/0ezKG65dXV3y/n/imP1xcvVznSO/yp@3eMiMvr9cVueuiB6@f06@3Qa/PuNl/@8FbzLbO4XqP/eS5LMTs6Q1kFh4/e3F2fv/RcTiPnr28vj0dxtnxo49e3TbL799993Q2l5XY7b/Ds8fnr8w5x/1w9/ufdj/dv7q8lpnf7vf4z4fj0j54@MpTH19c3RzO/u3jj/17v/jF2Tvv8Oe7hrBfrW@Oj7p9cfn0fLv@dSP7yaf4J2iqLy4e/eXw4qir1g9WnXL2y09/@@2Xn/6P3/76y2@/@vXvf/u7L4/3nqdpeijX/OHXn34mn/ZXP/zV5//zs@Wz9vDsgw8eHS6vzm8OV48//HC5@/bFD7ZfyK0evHKXV8bR@lvdb336g73yvLm9uN3J4/HdzxdVfVS4x/@/d/bF5TIZZ/efr3/vtNJ3F39etMg7z15cXP/5cPPO2cefHHXKe2fvbPOPX6iWOX7l5kTz/Phk0cDn9/0uy/ZYnvz@J6pilufut9IqicvF28COl6@axO/yHgTx5uVx@Y9P5Si/eXCyE/w78mDRSSeX7u@07jD/@l0XYh52F948vPfKVn/DYM8@@fiMi7pb@jslYJnh7XHHfz288/O/c9HukhbVU8sTH57K0C8vbg6w9nfvtO8ON7dfHF48fbn8/tn1@f3D1eHp4fr2ZrHYh8s/P7k9jnM6NQo6U/jCg6M222T2jkk6ex@3@3vtxPN1cMu@iDGf@62OQ@TDXx611PkvcPmd@tPf57iUrx3n6zXqTlruUKrLRC6W54vfffHt7z/78ts/fPq/Hr56xa99vCfS5@bicPHoyRln9Ozi5uz@0fAue2GzQ3futeMqrL7G9nbv7kzW7sLD1frc7fNvXr1gnaTlbh/9fRPko/juj4dlBmL4D@@80A36dvmfltf75sHdV/p4saTnp2/4Hh76hu9vMviaCblz9vZb@@aOe//0@ol709ZaLKfP7roVXjuTvpOWax@@/grZScs4f26YP90ldLsbifSpqfDBnCyCip5oUr3vzzqc/3250fHCz1/efv74d4eLHy4PL758cnHUQZsSXDzMixdHv@SrVxTH/e@OY3p/1nF@dfzNnbJHuXL38GelanO25NFnH2ETrYu4/WtZxq/uVv7LhB2fcJfe/@o1@/GNqv1np/JXV89ujjP55bN/@dzd//7y8ePVA//u5mQS38dXXnUyt2/9AzO6fP@fOaG/efni9slxRn/z4tnT//qc0hj8/rN/1aR@8v/HpD4@OnJ/uPgr3nk3eZenk7do5OnnJmybrjtl94flrZ/e@dKrsv/hjle@XGfj7V/38udf9/L67V/3679D/t745h/9i9/86eX15dOLq89Xx/ZXW@Ab8vOqCxhm5Mtnn37//RIrL/HT@Vs5kh@EsX01UNu28Qke8PRwlJwYzu6F/YpjMHx1Ph3jlsdXz569OD8Z3Qdn6cF7dz30OKr@4J96w3d/7oYnd3r/DU84@29n6c6nPIgHyKx9/eLm2YtYNJ3OZ1zTtxDQH1/RYvCxFnfrzuBvvfW77z78Z7vuevu33@f6uu@e/QNbUsIyYBtbOH/46@3h@vu7wrQTZO5NArT96rPD4fvDIj9vMUxx2O6/Kq5Eht5GlF/ZHl@qdXJx3o/xg7ueql7ksuLT2ccff/y6mPH@08PFNcV6C9hd0X4AtO2V/Rubaf32J3cN@E17CGjZXrGfbKezoyt@4EM@@gceIsby4Vu48ts33@C73DEQDbj39klu9xZuui6v3HSZh/fnDSu8fE3cD2tyEvWfjOEu//aN7@N3j6ef/cfyvw@htFZZXCATUWYr7OQ5iAV6O3/n@ZPnH37wwc3t95fX77x3toD9G6R7dbwqPTw7/n2MC/ryDwK2Dl55IuHKhwTEDcK54nsO7S3P2/TB@QO53PVOgMfLHR5EMub69vH5O/9@VPufnP37918vw7t/9d7u0uO1P907PHry7OydL5/dXlx9yLser394729/m9t0L03Tvbm245/53tzKvdmWv9P2c6/Hn4@f9@MfO/6uHz9v4/jn@PvWt@8tn9d8/Pn4Zxz/2PGzfvysH/@dbfu8zdt3@nJf/7keP8t5u7aY/97vu1y3jKMen5X7Np6@PKts91@/v4xp@b6Pt@OaZczH@/Wx/Y13qXX7/vK85d/Lu1YfU/d/L9eu42w@prQ9Y50D4@@X54/EeyzjXN6/tG2u1mun7Xfmc7jOVffvFB/z2OYJ81x8PMszlvcqw@fcx5vTNj/LmNaxpm09MMblumWdqs/rOgb/e7l3W96pH9e88fnL94fPi/lcL/OUff7X71Sfa4zf169M2@fLfGAezf@9jmXe3mN5x5KOz13WSuZi@X3FGHwd1/ezbU469s7k62g@X93XpPia4u@07cHlz3Kd@br3iXPRGud9HXvfnt/xx69b1n5Zv3Uu2/b@1ddjmWNr2@/X9RG5GOaykvw90raHl@uxt6s/J/t4lj1S0ro223OP9xvL77rff9o@W/5dfI0G1tufv469bXtvncN5@2yVyeLjXfZW3j5f7z37fEB@IOuV87t8vszDusZd5qDLHsSYu69R9T1dt71uPq5lDy7vt@zr5bPhv1/ldNo@W@Zv@LPX8fXt@evPTWSq@pyP7XvruLp/N7kMju0Zy/Oqj3/5XfU9u4yt@s@hEwavW9/LfD9V3w9Dxpe3fbvuB9cfVWRuGOV1Gft6bfP5mPjZMpelcR6rz8c699P27EXfLN/P1fWt6NFlrdd9Me31Y3f5XPVFdT1vXO/j7zaZxF43l03sYd/362eNOnzVA1VkCXILvdm2@VzX2@1E9@@vehN7afK9O1FPDJeJuumqsC/rNT7/y7p1l491XEbZG65/oWe76y5L1C/LPcxld12n7Lp@ph7t2xqv9tF8rdd97/sDtmKRJ7zz8p3q@3K5btl3q/5abOHg8xt0htvY7uu9zlFz3ZXFhsFGuM7seJ/G@6/PdztreGffbwN60Z@/zNFqb1ynxp6HPc1@b9crrXJOu4@ruXyt@rtTD9eJ9rv5O5vPB2Rs@XeDfE@uy4bsk8J1X95/QPcbZWdsOjJNgzpylbu63bf6PlrXwvUIdCR0HnTbqqc79f9qM1xvrmtU/H1xH/dZ1nkarguNe7i5TFeXZfM5qH6/0J2dfkl1nbLaYqN8VZ@bXikXy/sscrJcV2GPoIfwfLynr6El@mF4Rtgv2JPZ5wf2KolPWGhXmuvtdb0z91fMgeucVY@5zV7HXsT2NveXIHN9m6MBGXNbsYwju9/XXUYq/LvFf/X3xV7Not@tuY6D7@Jrt/pWttkE83EX2BKfx5Hp16x/Tz7v8I193NX1obnf2GCzXBetfs3M65pRFxnk1W2jzaKroMPhj8q4oQs7dA18AV9Py/RJzO1WcZuM/QMfZcB3HbRpBj@@bPNZXJ@s6@7vOnxOVrsN/w97r9Cedbc3sEPHd93WA2ORvVr8vZrLW3Mb1gf1GGxB6Kfm9xruS0H/iB3o7iOv3zXZw2PTE6PKnLrt6o0@W3Nbs653cX@jUU/Cfo3EGAexUndZwhhC58@0VTE/IvfrddC9fbMz3fW8uQwV1zFYmwo/otMvX8dg1FMV@8Ln01zOoF@6@/195r3X53aXdexvtyE2aLOa2/jq79HFZ2yue1efyOcO/mb3vQSfv870/bvHJmFL0t4fG9DFrlPrkBgq@VohFin@XON8NferO/yFeRtjha2AL@G@ShV/uRSOo2OuM/@u7oNXkZvqcmVGW4l4xjAH2EfNdaDuK@iS2feg2@1WuT@6xHOGmCxz7ObriZggbCviKN8riCFrEf050wda18Kvs8L1xh4osOd@j@a6ZdVlmEff37DBoR817nI/Fv5/b/tYDb7GqqN9r2P/ho9UGWuNRp/fGn0sPKN2@ibmtuH4nTTBz4X@M8ZsJn4t9HuFT4dY38dT4bNV8UtdrldsYZb3crk7fp7mOd47zdAbHjfC/4Gv2BLl0wrnedUfs8ip4wtD4/AhPtBMm7DusUH9AJ8vfEa3udUxhJJoszEPq6@RqFMRZxf3@bBnm/sOaxwMH8vHPgpxH/ha5uPt7q8Pl7HwF9wXLE387UT/ynz/V/jBSXQa5MRtdc1iDytjScQI8A@aCRay7a8Ve4H/bNif8FXhh2JuBm1kcxns7rvBh6wuo9a5xyIWTPRJgZEY9Jb77d3fp8LnFl2N9auF89NK7MctPvJ9b7DplboY/qcV@sLd/cHVr5f4HviZGeUWvgHs@/KnOHZhje9V3HYCf6quT4rLK9Z@0VXAKIEdwObBdwt/LtEmxVo3wblgI1yXhr8OfwDv5bJYIM@zYzCIQXxuyqDvXF1WFzlZfKIC3TZow9og1gcfIfwUE1zPBCPzvdgybZ35M0OeZ9q55v/GmlXY9Ep8En7Ysv/g64budf06ENu5zTPX59WItXX3w4bLmxXiplWwl1a4VxT3gn/bPe7uiHslToGMVcepIH@Y94jRB7FGmwU7TNsYWxYfr/H61a@uojcmmePk/pcRwwCukF3XmccqiAHgM8JOAtc19xdrps1dsZNGn3ld5yrxbiE@0FzPBXYI@@xrUEXWYVthy@F7A@MrxmeFbwvse/J1Eiwu4j3HsJc9WgqfCX02PE52ed7ivL7Jw/DnAGcDhpgH9x/8lFY4f4FjVMeZNv86zfAvgLkCV@2C9yJemqhngOeu8wY8C35xZew7sP/8faBrEJMAWy@J@Cbipeq2uML3r/6MWXAowfcgN/BprUseB35F2tbCPIcy8j6OxF4x8W0xf5BryG81yRH5HkDcF7qpRhy3@jDDxziGYCuIM3vE9ts@SoKFIo51HdoH91xrkiPogt3N4rO4PUEs0yfG99h30DEjCyZWiHd0YDnAD8RmAy9e1mFUYi@Bc8IvtW3PA3MZhRgDYuqeJC71PTMEk444sRDXa26Lusd@aaIfANtkmTEhcMQiNnvVPUPwf9GBdURsts4t4ltgaBV7Bvh8367D3BXYyUG5hd9aOrFkM9ok2FKbGEtH7srE9zH6huaYlvn8IOcEvB57P2JysTHwxSALQ@bMMYbt3Quxmeq6rgLPh69X9tg4YvIyMz@GOB@yWitlecWyHJtpifoQ8mJDMA7Xnev9K330Nktc6ZhbdfuesK@hn7F/oN8d27Mm8aWvW4Z/iryV6xXMc6niMybBuZvjzx6fDN/HwzHNmhjn10z7tDwvw657/nAk4mJ1lvy0ue6Hb14p@6PzHYHNIhe4@pfG/FLMxST2I9H/Qv7XKvcSbBuwe@T66mB82D2XMwR3BhZhjfsibITnTSru2WnDq/vz63y4TJchPhx0OfI4LqPWJV51nWpGPDRsWxbZd9@8QqaM/lLoriE@CPCyyhgVvnOX2NZ8PrDHkPMFjhe6sVAXVugrczsC22f0M/pMnbLLvyfGvyuGLHkT5FXhvxUTbCFxL8c8GeejCX7aCvGoWuh39on7CnyGkrnu5utXjWsS36v0z4fL7SrPQ3CTKjqkkCMBfYo8X2kxz2sMFz7C8JjOY3LFYyOfBJxWsalCn7FVckJCjxfOTxscRxNfA3kb5JiBdbYicbjaVNkbFXiV0V4Vn4OO3DLkJROftLLPZUA2AyubJfcDbHgwFiuDcTO4Gsg/IC4Dz6Jgb3TGwBGDDvrzqq/7JDhfFVtkvlYzbYzrqC2GmOn7r7Gg0fcP@@b57pao6@Gzaq4NvumyZ0Zmjgg@RG8uQ0NwjMI8XkM8LDZ39SGggyvzoqPQdnW/36qXkbsCduk2sg3iYGUwjsmYW5e1AuwAeXrB7wf8MeE74fnApIDnhH4Hxpqp42OtHUeI3Gxn7qu4vkDM0o25wODseKwFvKO63gYPCro4MPvEHF/4ukmw4dlzvfCRC@3eMGLj4DyUQYwQ/gF8nHXvJOFY1PCrVn8HWACwjcgxSo4GewO4XB/EGSMnaNQ5qx8pth0xXPiEyFnUTS8M1w/wrwPjzxKbFc59xHOVfmpVrhCwQsE4hug22MLVhxrM0a9@rftIIYtpjz9Gzjdv8mBD7GSi7AC/RY5FuW8GHBD52kx8unushrwQ5jVkE/iu66fA2SfGNMANgAn1ts8ZlZm4eOxdvwbyi72L@BA/d6Pu7EOwaxl/dzsMHLhLXgg6sfpehlyXtOflDM0jCTcQfp8NyZcWYue9h3@76lXECV18BPi/vQpPSeQqOGaCn5rHgTFHWeYccZZxz7bEfEF3fyrymFlkspCPCC5frVvcndQe@ngHMDbfG8j7rLq@@H5GLJ9E7zbxoavkXo37DHoa8whepIlvCDzSgPEP4dAJh2d0wUuEBwAcBL4rPov4yvdBcb0xJuZJgzM6E1dC3t8S5S34G7Dnjfwc4L@QIfhqWIcxCedqUJ4w9jYE@23kwASOZoxpi8dA5uOsVWTU4zTlO/YkOUlwRmfG9E38TlxbZ8EMJvrkwBxbJwe2Cz7RJvrE2ENt5ppHPFooQ2Uwvx48EbdPkWstJ7myLvio58pKFgw/k6uC/Q3934z5w9olLoG/gzxD51xVcCScx1iNOs2SvAO4b104dxJXB8Y0yIEDNjV8P6xxcaOfMRJtQa@025o3dnuU5ix@lPpFs8vuIHZik@BW8B2wl5TzlLk24BzbRD@vuD@muc8yE6uEnwosphSxERLjYT7B94v4S3xwK4JNip8RfNQisbPoJfjezZjXQl4BnKTA75PgdrI2PVPP7/LUwllY9VZlzG7i0wdv3UR3D/GHjNfnLLzWIVy4IXFPpQ1DfjXyKRO5EuEvSJ4WvCznCaV5MMZDflFjho7nG/M24QsjXzCTGxV@VBN9kKinwQmDbgCmGzl84TNDlwMHroP8nlUPlW2@gDkB44XuGcZcUAe/SGN0zzHkTp1gUvugcUOVfCv4kjYLd7kLRoxYsgi3I1FPD@ytiTkw7Evk1KxyfoDd98RngR8F3jt8fivkWTbntQKrap6jsE6@aG20L9V9QMhcrLPLPvI6ZYifKDkn@IW1cg9FXOq8Htjz4Ggl4SpN4gNlcsWb6xhgaA15J2BElTl3@OvgtqhvDBteO/Md2fFzcOvGTGw46g9m4hGI/yP@HeQrmD/XPH9kmfFodzlwvkP4@mvsNGini9jLKrjHcB00ZvEvYSOa1EMYOS@1ckyIK4FFRb4OOS2J5yHj1W1xlbg2m8Szk@wt47wgbzwkZ7vsp4y6j0niVdgyl7kivKs@9pwl5MGh2yrkSXhQiOOjBqJxXiLflAQfzMJx8jkfiflN5BitEq9FzIBYrEleE1w7zJ3KNjhUbSLnEX494mlLrEUqJjgQeA@ZXCXsbfgFBXbEfRrnSJPbMPZ8Vs0t1Yn8@4jtkQ/pwk3R@pwhOVa/V@Rgh2BJiTFbFb4L9P5wrmtwmoUvsMq6c2pM6mWC9wH@aKY9Rn4DnF3k4Vd/qexrE6CzgPvXmfysnvb58@p7yDT/Wfh@iDWBC5XGnOGOf5HkM2M@HXngsIGur4fnLZBbRE4guAoT@QDgd1lnbFNn8h3rEJ@@72OSyJPbttcgv2sOSnPuiTwhyHtvrIsKPpURXx1SjwJcRPmi4NyCewaucTHm@5AnLYOcg@D1zuRmhc6Y@G6B62Vya7rwc2BH2kz8EphU8Gf9HsBBwR8JG4O4PlFGgkvo/nfUWhT3nxu5vMF5K8KhLcIzTYK/uy@AGKEUsc@S9xueH4LOATcOsVAT/7sI97EjT2LMMYKrptzYavsYcrDGM82VublWhXMKfC5JfhH@@8S8LuoNEb9i/wTOaiccgEK@AviKqLHolTjh6otIXFhm4bgCX/d5hN/djZw96Drb7rPiQqMxZxh2qbhtkloLyIfWW4JjkGGjkvhOoh/aJPsRay/7GzVbqAGI2GhiDWWX2KA7zlHanmeoOYnI0bvMB/cmSV1oo80os@SUZ8ZPiE2Ah42ZPmzwRRrzYjVJ3jSTU2ULDmeeS/E80xDOdR6sgwGfH9w4@Bij048Et7F04V1LjL/qQcc4u2B1wZGoxClh/5HzBl80OGGJ3GRwnDVXiJ@x5iY576J4ivsu4AsF73Umn9BkfiCb8OchdyE7ReJI8ENnYvuYQ8Qa1pjLib00ttpE6JhahKc/KDOh5wZrz5EHhgwj9ovYY0hN3iD/BDWm4JVA55vUVYDTPpJg@p7zjTrGLlgieKfCc4J/HznNIrFdk3wYeCS2nx@M3WPvLb@aqHtQI1EcW0V8hL0GXDw4r7PE62LbRiXPvjl3FDwK4MamNedZYiqtP2ziq3bGC7F/pN4jGfkR8LmAoyMH0JHTsOA6rPFP8B@ycNkn@qzwv4rHDm67uXZN4tSyz4NGHq3I/ipi75pw8pLEaFXG4zbbusSv4BlqrwSpIQefzrZ8/ZZbd39uzZElqeEW/Htg36DHgBF3AS8fMh71jYPvBb49eHLhI2TycYvkqzr6NqDvg@j34JXPwhlL5P@s93JdBf6OJXKwgwswk2cKPj34WsEPT5Q1E26@ZfrqXXjOjXY3uLHBL5qY24APGz5m4x6MnFATPmxhTGmJNYxd8YCZeE1xn1r0GfOBwr3V74OftdYOJakvqlKDUoUT6ZyeqMsADuk6dUh@K/DzWTiCRgwzclknPACNc4Bp@XuuOhZ@OzBK1Gcr7qn8ftR/IPZozh0Inp0xV4L6tCJ6CXELYrYmPTXgCxbx7YvE9zs7VgTzT7L/OnmiVfIFeJbWvganEzYw73My0DvwV4OnjvoM9znzJFyATJ3SK/PIdbA/BjhUrQg3s7KeLfz8ac87qlKbDhwcGEslP2TLibQ9pwGyrT54cC18DocJDui4KewKchha9wAbXCfZvzPrp4a/E2oCq3MjR2WNPGLkCvxjSL44S/1LYiw6JJZEPiNw9iTPqGLz3S@MWr0kOOLEuh07zfl11lKA5wtbMCbyGyIem5lDRIxpUruPevXIXQDT66wTh68R9SKOg0fNw8SY0u3rxllFbwfPmYVOTBIneJwRMaI/s3rfAOy/PsijA@cefhRyhMEP0BrJwhqXwA8m1vBH/xVw8Af7uQR/1qQGynnRQ/jSQzj13ZjPLmKDgIMgDw@/qnj8lbrUOyfGloG/dfbeQf8g@CxaC9ROcr9tIo4D7kXgyWLvWmVtHOqfov9KEr9U@g1F7eIg3pWH@I@JNXzNbQv4IIgHSt33JUIeSntpFNtjJlHTLz2M4E9gDbv3/0G8Y1J3V4QLMbr0MqiUafDtA9cx7qlRyRuGz6D9MMDjjtxsk7oEWUtwxW1QL/WJfD5w5KpjY036kizrnYW/G/7DkHwmcvfeG0btW3DyBuMScPMhz859SVOn7kR@DNwJrRPr0iOqi3@G2LZrb6oqejsLBllZ04h9H3HQvO9Vg7xyk9y8eS4M3DvEshpTgcsBm1wyuXGIxU1wLXDh8fzwh2fhk7hvih4ikR/FfpPaU/RRQv2RwdYK/gO7EPy2SbDavK9Z7oLNjE4@XGCcErsihqvYE5W6AFh8cNETcyGIR6K3z0ReR9SujD33FuscOTKpoe2KUVTi6Yjf4KsEVyQJ1j7Il6mDecsmOmkI/yE7/3wg9y79SBpw3M1Wp0lqpBVnBRepdOLCqPeFj1LByTD2NYj@aRP97qj5z1LjrvzzTAwNHPvI8/leXHOHJrnzwdg6eikl6XEncRf6fZnk1oGDRY5mFv@1kcOMWBt1z5YYMwIHCFvDetOUPN/SpKY4ajrF/0F@Fz5K6KJGO1w9n9m09r7y52rshYa9Gjzmk5puzJFJ/wiTWLEaY1fISx77fT3Svj8S4l7kU6L@ExwQ1NagzrUwZox@IKJXoBPHxFxccd2aC3siIDbqUldqg720inDqy0ksgf43wHOQLwmMS/I1JvWp0Jnd2BdD86nDsYEqOaKo356kh1qmDPWJ/nj018rSy1B0a3DfsvhCHhuhH0LEUZW2GL3iwLeMXL4R54k8fyGeBp8@@GpSdw4urrmvqz266kQ9Hz0FpS4D8Tf8iiJ5YfQ0M6nxgL@LdanSV8SG4DFF6hAb3xM5rCp9FksinxI1Fi1Jr0Sv1SjSBwj4TjvhBJnw82tmzy3YZ@htcF5ss8Wb/kX/ssE9gbxg9IbrrF8LXkg9yc8Y@0usde1dahsa5zf6TCBunIg/73ITVeqYk3P@OznzUceQ@fzYK1rTkvb97lDfHnxCC9sW/eBaF39N8prAWIbUOqAHInK2wd@fiPlFP5rM/hnAl7rmNJzHMsDPMGKfJvyq8BES37O4bUENH2pRmnB38N3Rhe8373Ve9Bvrwl0zqWtpe93fPT9pSeznJPwanY8htb6F@d3oUVtZP7yr/3eMEPEp8lrNeybCHwZXbWfnFYcUnizq7JrXrkettfTJaOLjBze7iR6GnHg96ND6nS49pEzqzSf2@Im4uFF@oPvUlzDxi9G/ETIAvlcGb9X3eEnkL9SZ9fraXzV8pMY8Bmrcm@zvLv38gHWhBiHqgTJtBOp9DLWk7osMqaGOut0mvfv6vocF8D3U9VX2jlnjzagL62K3OvOwTXAecMgRPwJfbMK1WOt/C2VV91LPzGOlQk6/ST8n7WmKXAO4iNDDqMNGTjJP7A8WmFyiDeq@RtmELzmTm1klF2CCfTXpo3LaW6pJrAFeQ9SmJPY9jvqgQb0GTkeX@tAmNTXR58h1POx8n/YYMGoAemd/nTKEL1CE2yP9ena1R5m4LjArcD9Mcpmoe/c@HJEb6JI/6Vq7ksnrHp09QVB7En16tA9r2@cIo0ZvIs8i6gMn2qmKHkeT@OCJsoPeHwX8jib9GDY8cMUMmtbVo1@E8Cc1DwhuceRM0IOgk0vWhEMe@IXWTbY9jgs7VaTePnhDM3EV5OwMOLvkDZrY6Mg3VLG3EzkewFJ29/R5syG94OY9jx@2FPnflQPs8jYEm4HsIH4uTWrWpT8dYs8qNUNrrNDJL9X@FMH1zcSioj547LlGyLNFzq6Lbu2sayqIaea9LgXvvkpfK9Qzlyrfwe86@3cBW23gEDfJJyfh2BtxruCptn1cWjpryKrUIMDPi5rERMxI60uBkaN@BTVd6HHStQ5vnNTCJfFlC7ma4NygZhA5uip5w@hnlmlPqui36OMHH2ZijRj68EW9n/Szck72liff8LeNZ9RP4ivRuYg7oq6s0geGLoZOjZ6JUj@apcdPlV6oqN0cs/BnB3swoF@BSY01eg@Ao9lFBoOj2MiNjd6TM/v3Q56H9A1cxpK76OIq@S3UunZintrXUPEY6HH07UB/LtR3Ql@b1EB06U2GGKULdo4ei5F7rcIZnYRbJngV/MnIdxpx5YEeil7/637QGpMBv2qCgRYj57toD5cNC9jxbSJP1YhtgrcaNUTSr0J5ksE5Im6YkvRYqNNJH9pJ8sHoZ15Yb4pYpqUtnq3Q@UX4mIM9ccCvCPuguX@sf5Z@zN4LqEsfLOSpom90Yj3WKh8TOXF4bnAHB32Z4NjDhmX26oIf15wXPYz7M2q9M32MqIEutCewH9H/Qnic0FOj0F8YReogJ/poiMtRKwM/C/FncDAS/YzglSvXRvrAgWcSPd097m0yx2NmrWHgeifxOHrXaK@q2va4K@okqtSkwzeJnk8z9UKRvku1SH1bln45JueZVKmNzOTIay0d/PimOaYqvT2lTnJXg9r5fRMuduhAx3C0NgljW3O3mRwH4GXBNxvEvhCjRl2S5IxN@V3GfmuBG5vgqNO@n2yTmqrg/Wbmk9FbEXGZ645VT9WJ9bPICQVOV6Sn/RDMtot/UNkfLuRtFt9a@4@5TQJWWqF/MzFUk57mNZ3EYrP0l5aeLeDahW4urG8sZY9r2USdpPgkZDTqASbhNA3Kv2KJuKfW@AZeOaR@d5I66cTePoGba22@0W8bTbDnIf0tRA@OxP7T4Q9XqZGRPqj9hFcbvbkn3k/Pawj5dwwffTTXuizRtxH3Z/a0AhYVHHG39UN6hQ7PGUefZ@/hWwf9e@ATRc6jsMJeW3rejL4nMHhLol@a9DhD/66ZvEztBWDppF9nE1wpSf@nsrOz7B2bJU@Z9jV5kU@dJT9c9@eydOHktkQsSGMy6G70RQQnzzT@HcF15JkKhbop@lfM0lt3CGcykyfdpFYFtiB6LzjW3aVPFrga2FvBD86scwrsJklNmcQuVXo4mPP6CupIqvC9Z8YCYzo5l0N6zDfNJ0gf3yZxt/a1hW5FLF4kv4P4GnuvVvYyQ31b9OMaUqtQpa@n9Dlv0rMF5840sZnRq0ziWausD4ieYEZ8F1zYIv3mgkMPfkajPzzc1g/ydTdukpwvgJ7K6OEefcWlTzl0aZG4Abasax@zyjH7fbY@HkbcbjgesPT4ntOeBwQ@NMaNuY6zQJrwmyWfMaQX0sjk/CLfCNsR2G0TvMAkrjep7@3k449ZchzT3meKekSVySFcE@kNpGeqac4zsO1KfKQLlyn0ivARwufwXAywumHSf2OWeocquRYjhqE2PHKTidgP8ijAPYPzm1mHH328MvGsJv05lJs1CvOvK@cgs@4EsUacgeB2M3rPyJk@WvMefI9Bf0V6ri32dOMUdvrTYacm4WHM9EtjfzXxN7KctSWYQm9yLofUkTapw9md7aN2qErNzsy@eVaEdyj8hIhXi/D0suQ@KntCNjlvI/paot9OoT8NvmQznqOFM3eAfeHMlshPKSeqSM3ILHnNmbzGJnUmgQdLzUxzTi7qPJvYKZO@RhE/C/8YsWeczdKJ8Vuj3oUdyca@sKtedXkoPndZ@6S4fIzMOuyY6yJxtvcJrIIJhg84se86Yo1dXx89k2JmTbNJvd8Qn2sI9z2wS5Mcm/LSpZ9SL3IeWCPPMvrzNeFsF54z1yRPW4214YGPSe2p9umKvdKFNyM4psZMkY8dgqvOrMuo4qM36a0cPRfQT3Qi/z16TyvPsYkvpLzmvq/FCf7PoGyntOfVop5@FJ555/df6@bgM@zOrpGzOVWXgGsc/EXWWG54SmLcFOdQCqcsS74AfdW62Gnwpbpw6YEf4OzG4J925nyRsylN@s9Lb43oD2DkNyDuC67tHBymqCUDVo1a2jhLYKZ@AI@koAf9JDYliy8wiJk0wWdKpZ7s7vug55jyatEHEThf4NLSM9j5MlufYeFCRKxs3t9T8KPwR73@JfKFOG@rMgaMM/iS@2iden2HpxfJY0mdZfRwqtL3rrOOGTmQOANJuZbgFc7CKUzM39lgnW13HBBnigFPRK229l0d0lc3cB3ptVXlvM3gHRn5/IgnsvCbQr58z4YvKmd2oV8X6nbAS437u88EHw97AZwoYOxD8sgl7XGA0eScubHnciIeGhP1ZjLhIDbpkwIeQaJdU37eGKwpj7oco0@BnlDmPs9IrNcFr6NJT9PRhCuVpM65sZ/1mKU2cZLamcRcRQMvuzGftK5L4xkhwLyRg0EewyRXjL7UwYkEtt3YZ6bq@R9Stwo5LUXOAwWHz3hm8pj29dyBvxnPZ4x@9oXYIGp@w05U9kWq2lfc5FyHytxh7tKvx/Z@SPQcGrRjwZtJcqaU1DcA/97Fe5nc4D72XOkqPIwu5xMplyJ8RumDg7gB94h@cl6PGnxj4Xt3rb/Icr7YRJyuSq@N6DXWpHfvtO87F2fRGPuqoSdXXO/9cC3tudfQ8V3O10M9gAm3usr5hzirNOqSTLhmk/RSLtIrL0sv9JkcK5wvh74fkJla2MtN@20F1yOxN1ecg4TejjMxweipKbiIzfveSF3yb8CZquhHM85V9NUtEq/0fc@R4DlPJ33fwMuQ3u16HiHO4o1@iUY@0hBMuNq@Zzd0Ls51G8JjW7D6Gb1k0slZdln4t5mxFniU0BnI/0QuyHiWRZzbJPW9sR7SO7BkYuw4tzBsL3iMeV/vBT591MDMPD8oMPBJzgRXvrKe8yl1sCY9T4bUfQYXFfx94S836WmluYbQz1JLNZKcbzcYw1fpM4pekeCORj@awrxdUR3Web5I4JWT6Bf4EYm@ahaMBu8HuQG3Js7LLOwrDxsEPjFisCr5hl54RmNFXZ1wIRCHBQdFa7WqnBusNcFF@DHINwlmh9q4JjzR3Ml5hQ8avQG6yN8sPb/cxwzut@R3mpz1BMwfZwUHj0d6HyA3U4Aldcouzlptwhk3yTGh70HUOjT2X6ioG4RtrdJPcCYGhVi31D3nN2fKB@puUM8f7z2Jbyz9kbr2zhRcv0qflJbI@Qv@lklPxCr9Tsue74FcEnLiwQuZhas@sc40sMVp12tky5ngTMfOmhNTXq3Um8AON@nTWiTvFpgfYrPK9YxzbyUXFPMyy7kbyhGotJPAqppyKzt78lXVF5251pqkxwr6Jkrfb@1NA5@/VnJUTc4lQE4qzv0pUmNe5Wy2HLhzxBzRw7oK1607B7RxrYvUgUZu3W1E@EaDtXc@L1tOtkpvoUl6SZvUS/sa58YcWmmsYTZg/nIOQjvxm5DTAFZelG8iPf6jblb6O6LWKuqAjTxHxHeoxe1pz4VpcoY29rbW@AY/u5LzXHn2@VaHn6Xvg5yjFzi8cBtNaj@iL/980i8AZy1Jnxv4fLkSV1h5Xk16mEr/OfAWq9RAIMdRsvPFBC9AnXzesM@NNyT4V82Uadw31kZqhSO3OySeNDl3sFO@Q59Me06l1mZCl6itDWwS@ess5x0m6VUyc753HIjBvMAYcpbhkHNfjL0Cu@bvOn2a3fkPXfpTFsZlwK9b3/Ed2APa9j@vdkJ8SfCRimL3M/l/Y@IcRU9DPeNSchyRLzOe4wpOW/C5s9g57dunYx/7s8es7X2T4Mqg77Toj@h/pL69yVlw7jeOxP6rUVum5/LpGWiF@ZbWncPcxEeZGC@actHQb8SE@zZJfc20x5K6nBeoZ61g/8W591nyxl6Xir7ZetZvRb@CSeqU5ZwRzcWi93/TnkMu40VisOg1Lr2D9czi4AtlwbmNNflaK539bBTsI5zLUvUs2Mx@U1X2TvDem5yBmVk/ErgCzuirchbDzL7KYYtNuKgz5RL@WPSfqMKfnoRTnwWn9zXLVWq5VA/KOcBV@ZlDchRF8hOS6zLve4t6p7BPknMq0te0ypl0UZ@Ieg7kI7ucJ5jk7NyZ9WVNOCfIRcLnQR8I7HnkSNCzoWn9bRPfHVw6OZNnKO9DeggHr1kwXvCNgqsqOd3e2ZOmyhnhvct5bL4Hd2NN5IuCHxY@18R1atKTIM4eS3zP6LuVWTeB71rd8@uRTwidkOmfR31wYi0z8j3V8ZpS5dz7Wc62bcypwf53qdOBrm3ESFd/owiuU8TnNO1v3u6oYZc8fMznzPh419coCU9A4s8u8rDirRL3R59urK3vj9SZh4w@/OgLJD07Tc4zUV0Y8@R5o@y95OAz7M7dlBgaOi9PxC@iH6lwotq07wmM2lbw5qv25Tztkz943kTV822di6j1bVXOFgAnS7ljsT8n9v@IPltDOB6oCS7skzSEuxD43iQx/RBO2Cx5z0nqcY32AvVcdoqvZTnbIhNDRR/dOHeskNdapQ4RWFucHzVLD4xpXycZfbAT/bPgWcxcD/gpve5rWqqcpRMxX5LzxTx@hL8I3jm4CsqVRu48et4M6ftbpdduEa7M4JmAeoZ1nIGifl9lLNHbvq8wzvdpkjdDHKxnm0RtdpLej1nqOYQ3PLb5SnPheWF1YvwW5zFIvR04@8MEl5Rz/LSnfshIkrMJ7KQ3h/bJz@zRDFxwNPFX0e8wMb6Is7Zm1n41nJWgZ8xMkudMJ/7@9GrPgiq8SHDbcT7PmMifHIX7x6SXSAHeJHiHSf9o1FQX6Zkf8YTEqIgthnI0ZukPJHYvejwW5rXCr5qkb7@cBVw6MdWaeWYV8rrD2Ccz6tFQ@zIkp9OEz5qlvqnL@aquk4r0UIJfHjUS2kd1Zs7ANEep@YxGXN3kDOYhfXEDn5DzhOJsMZNeyej9VPec0@inJ/osYo@TM4OrnMEdtkt7pzbaFj0nMPKMQ/qKNqmLlb45qE2FLop6oHZypqbKexUfQjnrM/lJ4E82nbvB@rvwXQY5jtEryWP4AU6RnN9bC/PIsZaJZ8EP5VU3vg/sqem5VFXOo7H9@SpxPvXY@8nIe6K/E2rxow6uSV9i2UM7Xd2kHlz7SiVip9G7TGpiTTiZpudqdTlffZaaQ623TORna/1yzIXLT1EMcyLfdMzEXU24WlEX07hmwH6B0dVKvl035nabnh9byFOL3q0eQ42xjwl7Yc244jLadxL8g5KYx1niswLMR@tnB3NVwHmjR5L0XMF5muFT4syQzPwo@BFDatmQN0M9L85Sjj7fJv3T9bwu8H1wTkRj/UCcJyn8D/AllS/Q2l4@g3c20x/vGpu67ahp34Otm2Bim41Zz/Uz5c1l9ugJPpbs4/C39aylRo6L9vuBfEfPwomcZaxZyvszq3GGWpNaEJzZrb0jxyzcucGealXq8av69ol5PD3XVvNZiGWgm2uXsxOEXwhfbrieyZX@RZWzMEqW/KTWL8tZ76jdgp@F@ByYYxeMOfjzokPAGwPG1oWbm4v4oxN5WcAEamPOGDzCOvY9YZvU6mG8/aQfENZ5SJ004pjgIyGnB2xq3Pt/)

Comment: Nice! What's surprising for me is that it uses the current item count – I wonder if than can be factored out. After all, it doesn't matter if there are 3 items weighting 120 each or 3 items weighting 160 each.

Comment: @Angs probably it is possible. Current item count came out as a simple shortcut for idea "Hey, sometimes its possible to do 5 item bag" and I tunelled on getting 5 item bags working. With free time improvements will come :)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>9855</s> <s>9928</s> <s>9947</s> <s>9956</s> 9964 bags

Based on Jonathan Allan's starter code, but ungolfed to be readable.

Idea: Since 1000/170 = 5.88, we try to select fruits close to 1000/6 (I fiddled with the magic constants). However, if the last fruit in the bag can minimize waste, we use that instead.

This solution has bag sum targets for each fruit added. I'll probably stop here. I used Nelder-Mead to find my `targets` array:

```
[  165.79534144   343.58443287   522.58081597   680.76516204   845.93431713 1063.17204861]
```

```python
def f(a, m, l, targets):
    bags = []
    bag = []
    bag_sum = 0
    while a:
        buffer = a[:l]
        finishers = tuple(filter(lambda w: bag_sum + w >= m, buffer))
        if finishers:
            next_fruits = [min(finishers)]

        else:
            ind = len(bag)
            next_fruits = [min(buffer, key=lambda w: abs(targets[ind]-bag_sum-w))]

        for next_fruit in next_fruits:
            bag.append(a.pop(a.index(next_fruit)))
            bag_sum += bag[-1]

        if sum(bag) >= m:
            bags.append(bag)
            bag = []  # Reset bag
            bag_sum = 0

    return bags
```

---

**9956 bags**

```python
from itertools import combinations

def f(a,m,l):
    bags = []
    bag = []
    while a:
        buffer = a[:l]
        next_fruit = None
        single_fruit = True

        finishers = [w for w in buffer if sum(bag) + w >= m ]
        if finishers: next_fruit = min(finishers)

        if not next_fruit:
            if len(buffer) >= 4 and sum(bag) < 600:
                next_fruits = min(combinations(buffer, 2), key=
                                  lambda ws: abs(2*169-sum(ws)))
                for fruit in next_fruits:
                    bag.append(a.pop(a.index(fruit)))

                single_fruit = False  # Skip adding single fruit

            else:
                next_fruit = min(buffer, key=lambda w: abs(171.5-w))

        if single_fruit:
            bag.append(a.pop(a.index(next_fruit)))

        if sum(bag)>=m:
            bags.append(bag)
            bag = []

    return bags


oranges = [int(x.strip()) for x in open("fruit.txt").readlines()]
bagLists = []
for lookahead in (2,3,4,5,6,7):
    bagLists.append(f(oranges[:], 1000, lookahead))


totalBagsOver1000 = sum(map(len, bagLists))
print('bags: ', (totalBagsOver1000))
```

---

The **9947 bags** program is particularly simple:

```python
def f(a,m,l):
    bags = []
    bag = []
    while a:
        buffer = a[:l]
        next_fruit = None

        finishers = [w for w in buffer if sum(bag) + w >= m ]
        if finishers: next_fruit = min(finishers)

        if not next_fruit:
            next_fruit = min(buffer, key=lambda w: abs(171.5-w))

        bag.append(a.pop(a.index(next_fruit)))

        if sum(bag)>=m:
            bags.append(bag)
            bag = []

    return bags
```

Comment: Good! Btw, just picking the last item so as to minimize waste is quite powerful by itself and gives 9862 bags.

Comment: How did you come up with those `targets`? Training on random data?

Comment: @Alex I stated so: Nelder-Mead method (with negative bags as loss function)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 9967 bags

```ruby
def pick a, n
  if a.sum < n
    #return a.max
    d = n % 170
    return a.min_by{|w|
      [(w - d).abs, (w - d - 170).abs].min
    }
  end
  
  subsets = (0..a.length).map do |i|
    a.combination(i).to_a
  end.flatten(1)
  
  subsets.select!{|s|s.sum >= n}
  least_overkill = subsets.min_by{|s|s.sum}
  #puts "best: #{least_overkill.sort}"
  return least_overkill.min
end

def run list, weight, n
  bags = 0
  in_bag = 0
  while list.size > 0
    x = pick(list[0...n], weight - in_bag)
    i = list.index(x)
    raise new Exeption("not a valid weight") if(!i || i >= n)
    list.delete_at i
    in_bag += x
    if in_bag >= weight
      #puts in_bag
      in_bag = 0
      bags += 1
    end
  end
  return bags
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVJhb@IwDP3Or/BAJ7W6LGq4Qdlp27f7FQihlBqIVlLUpGt3dL@ds5NyJ65q0/jZfo5f3LTF5/Va4h7OZvcOWoCdAJg9aOnaE7wEE2DWoG8bS@hJ9wEp4RUsfAOVZ8H@F2Dstvi8DN0QcIB10sEjlKnUhRMQDfooMUAbzgihX7SiLWml17WFQ@@oSpJJqWWF9uCPKdU/Q1nDYCK9lrv6VBirvaltYlLp662OPHJfae/RJiq9o5QOK9z5h8vgBhe6fKNWuHiF2vlt/YHNu6kqKn3LuPU0JnDs7NzS6aYFOv8TZpf7VOnqxn9NJ39l@c/NHXOnExa@aclvnBfQoTkcfbyCQh@4eRaXi@vDaHRHU2GIl878RniDqH9Pfr7ChF1rkkzazY2R1I4caQg1FBoIjC2xT/qINto4BIsd/OrxHOSc2tqDhg9dmXKkmqY0HMmDgWEgHhYuZge@koT1uNUeTCwUD/79FeLM0FiNECVGvnFGoprROUJ3XfMTFCEuFew4KHEdReYAlvVaaq8pca1yJdTyh1D5XKjnpVAL@vIFYWTnbNN@RfvVs1BP9F9yfEb4fIx5GnMJXy02k0k4Jl8YlxCgsiwTML/@AQ)

If you have enough weight to fill the bag, find the lightest subset that can fill the bag and use the lightest orange of that subset. Otherwise, get the remaining weight as close as possible to a multiple of 170.

Answer (score 2):

## Racket/Scheme, 9880 bags

To decide which piece of fruit to add to the bag, compare the optimal bag weight to the weight of the bag with the additional piece of fruit. If it's the optimal weight, use it. If it's overweight, minimize the excess amount.
If it's underweight, minimize the excess amount after trying to leave an optimal gap.

```
;; types

(define-struct bagger (fruit look tray bag bags)) ; fruit bagger

;; constants

(define MBW 1000) ; minimum bag weight
(define AFW 170) ; average piece-of-fruit weight
(define GAP (- MBW AFW)) ; targeted gap
(define FRUIT (file->list "fruit-supply.txt")) ; supplied fruit

;; utility functions

(define (weigh-it ls)
  (if (empty? ls)
      0
      (+ (car ls) (weigh-it (cdr ls)))))

(define (ref-to-car ls ref)
  (if (zero? ref)
      ls
      (let ((elem (list-ref ls ref)))
        (cons elem (remove elem ls)))))

;; predicates

(define (bag-empty? bgr) (empty? (bagger-bag bgr)))
(define (bag-full? bgr) (>= (weigh-it (bagger-bag bgr)) MBW))
(define (fruit-empty? bgr) (empty? (bagger-fruit bgr)))
(define (tray-empty? bgr) (empty? (bagger-tray bgr)))
(define (tray-full? bgr) (= (length (bagger-tray bgr)) (bagger-look bgr)))
(define (target-not-set? target value) (and (empty? target) (empty? value)))

;; pick best piece of fruit

(define (pf-rec tray bag i target value diff)
  (if (or (target-not-set? target value) (< diff value))
      (pick-fruit (cdr tray) bag (add1 i) i diff)
      (pick-fruit (cdr tray) bag (add1 i) target value)))

(define (pick-fruit tray bag i target value)
  (if (empty? tray)
      target
      (let ((weight (weigh-it (cons (car tray) bag))))
        (cond
          ((= weight MBW) i)
          ((> weight MBW) (pf-rec tray bag i target value (- weight MBW)))
          ((< weight MBW)
           (if (> weight GAP)
               (pf-rec tray bag i target value (- weight GAP))
               (pf-rec tray bag i target value (modulo (- MBW weight) AFW))))))))

;; load tray, bag, bags, etc.

(define (load-bag bgr)
  (let* ((tray (bagger-tray bgr))
         (bag (bagger-bag bgr))
         (weight (+ (weigh-it tray) (weigh-it bag))))
    (if (= weight MBW)
        (struct-copy bagger bgr
                     (tray empty)
                     (bag (append tray bag)))
        (let ((new-tray (ref-to-car tray (pick-fruit tray bag 0 empty empty))))
          (struct-copy bagger bgr
                       (tray (cdr new-tray))
                       (bag (cons (car new-tray) bag)))))))

(define (load-bags bgr)
  (struct-copy bagger bgr
               (bag empty)
               (bags (cons (bagger-bag bgr) (bagger-bags bgr)))))

(define (load-tray bgr)
  (struct-copy bagger bgr
               (fruit (cdr (bagger-fruit bgr)))
               (tray (cons (car (bagger-fruit bgr)) (bagger-tray bgr)))))

;; run the bagger factory

(define (run-bagger-aux bgr)
  (cond
    ((bag-full? bgr) (run-bagger-aux (load-bags bgr)))
    ((bag-empty? bgr)
     (cond
       ((tray-full? bgr) (run-bagger-aux (load-bag bgr)))
       ((tray-empty? bgr)
        (if (fruit-empty? bgr)
            (length (bagger-bags bgr))
            (run-bagger-aux (load-tray bgr))))
       (else
        (if (fruit-empty? bgr)
            (run-bagger-aux (load-bag bgr))
            (run-bagger-aux (load-tray bgr))))))
    (else
     (cond
       ((tray-full? bgr) (run-bagger-aux (load-bag bgr)))
       ((tray-empty? bgr)
        (if (fruit-empty? bgr)
            (run-bagger-aux (load-bags bgr))
            (run-bagger-aux (load-tray bgr))))
       (else
        (if (fruit-empty? bgr)
            (run-bagger-aux (load-bag bgr))
            (run-bagger-aux (load-tray bgr))))))))

(define (run-bagger fruit look)
  (run-bagger-aux (make-bagger fruit look empty empty empty)))

;; stackexchange problem run

(define (run-problem fruit looks)
  (if (empty? looks)
      0
      (+ (run-bagger fruit (car looks)) (run-problem fruit (cdr looks)))))

(run-problem FRUIT '(2 3 4 5 6 7)) ; result = 9880
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 9777 bags

This was my first attempt:

- it greedily filled a bag with a batch when it could,
- or flushed all oranges into the bag when it could not.

```hs
options[]=[(0,([],[]))]
options(first:rest)=[option|(sum,(now,later))<-options rest,
 option<-[(sum+first,(first:now,later)),(sum,(now,first:later))]]
bags _[_]_=[]
bags(w_sum,w_bag)(w_kilo:w_iyts)w_view=
 let(w_take,w_remd)=splitAt(w_view)w_iyts;
     w_fill=filter((>=(w_kilo-w_sum)).fst)(options w_take)
 in if null w_fill then bags(w_sum+sum w_take,w_bag++w_take)(w_kilo:w_remd)w_view
    else let(_,(w_now,w_later))=minimum w_fill in
         (w_bag++w_now):bags(0,[])(w_kilo:w_later++w_remd)w_view
main=print.sum$map(length.bags(0,[])(1000:batch))[2..7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bX3bjh1HkuS7voIP@0Ci2UJmRHiEe89wgf0OQiC0O@xpoil2Q@KMsMD@u7Yy0s3NsmYEUGTVuWRmXPxibm7xt59/@/vnr1//@OMf//z@5R/ffvv404ePb4/3bz/@9P7jT@/e/fRD/v7tX7/8@tv3v/z6@bfv7z58vH/5/97@9h@/vH/77R@/v//68/fPv757969/zre/ud74/oc394//@ueP11v/tL/jfX6VfOw9v@h@LX//008//O@f//23N58@fvrp04eP909vf/90vfv3Ty8/vHv54e9fvv7jL79/@vJ/v//27vdP//nl8@8ffnjz9fP3l5e@//z3zy9v/PXzL//27sNv//z65fv/un59vefd/Yl/@eHN9d/vn/765evXDy//e7nu27f/80N@75/3td69@/GvL4/9Fs92f/G7H958@fbmy1/ffPuPr1/zG958/9vnb294l396@fOm7uPl93/6U36YN77v7r6pfTOfv/72ed//p/cvb7rG5PdPOR4ffvny7csv@yv31b58u2//@u9tff/LR979Zd/Dcc0hr7S/5XqHXvKXn798@/DPX798@/7jy83@j19@/ufbr5@//fv3v/0oX3Eex/Hyld//z9/evfvYfvxx/fTH/unDx3Me79txvD9tvvw5359zvD/9@rvdPy97@fnl9fXyx19@t15en/Hy5@X3c92fu163/vLzy594@eMvr62X19bLv7vfr8/z/sy6vjd/tpfXer/fOzx/n997ve@6D3u5Vl/3/azrWuP@/v35656uz@f9LrznuueX71tx/41nMbs/f13v@vf1rJb3tPLf13v3fc68p3ZfY4@B8/fX9aPxO677vJ5/zHus9nuP@3eeY7jHauVnRt5z3OOEcR55P9c1rucakWOe99vbPT7XPe17bfd84B6v913zZDmu@x7y7@u75/VM62XOJ69/fT5yXDzH@hqnnuO/P2M51rj/nL9x3K9f44Fx9Pz3vpfzfo7rGUd7ue41VzIW1@8N95DzuJ/P7zFZWDtHzqPneK2ck5Fzir/bvQavP9f7POd9HRyLOTnu@97Xff2FP/m@a@6v@dtjOe/nt5yPa4x93r/f8yP7Ijz3SsvnaPcavt6PtW15nZ73c62R0fbc3Nd9@b64frfy@4/7tevfI@coMN95/X3v8157ewzP@7W9J0fe77W2@v36/u4zxwP7B3vdOL7X69c47DleMgZL1iDueeUcWa5pu9e6531da/B6vmtdX69F/n7v0@N@7Rq/yGvv@1v39ffPU/aU5ZjH/bl9Xys/23IPxn2N63qW93/9znLNXvdm@XPZhOD79nN5rifL9RByf/1et3s9pP0w2XPh3K/Xve/3zhyPg69dYzkmx9FyPPbYH/e1L3tzfb5b2luxo9dc73VxPO3jyv257YWlnXfO98vv7j2Jte65N7GGc93v1yZt@LYDJnsJ@xZ2c97juec7/cTKz2@7ibV05No9aCci94Tdtqr8y35Pjv81byv3x74v596LtL@wsyttlzfal@s7PPfunqeetv6kHV33HG//6DnXe93n@oCvuPYTnvn6jOW6vN53rbttvy5fGLz@hM1IH7tyvvcYzbRdXXwYfETazIXnmfz@ff30s45nzvUWsIt5/WuMtr9Jm1prHv6053enXZnGMV15XzP317bfi3bYDvrvmc/sOR7YY9e/J/b3kbYsZJ0Mzvv1/AHb79w7cdvIdgRt5N53dn@v5Trac5F2BDYSNg@2bdvpRfu/fUbazT1HI58X35Mxyx6nSFvoXMMz97TlXvYcA8vvK9u5GJdY2pTti537y3JslnFfXM9z7ZPrfQZ/BDuE6@M5cw69MQ7DNcp/wZ@cOT7wV01iwkG/MtNu7/nuXF81Bmlzth1Ln73vfYjvnRkvYc@te4wCeyx9xXUfPeO@lXvEEN9d8Ws@L9ZqF/vuM20cYpecux1b@e0TPO97wJfkOEZnXLP/PnLcERvnfVvaQ8@4ccJnpS3acc3J902nLXLs1/SNfoqtgg1HPCr3DVu4YGsQC@R8emdM4um3RvpkrB/EKIHYNejTHHH8uMdzpD3Z857PGjkm228j/sPaG/RnK/0N/NDLs97zgXuRtTryuWbut5k@bAXtGHxB2aeZ3xUZS8H@iB9YGSPvz7qs4bjtRJiMafquNRmzzfQ1e75HxhuTdhL@KxpzHORKK/cS7qFs/klfVeMj@36/D7Z33X5mpZ333EMjbQzmxhBHLMbl@x6cdsqwLnI8PfcZ7MvKuH@d/O593ZV7Hes7fYgHfdZMH2/5HEtixpm2d8dEOXaIN1euJcT8djL2X5mblC9pz3gsYIvTplpIDtVyrpCLjLyuc7xmxtUL8cJ536PBVyCWyFjFJF4eg/exMNadf1vG4Cb7xnJfudNXIp9xjAHW0UwbqOsKtuTMNZh@exrXx5J8zpGTdd6753wiJyjfijwq1wpySBtiP0/GQHsu8n0@ON9YAwP@PL9jpm3ZtgzjmOsbPrjso@ZdGcci/l/zmash1tg2Otc61m/FSMZcKyZjfp@MsXANW4xNPH3Dy2fagTgX9s@Zs7nEtbDvhpgOuX7ejyFmM4lLc19vbOGU58p99/J6O8967nbCbmTeiPgHseJs3J8@OM7bfpyyTxNfCM3DQ2Kgkz5hr7GgfUDMVzFj@lxLDGE0@myMw441Gm0q8uyRMR/W7MzYYefBiLHy3mMQ90Gs5Xm/K@P1yD1W8ULGgmNKvN0YX3muf0Mc3MSmYZ@kr7Yu/tCYSyJHQHwwXbCQe31t7AXxs2N9IlZFHIqxCfrImXtwZeyGGNJyj/riGqtcsDEmBUbisFsZt698HkPMLbYa82eD4zNHrcc7P8p17/DpRluM@NMHY@GV8eCO6yW/B37mzn2L2AD@/fozErvwyeca6TuBP1nak5H7FXN/2SpglMAO4PMQu1U81@iTaq6n4FzwEWlLK15HPIDnyr04sJ/PxGCQg@TYjGDsbLlXr31yxUQDti3ow2YQ60OMUHGKC67ngpHlWpydvs7zmrWfT/q5mf/GnBl8uhGfRBx2rT/EumV7074Gcrv0eZ723JxY28o4LHK/@SBuaoK9zMG1orgX4tuVefdC3it5CvaYJU6F/Ydxrxw9iDX6Kdhhu@9xdonxJt@/42oTu3HIGLeMv5wYBnCFnrbOM1dBDoCYEX4SuK5nvGidPndjJ5Mx855nk3x3EB@YaecKO4R/zjkw2evwrfDliL2B8Q3ntSq2BfZ95DwJFlf5XmLY1xodg9eEPYvMk3M/33neuvdD5HWAswFD7MH1hzhlDo5f4RiWONMdX7cT8QUwV@CqS/Be5EsH7Qzw3D1uwLMQFxtz38D6y@eBrUFOAmx9NOKbyJcsfbEh9re8xik4lOB72DeIaX1JHQdxRbvnwrOGEv2ZR2KtuMS2GD/sa@xfc6kR5RpA3le2ySqP2zFM5D1GCLaCPHNVbn@voyZYKPLYtKEruObmlBrBEuzulJgl/QlymXUwv8e6g42JLpjYIN6xgOUAPxCfDbz4mocwYi@FcyIu9XvNA3OJQYwBOfVqkpfmmgnBpCtPHMT1ZvqilblfOxgHwDd5Z04IHHGIz962JwT/FxtoUbnZHlvkt8DQDGsG@Py634exG/CTwX2LuHUsYsnu9EnwpX4wl67alUvs44wNPTEtz/FBzQl4PdZ@5eTiYxCLYS@EjFliDPezD2IzlrbOgOcj1htPbBw5@ThZH0Oej71qxr28sazEZmajPcR@8RCMI23n/n5jjD5PySsTc7P07w3rGvYZ6wf2PbE9n5Jf5rx1xKeoW6VdwTgPk5ixCc49E3/O/CRyHUdimtaY51unf7qu1@HXs34YjbiYnVKf9rT9iM2Nez8WnxHYLGqBO7501pdqLA7xH43xF@q/blxL8G3A7lHrs2B@uLKWE4I7A4vwyXVRPiLrJobvXPThlvH8Ho/c0yMkhoMtRx0n96gvyVfTproTDy3f1mXvZ2xu2FPOeKlsV0gMArzMmKMidl6S23qOB9YYar7A8co2DtpCg73y9CPwfc44Y520KY/6e2P@uzFkqZugror4bbhgC41rucbJOR5T8NM5iEfZYNy5Dq4r8BlG57x7zp8556Q@Z4zPI/ft3s8huImJDRnkSMCeos43Zo3zzuEqRojM6TInVzy26knAaRWbGowZp5ETUnZ8cHxm8D6mxBqo26DGDKxzDsnD1afK2jDgVU5/NXIMFmrL2C@d@KSPZy0De7OwslNqP8CGg7nYCObN4Gqg/oC8DDyLgbWxmANXDhqM59Ver0NwPhNf5DlXJ31M2qg7hzgZ@@9c0Bn7l3/LevdstPWIWbXWhtj0WjPRWSNCDLFm7qEQHGOwjjeRD4vP3TEEbLCxLhqDvmvl9227jNoVsMv0kTOIg41gHtMxtrnXBrAD1OkFvw/EY8J3wvWBSQHPKfsOjLXTxtdcJ45QtdnF2tdIe4GcZTlrgcXZyVwLeIel3QYPCra4MPvGGl/Fuk2w4TNrvYiRB/1eOLFxcB5GECNEfIAYZ6@dJhwLq7hqxzvAAoBtVI1RajRYG8DlVhBnrJqg0@bsOFJ8O3K4iglRs7DbLkTaB8TXhfF3yc0Gx77yOWOcasoVAlYoGEeIbYMv3DFUsEa/49qMkWovtif@WDXffu8HD/GTjXsH@C1qLMp9c@CAqNd24tMrczXUhTCutTeB76Z9Kpz9YE4D3ACY0JrPmtE4iYvX2s33YP9i7SI/xM/LaTtXCHYt97/SDwMHXlIXgk20XMvY16M9eTmhdSThBiLu85B66SB2vlbFt9uuIk9YEiMg/l0mPCXZV8UxE/zUMw@sMeoy5siznGt2NtYLVsZTVcfssicH@Yjg8pndeXdTf5j3G8DYcm2g7rNt/cj1jFy@id2dEkOb1F6d6wx2GuMIXqRLbAg80oHxh3DohMMTS/AS4QEAB0Hsitcqv8p1MNJuxME6aXFGT@JKqPt7434r/gb8@SQ/B/gv9hBiNcxDHMK5Cu4n3PsMwX4nOTCFozlz2pE5kOd9mskezTxN@Y6rSU0SnNGTOf2UuBPvtVMwg4MxOTDHuciBXYJPzIMxMdbQPDnnlY8O7qERrK8XTyT9U9Vax6ta2RJ8NGtlowuG38lVwfqG/Z/O@qEtyUsQ76DOsDhWBo5E8hjNadO8yTOA@7aEcyd5dWFMQQ4csKnI9bDz4sk4Ixp9wTL6ba0bpz9qZ5c4SuOiM/duEDvxQ3ArxA5YS8p56pwbcI79YJw3Mh7T2uc4iVUiTgUWM4b4CMnxMJ7g@1X@JTG4D8EmJc4oPuqQ3FnsEmLv6axroa4ATlLh901wO5mb1WnnH3Vq4Sxsu2XM2V1i@uKtu9jukHjI@f7ehdcawoULyXuMPgz11aqnHORKVLwgdVrwspIn1M5gjof6ouYMC9d31m0qFka94CQ3quKoKfag0U6DEwbbAEy3avjCZ4YtBw5sQX7PtkPjHi9gTsB4YXvCWQta4Bdpjp41hr5oE1x6HzRvMKm3gi/pp3CXl2DEyCWHcDsa7XRgbR2sgWFdoqbmxvEBdr8arwV@FHjviPl9kGc5k9cKrGpmjcIX@aI26V8sY0DsuZrn3Puo64yQOFFqTogLzbiGKi9NXg/8eXG0mnCVDomBOrniM20MMLSJuhMwImPNHfE6uC0aG8OH22K9oyd@Dm5dnMSGq//gJB6B/L/y3yBfwfO6nvUj78xHV@6D5DtUrL9zp6CfHuIvTXCPSBsUp8SX8BFT@iGcnBcz3hPySmBRVa9DTUvyeexxS19sktd2l3z2kLXlHBfUjUNqttd66uj7OCRfhS/LPTeEd7XiyVlCHRy2zbCfhAeFPL56ICbHpepNTfDBLhynHPNorG@ixuhGvBY5A3KxKXVNcO0wdrq3waGaBzmPiOuRT3tjL9JwwYHAe@jkKmFtIy4Y8CMZ0yRHmtyGePJZtbZkB/n3ldujHrKEm6L9OSE11vyuqsGGYEmNOZsJ3wV2P5LrWpxm4QvsvZ6cGpd@meJ9gD/a6Y9R3wBnF3X4HS@NZ28CbBZwfzvJz1rtWT@3XEOu9c/B50OuCVxoTNYMH/yLJq856@moA5cPTHsdWbdAbRE1geIqHOQDgN/li7mNneQ7WkhMv545SdXJ/V5r2L@7BqU190aeEPb7muyLKj6VE18N6UcBLqJ8UXBuwT0D13g4632ok44g56B4vSe5WWUzDj5b4Xqd3Jol/Bz4kXkSvwQmVfzZ/A7goOCPlI9BXt@4R4pLmPF39VqMjJ8nubzFeRvCoR3CM22Cv2csgBxhDPHPUveLrA/B5oAbh1xoSvw9hPu4UCdx1hjBVVNurPkzhwz2eLbTWJubJpxT4HNN6ouI3w/WddFviPwV66dwVn/FARjkK4CviB6LZcQJdywieeE4heMKfD3HEXH3cnL2YOv8/p6NC8VkzbD80kjfJL0W2B/abwmOQYePahI7iX2Yh6xHzL2sb/RsoQegcqODPZRLcoOVOMeYT56h1iSqRp97vrg3TfpCJ33GOKWmfDJ/Qm4CPCxOxrDFF5msi1mTumknp8ovHM6zlpJ1phDOdQ/2wYDPD24cYoxYjCPBbRxLeNeS4287mBjnEqyuOBJGnBL@HzVv8EWLE9bITQbHWWuF@Blz7lLzHoqnZOwCvlDxXk/yCV3GB3sT8Tz2Xe2dIXkk@KEnsX2MIXINn6zl1FqKuzcRNsaG8PSDe6bsXLD3HHVg7GHkfpV7hPTkBfkn6DEFrwQ236WvApz2aILpZ823@hiXYIngnQrPCfF91TSH5HZT6mHgkfhzfHDvmXvf9dVG24MeiZHYKvIjrDXg4sV5PSVfF98WRp79TO4oeBTAjV17zrvkVNp/OCVWXcwXav1Iv0dz8iMQcwFHRw1goabhxXXY@U/xH7pw2Q/GrIi/RuYO6bs5d1Py1PGsg1Ydbcj6GuLvpnDymuRoJveTPtuX5K/gGapWgvSQg0/nd73@rq1nPLdrZE16uAX/DqwbaAw4cRfw8rHHq78x@Fzg24MnVzFCJx93SL1qQbcBug9i34tXfgpnrJH/s78rbRX4O97IwS4uwEmeKfj04GsVP7xxr7lw870zVl/Cc570u8WNLX7RwdoGYtiKMSfXYNWEpvBhB3NKb@xhXIoHnMRrRsbUYs9YDxTurX4e/KzdO9Skv8ikB8WEE5mcnurLAA6ZNjWkvlX4@SkcQSeGWbWsVzwAzXOAaeVzbhuLuB0YJfqzFfdUfj/6P5B7zOQOFM/OWStBf9oQu4S8BTnbFE0NxIJDYvsh@f3Djw3B/Jusv0WeqEm9ANfS3tfidMIH9mdNBnYH8Wrx1NGfkTFnP4QL0GlTlrGObEF9DHCo5hBuprGfreL848k7MulNBw4OjMXID7lrIvPJacDe1hi8uBY5huGCAyZuCr@CGob2PcAH2yHr92T/VOQzoSfQkhsZxh555MgG/COkXtyl/6UxFw3JJVHPKJy9yTVMfH7GhdWr1wRHPNi3469rfou9FOD5whfEQX5D5WMna4jIMV1699GvXrULYHqLfeKINapfJHHw6nk4mFOmf705q9B2yJpZ2cQmeULmGZUj5jUtdQOw/laQRwfOPeIo1AiLH6A9koM9LoUfHOzhL/0VcPCDei7Fn3XpgUpedAhfOoRTv5z17CE@CDgI6vCIq0bmX21Jv3Njbln426L2DvSDELNoL9B8VfudB3EccC8KTxZ/N429ceh/Kv2VJnGp6A1V72IQ7@oh8WNjD99M3wI@CPKBYU9dItShVEtj@BMzqZ5@0TBCPIE5XKn/g3zHpe9uCBcilmgZGPc0@PaF6zjXVBh5w4gZVA8DPO6qzU7pS5C5BFfcg3ZpHeTzgSNniY1N0SW55rsLf7fih5B6Jmr3qQ2j/q04ecG8BNx87OfkvrRj0XaiPgbuhPaJLdGIWhKfIbddqk1lYre7YJDGnkas@8qDzqdWDerKU2rznrUwcO@Qy2pOBS4HfPLo5MYhF3fBtcCFx/UrHj6FT5KxKTREqj6K9Sa9p9BRQv@Rw9cK/gO/UPy2Q7Da/uxZXoLNxCIfrjBOyV2RwxnWhNEWAIsvLnpjLQT5SGn7HOR1VO9KPLm3mOeqkUkP7VKMwoinI39DrFJckSZYe5AvY8G65RSbFMJ/6Mk/D9TeRY9kAse9fXU7pEdacVZwkcYiLox@X8QoBk6GU9eg9NMOxt3V89@lx135550YGjj2VefLtbhrhy6182BuXVpKTTTuJO@C3pdLbR04WNVoTolfJznMyLXR9@yNOSNwgPI17DdtLestU3qKq6dT4h/UdxGjlC2a9MOW9cypvffGn82phYa1WjzmVz3dGCMX/QiXXNGcuSv2S4/nuo721EdC3ot6SvV/ggOC3hr0uQ7mjKUHInYFNjEO1uJG2tY@qImA3GhJX6kHtbSGcOrHq1wC@jfAc1AvKYxL6jUu/amwmcupi6H11EhswKRGVP3bh2iode6hdTAeL32tLlqGYluL@9YlFsrcCHoIlUcZfTG04sC3rFq@E@epOv8gnoaYvvhq0ncOLq5nrKsaXXbQzpemoPRlIP9GXDGkLgxNM5ceD8S7mBcTXREPwWOG9CFOPidqWCY6i6ORT4kei9lEKzF7NYboAAHfma84QS78fOvU3IJ/ht0G58VvX3zbX@iXBdcE6oKlDbfYv1a8EHtVn3HqS@y@9iW9DZPjWzoTyBsP4s@P2oRJH3NLzv8iZ776GDqvX2tFe1raU@8O/e3FJ/TybaUHN5fEa1LXBMYS0usADUTUbIu/fxDzKz2aTv0M4EtLaxrJYwnwM5zYpwu/qmKExucc6VvQw4delCncHXw2lvD9zqfNK72xJdw1l76W@bT9K@uT3sR/HsKv0fEI6fUdrO@WRq2xf/jR/58YIfJT1LVmaiYiHgZX7eHnFYcUniz67Gb2rlevtehkTInxi5s9xQ5jn2Q/aGj/zhINKZd@84MaP5UXT@4f2D6NJVziYug3Yg@A79XBW801Phr5C3ayX1/1VStGmqxjoMd9yvpeoucHrAs9CNUP1Okj0O/j6CXNWCSkh7r6dqdo962nhgXwPfT1GbVjdr5ZfWFL/NZiHXYKzgMOOfJH4ItTuBa7/3dwr@paWp11rDbI6XfRc1JNU9QawEWEHUYfNmqS/aA@WGFyjT5o5Rx1F77kSW6mSS3ABfuaoqPyWltqSq4BXkP1pjTqHld/UNCugdOxpD90Sk9N6RyljYefX8cTA0YPwFrU1xkhfIEh3B7R63n0HnXiusCswP1wqWWi7z11OKo2sKR@srR3pZPXHYuaIOg9KZ0e1WGdzxph9egd5FlUf@BBP2XQODokBm/cO9D@GOB3TNFjuPHAjRlM7auHXoTwJ7UOCG5x1UygQbDIJZvCIS/8Qvsm5xPHhZ8a0m9fvKGTuApqdg6cXeoGU3x01RtM/O1BjgewlMd35rh5iBbc@eTxw5ei/rs5wLnfQrAZ7B3kz2NKz7ro0yH3NOkZ2rnCIr9U9SmK69uJRVV/cDy5RqizVc1uiW1d7GsayGnOpy0F795E1wr9zMPkM/jdon4XsNUJDvGUenITjr0T5yqe6nzmpWOxh8ykBwFxXvUkNmJG2l8KjBz9K@jpgsbJ0j68eNUL1ySWHeRqgnODnkHU6EzqhqVn1ulPTOxb6fghhjnYIwYdvur3Ez2r5GTfdfIbf7t5RutVfiU2F3lH9ZUZY2DYYtjU0kyU/tEuGj8mWqjo3YxT@LNBDQboFbj0WEN7ABzNJXuwOIqT3NjSnjyp34/9HKIbeN1LX2KLTepb6HVdxDxV11DxGNhx6HZAnwv9nbDXLj0QS7TJkKMswc6hsVi1VxPO6CHcMsGrEE9WvdOJKwc0FLP/N@OgnZMBv5qCgQ4n53uohsuNBTz4NlWnmsQ2wVutHiLRq1CeZHGOiBu2JhoLdrzSoT2kHgw988F@U@Qys935rMHmD@FjBjVxwK8o/6C1f8x/Fz3m1AJaooOFOlXpRjf2Y@39cZATh@sWdzAYyxTHHj6sU6sLcdxMXnQ412f1enfGGNUDPehP4D9K/0J4nLBTMRgvxJA@yIMxGvJy9MogzkL@WRyMxjijeOXKtREdOPBMStM9894pYxwnew0L13uVj0O7RrWqbD5xV/RJmPSkIzYpzaeTdmGI7pIN6W/ropfjcp6JSW9kJ0dee@kQx0@tMZloe0qf5KMHdfHzLlzssoGJ4WhvEu5t1247OQ7Ay4pvFsS@kKNWX5LUjF35XU69tcKNXXDU46knO6Wnqni/nfVkaCsiL0vbse2UHeyfRU2ocLohmvYhmO2S@MCoD1f77ZTYWvXH0icBKzXY304M1UXT3NqrXOwUfWnRbAHXrmzzYH/jGE9cyw/aJMUnsUerH@AQTlNw/yuWiO/UHt/CK0P6dw/pk27U9incXHvznXFbTMGeQ/QtxA5Go/50xcMmPTKig7pe8WpLm/vg9@l5DbX/E8OHjubuyxJ7W3l/p6YVsKjiiKevD9EKjawZl85zavhaML4HPjHkPAof1NrS82b0OYHBexP7MkXjDPpdJ3mZqgXg7ZVe5xRcqYn@03j4WWrHdqlTtmdPXtVTT6kP2/NcliWc3NmIBWlOBtsNXURw8lzz3yiuI89UGLRNpV9xirZuCGeykyc9pVcFvqC0FxLrXqKTBa4G1lbxgzv7nAq7adJTJrmLiYaDJ69voI/EhO99MheI49W5HKIxP7WeIDq@U/Ju1bWFbUUuPqS@g/waa8@MWmbobys9rpBeBRNdT9E5n6LZgnNnpvjM0iqTfNaN/QGlCebEd8GFHaI3Vxx68DMm4@FIXx/k697cJDlfAJrK0HAvXXHRKYctHZI3wJct1TEz3nN@z63j4cTtIvGAS@P7bE8eEPjQuG@MdZ0FMoXfLPWMEC2k6OT8ot4I31HY7RS8wCWvd@nvXeTjxyk1juMZM1U/ou7JEK6JaAPpmWpa8yxs24iPLOEylV0RPkLFHFmLAVYXLvobp/Q7mNRanBiG@vCqTTZiP6ijAPcszm9nH37peHXiWVP0OZSbFYP118056Ow7Qa5RZyCk3yztGTnTR3vei@8RjFdEc@3ypzencDGeLj91CA/jZFxa62tKvNHlrC3BFNaUczmkj3RKH87jbB/1QyY9Oyd183wI71D4CZWvDuHpdal9GDUhp5y3UbqW0NsZjKfBl5zOc7Rw5g6wL5zZUvUp5UQN6Rk5pa55ktc4pc@k8GDpmZnJyUWf5xQ/5aJrVPmz8I@Re9bZLIsYv0/aXfiR7tSF3XY198PIseuqk5L7Izr7sGush@TZqRNogglWDHhQdx25xkPXR8@kONnT7NLvFxJzhXDfC7t0qbEpL130lNaQ88AmeZalzzeFsz14ztyUOq05e8MLH5PeU9XpqrWyhDcjOKbmTFWPDcFVT/ZlmMToU7SVS3MBeqIH@e@lPa08xymxkPKa17MXp/g/wb3d2pNXi376GDzzLr9/980hZnicXSNnc6otAde4@IvssbzxlMa8qc6hFE5Zl3oBdNWW@GnwpZZw6YEf4OzG4p8u1nxRsxlT9OdFW6P0AZz8BuR9xbU9i8NUvWTAqtFLW2cJnLQP4JEMaNAf4lO6xAJBzGQKPjOMdnJl7APNMeXVQgcROF/h0qIZnHyZW2dYuBCVK3vqewp@VPFo9r9UvRDnbRlzwDqDr2WMtmjXH3j6kDqW9FmWhpOJ7t1iHzNqIHUGknItwSs8hVPYWL/zYJ/tShwQZ4oBT0SvtuquhujqFq4jWlsm520W78jJ50c@0YXfVPsr12zFonJmF/S60LcDXmp9f8ZMiPGwFsCJAsYeUkce7YkDxJRz5uLJ5UQ@FAftZnPhIE7RSQGPoNGvKT8vgj3l1ZfjjCmgCeUZ80Rjvy54HVM0TWMKV6pJn/OknnWc0pt4SO9MY61igpc9WU/a8zJ5Rggwb9RgUMdwqRVDl7o4kcC2J3VmTM//kL5V7NMx5DxQcPicZybH8eznLvzNeT5j6dkPYoPo@S0/YdRFMtUVdznXwVg77Ev0evwZh5TmUNCPFW@myZlS0t8A/PuR73Vyg1c8udImPIwl5xMpl6JiRtHBQd6A7yg9uexHLb6x8L2X9l90OV/sIE5norVRWmNTtHuPp@5cnUXj1FWDJle9P/VwvT2517DxS87XQz@AC7fa5PxDnFVafUkuXLNDtJSHaOV10UI/ybHC@XLQ/cCesUEtN9XbKq5HozZXnYMEbceTmGBpagou4udTG2lJ/Q04k4l9dOdYla7ukHxlPTVHiud8vNJ9Ay9DtNv1PEKcxVt6iU4@UggmbP7U7IbNxbluITy2C6s/oSXTXp1l14V/25lrgUcJm4H6T9WCnGdZ1LlN0t9b8yHagaMTY8e5heV7wWPsz34v8OmrB@bk@UGFgR9yJrjylfWcT@mDddE8Cen7LC4q@PvCX56iaaW1hrLP0ksVTc63C@bwJjqj0IoEd7T0aAbrdkNt2OL5IoVXHmJfEEc0xqpdMBo8H/YNuDV1Xuagrjx8EPjEyMFM6g1r8IxGQ1@dcCGQhxUHRXu1TM4N1p7gIfwY1JsEs0Nv3BSeaF/kvCIGLW2AJfvvFM2vjDGL@y31nSlnPQHzx1nBxeMR7QPUZgawpMW9i7NWp3DGXWpM0D2oXodJ/QVD3yB8q4me4EkMCrnusCfnt3fuD/TdoJ@/nvuQ2Fj0kZZqZwqub6KTMhs5f8XfctFENNE7HU@@B2pJqIkXL@QUrvrBPtPCFo@H1shdM8GZjos9J668Wuk3gR@eotM6pO5WmB9yM@N81rm3UguqcTnl3A3lCBj9JLCqqdzKRU0@U3uxWGu1Jhor0E0U3W/VpkHMb0aOqsu5BKhJ1bk/Q3rMTc5m64U7V85RGtYmXLeVHNDJuR7SB1q19fQRFRsFe@9yXO6arIm20CFa0i790jnHfbKGNiZ7mB2Yv5yDMF/FTahpACsfyjcRjf/qmxV9R/RaVR@wk@eI/A69uKs9uTBTztDG2tYe3@JnGznPxrPP7z78LroPco5e4fDCbXTp/Shd/vOVXgDOWhKdG8R83YgrbJ7XFA1T0Z8Db9GkBwI1jtGTLyZ4Afrk@4193rwhwb@sc0/je2tupFe4arsh@aTLuYOL@7vsyfHkVGpvJmyJ@trCJlG/7nLeYROtkpPj/eBABOsCEXKWYci5L06twKX1u8WY5nH@wxJ9ysG8DPj1XA@@AzWg/fnz9hMSS4KPNBS7P8n/i4NjVJqGesal1DiqXuY8xxWctuJzd/Fzqtun9x7Ps8d8PmOT4spAd1rsR@kfaWzvchZcxo3RqL9avWV6Lp@egTZYb5krOcxTYpSD@aIrFw16Iy7ct0P6a44nlrTkvEA9awXrr86971I3zr5U6GbrWb8GvYJD@pTlnBGtxUL7f6rmUO7xITlYaY2LdrCeWVx8oS44t7MnX3ule56NgnWEc1lMz4Lt1JsyWTvFe59yBmZn/0jhCjijz@QshpO6yuWLXbioJ/cl4rHSnzDhTx/Cqe@C0@ecdZNeLrWDcg6wKT8zpEYxpD4htS5P3Vv0O5V/kprTEF1TkzPpqj8R/RyoRy45T7DJ2bkn@8umcE5Qi0TMAx0IrHnUSKDZMLX/dkrsDi6dnMkTyvsQDeHiNQvGC75RcVWlprsWNWlMzghfS85jyzX4uNdGvij4YRVzHZynKZoEdfZY43OW7lZn3wQ@6/bk16OeUDahMz6v/uDGXmbUeyzxmmFy7v0pZ9tO1tTg/5f06cDWTmKkO94YgusMiTld9c3nf9PDLnX4Gs@T@fFD16gJT0DyzyX7YeOtkveXTjfmNtdHW6xDlg4/dIFEs9PlPBO1hTVOWTfqqSWHmOFx7qbk0LB5/SB@UXqkwomax1MTGL2t4M2b6nK@1skPnjdher5tchG1v83kbAFwspQ7VuvzoP5H6WyFcDzQEzyokxTCXSh875CcPoQTdkrd85B@XKe/QD@Xv8bXupxt0YmhQke3zh0b5LWa9CECa6vzo07RwDiefZKlg90YnxXP4uR8IE5Z9uxpMTlLp3K@JueLZf6IeBG8c3AVlCuN2nlp3oTo/ppo7Q7hygTPBNQzrOsMFI37jLnEmk9dYZzvM6VuhjxYzzap3uwm2o9d@jmENxz3eLVz8LwwO5i/1XkM0m8Hzn644JJyjp9q6tceaXI2gb/S5lCd/E6NZuCCMSVehd5hY35RZ22d7P2aOCtBz5g5pM7ZXsX7x3/VLDDhRYLbjvN54iB/MgbXj4uWyADeJHiHi340eqqHaOZXPiE5KnKLUI7GKfpA4vdK43GwrlVx1SG6/XIW8FjEVK3zzCrUdcOpk1n9aOh9CanpTOGzdulvWnK@atqkIRpKiMurR0J1VE/WDFxrlFrPmMTVXc5gDtHFLXxCzhOqs8VctJKh/WRPzmnp6Yk9q9zj1ZnBJmdwl@9S7dRJ36LnBFadMURXdEpfrOjmoDcVtqj6gearMzV1v5vEEMpZP8lPAn9y6tgF@@8qdglyHEsrKXP4AKdIzu@1wTpyzWXjWfChvOrJ54E/dT2XyuQ8Gn@er1LnU8czTkbdE/pO6MWvPrgpusSyhh62eko/uOpKNWKnpV0mPbEunEzXc7WWnK9@Ss@h9ls28rO1f7nGIvfPUAzzIN80TuKuLlyt6ouZnDNgv8DozMi3W87a7tTzYwd5aqXdmjlUxDMnXIM944rLqO4k@AejsY5z5WcDmI/2zwZrVcB5SyNJNFdwnmbFlDgzpLM@Cn5ESC8b6mbo58VZyqXz7aKfrud1ge@DcyIm@wfqPEnhf4AvqXyBOZ/7s3hnJ@Pxpblp@g5rTw225YKJ3T5mn@vnypvr1OgpPpas44q39aylSY6L6v1gf5dm4UHOMuas9eeZ1ThDbUovCM7sVu3IOIU7F9RUM@nHN43tG@t4eq6t1rOQy8A225KzE4RfiFgu0s50Y3xhchbG6FKf1P5lOesdvVuIs5CfA3NcgjEXf15sCHhjwNiWcHP7kHj0IC8LmIBN1ozBI7R4asJO6dXD/a5XekCY55A@aeQxxUdCTQ/YVPz0xx//Hw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 9981 bags

The [Angs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162453/fruit-bagging-factory/163190) → [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162498/58925) → [JayCe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162852/58925) → [fortraan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162863/58925) → [Alex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162969/58925) → [Roman Czyborra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163052/58925) codegolf python could cyclize back to Haskell for some added mathematical purity along the same major train of thought

- only one orange gets sacked before a new orange is added into consideration
- bias prefers sufficing fruits (`(<miss)==False<True`)
- bias prefers fruits close to the most likely integer fill
- for that integer reverse the
  `(m-n)/sqrt(n)==(n+1-m)/sqrt(n+1) <==> n=sqrt(m^2-1/4)-1/2`
  from a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

  [image: https://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs(1-x)*sqrt(1),abs(2-x)*sqrt(2),abs(3-x)*sqrt(3),abs(4-x)*sqrt(4)]

seasoned with some unecessary pointlessnesses

```hs
subsets[]=[[]];subsets(f:t)=[r|s<-subsets t,r<-[s,f:s]]
mean=uncurry(div).(id***max 1).(sum&&&length)
bags[]_ _=[];bags batch(miss:have)n=let
 goal=div miss$ceiling(sqrt((fromIntegral miss/170)^2+1/4)-1/2)
 best=minimumBy.comparing.(((<miss)&&&(abs.(goal-))).); desk=take n batch
 pick=best id.best(if sum desk<miss then mean else sum).filter(>[]).subsets$desk
 in if pick < miss then bags(delete pick batch)(miss-pick:pick:have)n
       else (pick:have):bags(delete pick batch)[miss+sum have]n
main=print$id&&&sum$map(length.bags batch[1000])[2..7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dX1brx5Hktw7f8V5GAzIWYnTXVVZlakZGvDlxYAB/wCCXlASJRFDUjJJrb2A/7v2dHdGRvTZtQCKPOe7dHdd8hIZGfXL2y//ePfhwx/vP/726@evD//t7de3L//n5x@f6c//4/2Xr/jFf/3109fPv354@Z8/f/71//zx5ffvv7z7@uX1m1evX79587f88flP33198er15//35e/f5q8evn7z@e/fvv7yzU/ffXnz5tnHd28/vfr90w@/f/78r89/fP8vL14@f//jX/7yl49v/@/D/vjDl98//vnPf/7w7tPPX3958ez7tz8/XuKfH/751es3fzt@ePj@7dcffnn@8f2XL9/98vZf3r349OrDu6/PHn7@9e2HV49f93C88qcf3r3/8P7Tz8@//O/PX58//@nzrx//@6ev737@/PbD@fpf97W9@F/tn/a/jhff7n9tL549fP/uy9dXH99/ev/x94//5V9f/vDrx9/efn78ipfPnz//@/GZF4939fzt919ePj8u9e2LFy9evvjbw4/vvvzj1de3/3j38Om6s2cPv73/4R@vjq97eP/jy@Pv5@9/enh8qvO951c9fP3l3aeHYyAe3n348u548cXLn95/@Pru8/P/9PrNi5c5cn86PvHs4f2nh8dvOL724e8P/PwxGs9/fPf49O@uF8/rvziH5tvjF9@d/7sG6dnD9d95ved84bv/z7e8Pr7ln467Pt725tOzj2/ff3r12@OIfP3T@x8fh@LxpT99fPvb82uiXnJqXu/btr158bq9fLne/HH@6tXrfW7ftG37Zrf5@Gf/Zp/jm92Pv9v187LHnx9fX49//PF36/H1GY9/Hn8/1/W543Xrjz8//onHP/742np8bT3@u/v1@tyvz6zje/Nne3yt9@u9w/P3@b3H@477sMdr9XXdzzquNa7vPz9/3NPx@bzfhfcc9/z4fSuuv/EsZtfnj@sd/z6e1fKeVv77eO95nzPvqV3XOMfA@fvj@tH4Hcd9Hs8/5jVW53u363eeY3iO1crPjLznuMYJ4zzyfo5rHM81Isc877e3a3yOezrvtV3zgXs83nfMk@W4nveQfx/fPY9nWo9zPnn94/OR4@I51sc49Rz/8zOWY437z/kb2/X6MR4YR89/n/eyX89xPONoj9c95krG4vi94R5yHs/n82tMFtbOlvPoOV4r52TknOLvdq3B48/xPs95XxvHYk6O@3nv67r@wp983zH3x/ydYzmv57ecj2OMfV6/P@dH9kV47pWWz9GuNXy8H2vb8jo97@dYI6Odc3Nd9/H74vjdyu/frteOf4@co8B85/XPe5/X2jvHcL9eO/fkyPs91la/Xj@/e8/xwP7BXjeO7/H6MQ7nHC8ZgyVrEPe8co4s17Rda93zvo41eDzfsa6P1yJ/f@7T7XrtGL/Ia5/3t67rnz9P2VOWYx7X5877WvnZlnswrmsc17O8/@N3lmv2uDfLn8smBN93PpfnerJcDyH31691e66HtB8mey6c@/W49/O9M8dj42vHWI7JcbQcj3Pst@vah705Pt8t7a3Y0WOuz3Wx3e3jyv152gtLO@@c78ffXXsSa91zb2IN57o/X5u04acdMNlL2Lewm/Maz3O@00@s/PxpN7GWtly7G@1E5J6wy1aVfznfk@N/zNvK/XHel3PvRdpf2NmVtssb7cvxHZ5795ynnrZ@px1d1xyf/tFzrs91n@sDvuLYT3jm4zOW6/J437HuTvt1@MLg9SdsRvrYlfN9jtFM29XFh8FHpM1ceJ7J7z@vn37W8cy53gJ2Ma9/jNHpb9Km1pqHP@353WlXpnFMV97XzP112u9FO2wb/ffMZ/YcD@yx498T@3tLWxayTgbn/Xj@gO137p24bGTbgjby3Hd2fa/lOjrnIu0IbCRsHmzbaacX7f/pM9JunnM08nnxPRmznOMUaQuda3jmnrbcy55jYPl9ZTsX4xJLm3L6Yuf@shybZdwXx/Mc@@R4n8EfwQ7h@njOnENvjMNwjfJf8Cd7jg/8VZOYcNCvzLTb53x3rq8ag7Q5px1Ln33e@xDfOzNewp5b1xgF9lj6iuM@esZ9K/eIIb474td8XqzVLvbdZ9o4xC45d2ds5ZdP8LzvAV@S4xidcc3595bjjtg479vSHnrGjRM@K23RGdfsfN902iLHfk3f6LvYKthwxKNy37CFC7YGsUDOp3fGJJ5@a6RPxvpBjBKIXYM@zRHHj2s8R9qTc97zWSPH5PTbiP@w9gb92Up/Az/0@KzXfOBeZK2OfK6Z@22mD1tBOwZfUPZp5ndFxlKwP@IHVsbI52dd1nBcdiJMxjR915qM2Wb6mnO@R8Ybk3YS/isacxzkSiv3Eu6hbP5OX1XjI/v@fB9s77r8zEo777mHRtoYzI0hjliMy897cNopw7rI8fTcZ7AvK@P@tfO7z@uu3OtY3@lDPOizZvp4y@dYEjPOtL1nTJRjh3hz5VpCzG87Y/@VuUn5knaPxwK2OG2qheRQLecKucjI6zrHa2ZcvRAv7Nc9GnwFYomMVUzi5TF4Hwtj3fm3ZQxusm8s95U7fSXyGccYYB3NtIG6rmBL9lyD6bencX0syeccOVnnvXvOJ3KC8q3Io3KtIIe0IfZzZwx0zkW@zwfnG2tgwJ/nd8y0Lactwzjm@oYPLvuoeVfGsYj/17znaog1Thudax3rt2IkY64VkzG/T8ZYuIYtxiaevuHxM21DnAv758zZXOJa2HdDTIdcP@/HELOZxKW5r09sYZfnyn33@Hrb93rutsNuZN6I@Aex4mzcnz44zqf92GWfJr4QmoeHxEA7fcK5xoL2ATFfxYzpcy0xhNHoszEOZ6zRaFORZ4@M@bBmZ8YOZx6MGCvvPQZxH8Ranve7Ml6P3GMVL2QsOKbE243xlef6N8TBTWwa9kn6auviD425JHIExAfTBQu51teJvSB@dqxPxKqIQzE2QR85cw@ujN0QQ1ruUV9cY5ULNsakwEgcdivj9pXPY4i5xVZj/mxwfOao9XjlR7nuHT7daIsRf/pgLLwyHjzjesnvgZ@5c98iNoB/P/6MxC588rlG@k7gT5b2ZOR@xdwftgoYJbAD@DzEbhXPNfqkmuspOBd8RNrSitcRD@C5ci8O7Oc9MRjkIDk2Ixg7W@7VY58cMdGAbQv6sBnE@hAjVJziguu5YGS5Fmenr/O8Zu3nnX5u5r8xZwafbsQnEYcd6w@xbtnetK@B3C59nqc9NyfWtjIOi9xvPoibmmAvc3CtKO6F@HZl3r2Q90qegj1miVNh/2HcK0cPYo2@C3bYrnucXWK8yfefcbWJ3dhkjFvGX04MA7hCT1vnmasgB0DMCD8JXNczXrROn3tiJ5Mx8znPJvnuID4w084Vdgj/nHNgstfhW@HLEXsD4xvOa1VsC@x7y3kSLK7yvcSwjzU6Bq8JexaZJ@d@vvK8de2HyOsAZwOG2IPrD3HKHBy/wjEscaYrvm474gtgrsBVl@C9yJc22hnguee4Ac9CXGzMfQPrL58HtgY5CbD10YhvIl@y9MWG2N/yGrvgUILvYd8gpvUldRzEFe2aC88aSvR7Hom14hLbYvywr7F/zaVGlGsAeV/ZJqs87oxhIu8xQrAV5JmrcvtrHTXBQpHHpg1dwTU3p9QIlmB3u8Qs6U@Qy6yN@T3WHWxMdMHEBvGOBSwH@IH4bODFxzyEEXspnBNxqV9rHphLDGIMyKlXk7w010wIJl154iCuN9MXrcz92sY4AL7JO3NC4IhDfPZpe0Lwf7GBFpWbnWOL/BYYmmHNAJ9f1/swdgN@MrhvEbeORSzZnT4JvtQ35tJVu3KJfZyxoSem5Tk@qDkBr8far5xcfAxiMeyFkDFLjOF69kFsxtLWGfB8xHrjjo0jJx8762PI87FXzbiXTywrsZnZaA@xXzwE40jbeX6/MUafu@SViblZ@veGdQ37jPUD@57Ynk/JL3PeOuJT1K3SrmCch0nM2ATnnok/Z34SuY4jMU1rzPOt0z8d1@vw61k/jEZczHapT3vafsTmxr0fi88IbBa1wDO@dNaXaiw28R@N8Rfqv25cS/BtwO5R67NgfriylhOCOwOL8Ml1UT4i6yaG71z04Zbx/DkeuadHSAwHW446Tu5RX5Kvpk11Jx5avq3L3s/Y3LCnnPFS2a6QGAR4mTFHRey8JLf1HA@sMdR8geOVbRy0hQZ75elH4PucccbaaVNu9ffG/PfEkKVugroq4rfhgi00ruUaJ@d4TMFP5yAeZYNx59q4rsBnGJ3z7jl/5pyT@pwxPo/ct@d@DsFNTGzIIEcC9hR1vjFrnM8crmKEyJwuc3LFY6ueBJxWsanBmHEaOSFlxwfHZwbvY0qsgboNaszAOueQPFx9qqwNA17l9Fcjx2Chtoz90olP@rjXMrA3CyvbpfYDbDiYi41g3gyuBuoPyMvAsxhYG4s5cOWgwXhe7fXaBOcz8UWec7XTx6SNunKInbH/mQs6Y//yb1nvno22HjGr1toQmx5rJjprRIgh1sw9FIJjDNbxJvJh8blnDAEbbKyLxqDvWvl9p11G7QrYZfrIGcTBRjCP6Rjb3GsD2AHq9ILfB@Ix4Tvh@sCkgOeUfQfG2mnja64TR6ja7GLta6S9QM6ynLXA4uxkrgW8w9JugwcFW1yYfWONr2LdJtjwnrVexMiDfi@c2Dg4DyOIESI@QIxzrp0mHAuruOqMd4AFANuoGqPUaLA2gMutIM5YNUGnzTnjSPHtyOEqJkTNwi67EGkfEF8Xxt8lNxsc@8rnjHGqKVcIWKFgHCG2Db7wjKGCNfozrs0YqfZiu@OPVfPt137wED/ZuHeA36LGotw3Bw6Iem0nPr0yV0NdCONaexP4btqnwtk35jTADYAJrXmvGY2duHit3XwP9i/WLvJD/LyctnOFYNdy/yv9MHDgJXUh2ETLtYx9PdqdlxNaRxJuIOI@D6mXDmLna1V8e9pV5AlLYgTEv8uEpyT7qjhmgp965oE1Rl3GHHmWc83OxnrByniq6phd9uQgHxFcPrMr727qD/N@Axhbrg3UfU5bP3I9I5dvYnenxNAmtVfnOoOdxjiCF@kSGwKPdGD8IRw64fDEErxEeADAQRC74rXKr3IdjLQbsbFOWpzRnbgS6v7euN@KvwF/PsnPAf6LPYRYDfMQm3CugvsJ9z5DsN9JDkzhaM6cdmQO5HmfZrJHM09TvuNqUpMEZ3RnTj8l7sR7bRfMYGNMDsxxLnJgl@ATc2NMjDU0d8555aODe2gE6@vFE0n/VLXW8aRWtgQfzVrZ6ILhd3JVsL5h/6ezfmhL8hLEO6gzLI6VgSORPEZz2jRv8gzgvi3h3EleXRhTkAMHbCpyPZx58WScEY2@YBn9ttaN0x@1vUscpXHRnns3iJ34JrgVYgesJeU8dc4NOMe@Mc4bGY9p7XPsxCoRpwKLGUN8hOR4GE/w/Sr/khjch2CTEmcUH3VI7ix2CbH3dNa1UFcAJ6nw@ya4nczN6rTztzq1cBZOu2XM2V1i@uKtu9jukHjI@f7ehdcawoULyXuMPgz11aqnbORKVLwgdVrwspIn1PZgjof6ouYMC9d31m0qFka9YCc3quKoKfag0U6DEwbbAEy3avjCZ4YtBw5sQX7PaYfGNV7AnIDxwvaEsxa0wC/SHD1rDH3RJrj0PmjeYFJvBV/Sd@EuL8GIkUsO4XY02unA2tpYA8O6RE3NjeMD7H41Xgv8KPDeEfP7IM9yJq8VWNXMGoUv8kVt0r9YxoDYczXPufdR1xkhcaLUnBAXmnENVV6avB748@JoNeEqbRIDdXLFZ9oYYGgTdSdgRMaaO@J1cFs0NoYPt8V6R0/8HNy62IkNV//BTjwC@X/lv0G@gud1PetH3pmPrtwHyXeoWP/MnYJ@eoi/NME9Im1Q7BJfwkdM6Ydwcl7MeE/IK4FFVb0ONS3J57HHLX2xSV7bXfLZTdaWc1xQNw6p2R7rqaPvY5N8Fb4s99wQ3tWKO2cJdXDYNsN@Eh4U8vjqgZgcl6o3NcEHu3Cccsyjsb6JGqMb8VrkDMjFptQ1wbXD2OneBodqbuQ8Iq5HPu2NvUjDBQcC76GTq4S1jbhgwI9kTJMcaXIb4s5n1dqSbeTfV26PesgSbor254TUWPO7qgYbgiU15mwmfBfY/Uiua3GahS9w7vXk1Lj0yxTvA/zRTn@M@gY4u6jDn/HSuPcmwGYB97ed/KzV7vVzyzXkWv8cfD7kmsCFxmTN8Ma/aPKas56OOnD5wLTXkXUL1BZREyiuwkY@APhdvpjb2E6@o4XE9Ouek1Sd3K@1hv171qC05t7IE8J@X5N9UcWncuKrIf0owEWULwrOLbhn4BoPZ70PddIR5BwUr3cnN6tsxsZnK1yvk1uzhJ8DPzJ34pfApIo/m98BHBT8kfIxyOsb90hxCTP@rl6LkfHzJJe3OG9DOLRDeKZN8PeMBZAjjCH@Wep@kfUh2Bxw45ALTYm/h3AfF@okzhojuGrKjTW/55DBHs@2G2tz04RzCnyuSX0R8fvGui76DZG/Yv0UzupPOACDfAXwFdFjsYw44RmLSF44duG4Al/PcUTcvZycPdg6v77nxIVismZYfmmkb5JeC@wP7bcEx6DDRzWJncQ@zE3WI@Ze1jd6ttADULnRxh7KJbnBSpxjzDvPUGsSVaPPPV/cmyZ9oZM@Y@xSU96ZPyE3AR4WO2PY4otM1sWsSd20k1PlBw7nWUvJOlMI57oH@2DA5wc3DjFGLMaR4DaOJbxryfFPO5gY5xKsrjgSRpwS/h81b/BFixPWyE0Gx1lrhfgZc@5S8x6Kp2TsAr5Q8V538gldxgd7E/E89l3tnSF5JPihO7F9jCFyDZ@s5dRaiqs3ETbGhvD0g3um7Fyw9xx1YOxh5H6Ve4T05AX5J@gxBa8ENt@lrwKc9miC6WfNt/oYl2CJ4J0KzwnxfdU0h@R2U@ph4JH4fXxw75l7X/XVRtuDHomR2CryI6w14OLFed0lXxffFkae/UzuKHgUwI1de8675FTafzglVl3MF2r9SL9Hc/IjEHMBR0cNYKGm4cV1OPOf4j904bJvjFkRf43MHdJ3c@6m5KnjXgetOtqQ9TXE303h5DXJ0UzuJ322L8lfwTNUrQTpIQefzq96/VVbz3jurJE16eEW/DuwbqAx4MRdwMvHHq/@xuBzgW8PnlzFCJ183CH1qgXdBug@iH0vXvkunLFG/s/5XWmrwN/xRg52cQF28kzBpwdfq/jhjXvNhZvvnbH6Ep7zpN8tbmzxizbWNhDDVow5uQarJjSFDzuYU3pjD@NSPGAnXjMyphZ7xnqgcG/18@Bnnb1DTfqLTHpQTDiRyempvgzgkGlTQ@pbhZ/vwhF0YphVy3rCA9A8B5hWPudpYxG3A6NEf7binsrvR/8Hco@Z3IHi2TlrJehPG2KXkLcgZ5uiqYFYcEhsPyS/v/mxIZh/k/W3yBM1qRfgWtr7WpxO@MB@r8nA7iBeLZ46@jMy5uybcAE6bcoy1pEtqI8BDtUcws009rNVnL/deUcmvenAwYGxGPkhV01k3jkN2NsagxfXIscwXHDAxE3hV1DD0L4H@GDbZP3u7J@KfCb0BFpyI8PYI48c2YB/hNSLu/S/NOaiIbkk6hmFsze5honPz7iwevWa4Igb@3b8ac1vsZcCPF/4gtjIb6h8bGcNETmmS@8@@tWrdgFMb7FPHLFG9YskDl49DxtzyvSvF2cV2g5ZMyub2CRPyDyjcsS8pqVuANbfCvLowLlHHIUaYfEDtEdysMel8IONPfylvwIOflDPpfizLj1QyYsO4UuHcOqXs549xAcBB0EdHnHVyPyrLel3bswtC39b1N6BfhBiFu0Fmk9qv3MjjgPuReHJ4u@msTcO/U@lv9IkLhW9oepdDOJdPSR@bOzhm@lbwAdBPjDsrkuEOpRqaQy/YybV0y8aRognMIcr9X@Q77j03Q3hQsQSLQPjngbfvnAd55oKI28YMYPqYYDHXbXZKX0JMpfginvQLq2NfD5w5CyxsSm6JMd8d@HvVvwQUs9E7T61YdS/FScvmJeAm4/9nNyXti3aTtTHwJ3QPrElGlFL4jPktku1qUzsdhcM0tjTiHVfedB@16pBXXlKbd6zFgbuHXJZzanA5YBPHp3cOOTiLrgWuPC4fsXDu/BJMjaFhkjVR7HepPcUOkroP3L4WsF/4BeK37YJVtvvPctLsJlY5MMVxim5K3I4w5ow2gJg8cVFb6yFIB8pbZ@NvI7qXYk79xbzXDUy6aFdilEY8XTkb4hViivSBGsP8mUsWLecYpNC@A89@eeB2rvokUzguJevbpv0SCvOCi7SWMSF0e@LGMXAyXDqGpR@2sa4u3r@u/S4K/@8E0MDx77qfLkWz9qhS@08mFuXllITjTvJu6D35VJbBw5WNZpd4tdJDjNybfQ9e2POCBygfA37TVvLesuUnuLq6ZT4B/VdxChliyb9sGU9c2rvvfFnc2qhYa0Wj/lJTzfGyEU/wiVXNGfuiv3S476uo931kZD3op5S/Z/ggKC3Bn2ugzlj6YGIXYFNjI21uJG2tQ9qIiA3WtJX6kEtrSGc@vEkl4D@DfAc1EsK45J6jUt/KmzmcupiaD01EhswqRFV//YmGmqde2htjMdLX6uLlqHY1uK@dYmFMjeCHkLlUUZfDK048C2rlu/EearOP4inIaYvvpr0nYOL6xnrqkaXbbTzpSkofRnIvxFXDKkLQ9PMpccD8S7mxURXxEPwmCF9iJPPiRqWic7iaORTosdiNtFKzF6NITpAwHfmE06QCz/fOjW34J9ht8F58csXX/YX@mXBNYG6YGnDLfavFS/EntRnnPoSZ1/7kt6GyfEtnQnkjRvx51ttwqSPuSXnf5EzX30MndevtaI9Le2ud4f@9uITevm20oObS@I1qWsCYwnpdYAGImq2xd/fiPmVHk2nfgbwpaU1jeSxBPgZTuzThV9VMULjc470LejhQy/KFO4OPhtL@H773eaV3tgS7ppLX8u82/6V9Ulv4j834dfoeIT0@g7Wd0uj1tg/fOv/T4wQ@SnqWjM1ExEPg6t28/OKQwpPFn12M3vXq9dadDKmxPjFzZ5ih7FPsh80tH9niYaUS7/5Ro2fyosn9w9sn8YSLnEx9BuxB8D36uCt5hofjfwF29mvr/qqFSNN1jHQ4z5lfS/R8wPWhR6E6gfq9BHo93H0kmYsEtJDXX27U7T71l3DAvge@vqM2jFnvll9YUv81mIddgrOAw458kfgi1O4Fmf/7@Be1bW0OutYbZDT76LnpJqmqDWAiwg7jD5s1CT7Rn2wwuQafdDKOeoufMmd3EyTWoAL9jVFR@WpttSUXAO8hupNadQ9rv6goF0Dp2NJf@iUnprSOUobDz@/tjsGjB6AtaivM0L4AkO4PaLXc@s96sR1gVmB@@FSy0Tfe@pwVG1gSf1kae9KJ687FjVB0HtSOj2qwzrvNcLq0dvIs6j@wI1@yqBxtEkM3rh3oP0xwO@Yosdw4YEnZjC1rx56EcKf1DoguMVVM4EGwSKXbAqHvPAL7ZucdxwXfmpIv33xhnbiKqjZOXB2qRtM8dFVbzDxtxs5HsBSbt@Z4@YhWnD7nccPX4r678kBzv0Wgs1g7yB/HlN61kWfDrmnSc/QmSss8ktVn6K4vp1YVPUHx51rhDpb1eyW2NbFvqaBnGa/21Lw7k10rdDPPEw@g98t6ncBW53gEE@pJzfh2DtxruKpznteOhZ7yEx6EBDnVU9iI2ak/aXAyNG/gp4uaJws7cOLJ71wTWLZQa4mODfoGUSNzqRuWHpmnf7ExL6Vjh9imI09YtDhq34/0bNKTvZVJ7/wt4tntJ7kV2JzkXdUX5kxBoYthk0tzUTpH@2i8WOihYrezdiFPxvUYIBegUuPNbQHwNFcsgeLozjJjS3tyZ36/djPIbqBx730JbbYpL6FXtdFzFN1DRWPgR2Hbgf0udDfCXvt0gOxRJsMOcoS7Bwai1V7NeGMbsItE7wK8WTVO524ckBDMft/Mw46czLgV1Mw0OHkfA/VcLmwgBvfpupUk9gmeKvVQyR6FcqTLM4RccPWRGPBtic6tJvUg6FnPthvilxmtiufNdj8IXzMoCYO@BXlH7T2j/nvosecWkBLdLBQpyrd6MZ@rHN/bOTE4brFHQzGMsWxhw/r1OpCHDeTFx3O9Vm93p0xRvVAD/oT@I/SvxAeJ@xUDMYLMaQPcmOMhrwcvTKIs5B/FgejMc4oXrlybUQHDjyT0nTPvHfKGMfOXsPC9Z7k49CuUa0qm3fcFX0SJj3piE1K82mnXRiiu2RD@tu66OW4nGdi0hvZyZHXXjrE8VNrTCbantIneetBXfy8Cxe7bGBiONqbhHs7a7edHAfgZcU3C2JfyFGrL0lqxq78LqfeWuHGLjjqdteTndJTVbzfznoytBWRl6XtOO2UbeyfRU2ocLohmvYhmO2S@MCoD1f7bZfYWvXH0icBKzXY304M1UXT3NqTXGwXfWnRbAHXrmzzYH/jGHdcyzfaJMUnsUerH2ATTlNw/yuWiO/UHt/CK0P6dzfpk27U9incXHvznXFbTMGeQ/QtxA5Go/50xcMmPTKig7qe8GpLm3vj9@l5DbX/E8OHjubZlyX2tvL@Tk0rYFHFEU9fH6IVGlkzLp3n1PC1YHwPfGLIeRQ@qLWl583ocwKD9yb2ZYrGGfS7dvIyVQvA2xO9zim4UhP9p3Hzs9SO7VKnbPeevKqn7lIftvu5LEs4ubMRC9KcDLYbuojg5Lnmv1FcR56pMGibSr9iF23dEM5kJ096Sq8KfEFpLyTWvUQnC1wNrK3iB3f2ORV206SnTHIXEw0HT17fQB@JCd97Zy4Q25NzOURjfmo9QXR8p@TdqmsL24pcfEh9B/k11p4ZtczQ31Z6XCG9Cia6nqJzPkWzBefOTPGZpVUm@awb@wNKE8yJ74ILO0Rvrjj04GdMxsORvj7I1724SXK@ADSVoeFeuuKiUw5bOiRvgC9bqmNmvOf8nkvHw4nbReIBh8b33u48IPChcd8Y6zoLZAq/WeoZIVpI0cn5Rb0RvqOw2yl4gUte79Lfu8jHj11qHNs9Zqp@RN2TIVwT0QbSM9W05lnYthEfWcJlKrsifISKObIWA6wuXPQ3dul3MKm1ODEM9eFVm2zEflBHAe5ZnN/OPvzS8erEs6bocyg3KwbrryfnoLPvBLlGnYGQfrO0Z@RMH@15L75HMF4RzbXDn16cwsV4uvzUJjyMnXFpra8p8UaXs7YEU1hTzuWQPtIpfTi3s33UD5n07OzUzfMhvEPhJ1S@OoSn16X2YdSEnHLeRulaQm9nMJ4GX3I6z9HCmTvAvnBmS9WnlBM1pGdkl7rmTl7jlD6TwoOlZ2YmJxd9nlP8lIuuUeXPwj9G7llnsyxi/D5pd@FHulMX9rSruR9Gjl1XnZTcH9HZh11jPSTPTp1AE0ywYsCNuuvINW66Pnomxc6eZpd@v5CYK4T7XtilS41Neemip7SGnAc2ybMsfb4pnO3Bc@am1GnN2Rte@Jj0nqpOV62VJbwZwTE1Z6p6bAiuurMvwyRGn6KtXJoL0BPdyH8v7WnlOU6JhZTXvO69OMX/Ce7t1u68WvTTx@CZd/n9Z98cYobb2TVyNqfaEnCNi7/IHssLT2nMm@ocSuGUdakXQFdtiZ8GX2oJlx74Ac5uLP7pYs0XNZsxRX9etDVKH8DJb0DeV1zbvThM1UsGrBq9tHWWwE77AB7JgAb9Jj6lSywQxEym4DPDaCdXxj7QHFNeLXQQgfMVLi2awcmXuXSGhQtRubKnvqfgRxWPZv9L1Qtx3pYxB6wz@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@4cq9LVHZKvrLvmSPGctye6b@BliHa7nkeIs3hLL9HJRwrBhM3vmt2wuTjXLYTHdmD1O7Rk2pOz7LrwbztzLfAoYTNQ/6lakPMsizq3Sfp7az5EO3B0Yuw4t7B8L3iM/d7vBT599cDsPD@oMPBNzgRXvrKe8yl9sC6aJyF9n8VFBX9f@MtTNK201lD2WXqposn5dsEc3kRnFFqR4I6WHs1g3W6oDVs8X6Twyk3sC@KIxli1C0aD58O@Abemzssc1JWHDwKfGDmYSb1hDZ7RaOirEy4E8rDioGivlsm5wdoTPIQfg3qTYHbojZvCE@2LnFfEoKUNsGT/7aL5lTFmcb@lvjPlrCdg/jgruHg8on2A2swAlrS4d3HW6hTOuEuNCboH1eswqb9g6BuEbzXRE9yJQSHXHXbn/PbO/YG@G/Tz13NvEhuLPtJS7UzB9U10UmYj56/4Wy6aiCZ6p@PO90AtCTXx4oXswlXf2Gda2OJ20xq5aiY403Gx58SVVyv9JvDDU3Rah9TdCvNDbmaczzr3VmpBNS67nLuhHAGjnwRWNZVbuajJZ2ovFmut1kRjBbqJovut2jSI@c3IUXU5lwA1qTr3Z0iPucnZbL1w58o5SsPahOu2kgM6OddD@kCrtp4@omKjYO9djstVkzXRFtpES9qlXzrnuE/W0MZkD7MD85dzEOaTuAk1DWDlQ/kmovFffbOi74heq@oDdvIckd@hF3e1OxdmyhnaWNva41v8bCPn2Xj2@dWH30X3Qc7RKxxeuI0uvR@ly78/0QvAWUuic4OYrxtxhZPnNUXDVPTnwFs06YFAjWP05IsJXoA@@X5hnxdvSPAv69zT@N6aG@kVrtpuSD7pcu7g4v4ue7LdOZXamwlbor62sEnUr7ucd9hEq2TneN84EMG6QIScZRhy7otTK3Bp/W4xprmd/7BEn3IwLwN@PdeN70ANaL//fPoJiSXBRxqK3e/k/8XGMSpNQz3jUmocVS9znuMKTlvxubv4OdXt03uP@9ljPu@xSXFloDst9qP0jzS2dzkLLuPGaNRfrd4yPZdPz0AbrLfMlRzmKTHKxnzRlYsGvREX7tsm/TXbHUtacl6gnrWC9Vfn3nepG2dfKnSz9axfg17BJn3Kcs6I1mKh/T9Vcyj3@JAcrLTGRTtYzywuvlAXnNvZk6@90j3PRsE6wrkspmfBdupNmayd4r1POQOzs3@kcAWc0WdyFsNOXeXyxS5c1J37EvFY6U@Y8Kc34dR3welzzrpJL5faQTkH2JSfGVKjGFKfkFqXp@4t@p3KP0nNaYiuqcmZdNWfiH4O1COXnCfY5Ozcnf1lUzgnqEUi5oEOBNY8aiTQbJjafzsldgeXTs7kCeV9iIZw8ZoF4wXfqLiqUtNdi5o0JmeEryXnseUavN1rI18U/LCKuTbO0xRNgjp7rPE5S3ers28Cn3W78@tRTyib0BmfV39wYy8z6j2WeM0wOfd@l7NtJ2tq8P9L@nRgaycx0jPeGILrDIk5XfXN53/Qwy51@BrPnfnxTdeoCU9A8s8l@@HEWyXvL51uzG2uj7ZYhywdfugCiWany3kmagtrnLJu1FNLDjHD7dxNyaFh8/pG/KL0SIUTNbe7JjB6W8GbN9XlfKqTHzxvwvR82@Qian@bydkC4GQpd6zW50b9j9LZCuF4oCd4UCcphLtQ@N4mOX0IJ2yXuucm/bhOf4F@Ln@Kr3U526ITQ4WObp07NshrNelDBNZW50ftooGx3fskSwe7MT4rnsXO@UCcsuze02Jylk7lfE3OF8v8EfEieOfgKihXGrXz0rwJ0f010dodwpUJngmoZ1jXGSga9xlziTXvusI432dK3Qx5sJ5tUr3ZTbQfu/RzCG84rvFq@@B5YbYxf6vzGKTfDpz9cMEl5Rw/1dSvPdLkbAJ/os2hOvmdGs3ABWNKvAq9w8b8os7a2tn7NXFWgp4xs0mdsz2J97d/r1lgwosEtx3n88RG/mQMrh8XLZEBvEnwDhf9aPRUD9HMr3xCclTkFqEcjV30gcTvlcbjYF2r4qpNdPvlLOCxiKla55lVqOuGUyez@tHQ@xJS05nCZ@3S37TkfNW0SUM0lBCXV4@E6qjurBm41ii1njGJq7ucwRyii1v4hJwnVGeLuWglQ/vJ7pzT0tMTe1a5x5Mzg03O4C7fpdqpk75FzwmsOmOIruiUvljRzUFvKmxR9QPNJ2dq6n43iSGUs76TnwT@5NSxC/bfVewS5DiWVlLm8AFOkZzfa4N15JrLxrPgQ3nVk88Df@p6LpXJeTR@P1@lzqeOe5yMuif0ndCLX31wU3SJZQ3dbPWUfnDVlWrETku7THpiXTiZrudqLTlffZeeQ@23bORna/9yjUXun6EY5ka@aezEXV24WtUXMzlnwH6B0ZmRb7ectd2p58cO8tRKuzVzqIh7TrgGe8YVl1HdSfAPRmMd58jPBjAf7Z8N1qqA85ZGkmiu4DzNiilxZkhnfRT8iJBeNtTN0M@Ls5RL59tFP13P6wLfB@dETPYP1HmSwv8AX1L5AnPe92fxznbG40tz0/Qd1u4abMsFE7t8zHmunytvrlOjp/hYso4r3tazliY5Lqr3g/1dmoUbOcuYs9bvZ1bjDLUpvSA4s1u1I2MX7lxQU82kH980tm@s4@m5tlrPQi4D22xLzk4QfiFiuUg7043xhclZGKNLfVL7l@Wsd/RuIc5Cfg7McQnGXPx5sSHgjQFjW8LN7UPi0Y28LGACNlkzBo/Q4q4JO6VXD/e7nugBYZ5D@qSRxxQfCTU9YFPx5o8//g0)

without yielding a different numeric gain atop the 9981 nets of oranges harvested afore while [my 10k011 bags packer grabbing unfit oranges back out of unclosed bags](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163190/58925) was disqualified by [user69850](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729) in persona [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162914/58925) → [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) → [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) hencefore the deserved bounty went to [Alex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162498/58925)

[image: GIMME BOUNTY!]